# A get_from_variant function in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

This is the follow-up question for [A recursive_transform Function For Various Type Nested Iterable With std::variant Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251060/231235). As [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251072/231235) mentioned, leaving only recursively transforming operation for `recursive_transform()` may be a better idea. As the result, the implementation of `recursive_transform` function is kept in the following form. Moreover, the forward declarations have been removed.

```
template<class T, class _Fn> requires is_iterable<T>
static inline T recursive_transform(const T input, _Fn func)
{
    T returnObject = input;

    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), returnObject.begin(), func);
    return returnObject;
}

template<class T, class _Fn> requires is_iterable<T> && is_element_iterable<T>
static inline T recursive_transform(const T input, _Fn func)
{
    T returnObject = input;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), returnObject.begin(),
        [func](const auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, func);
        }
    );
    return returnObject;
}
```

However, I still want to handle the compound structure with ranges and `std::variant`, such as `std::vector<std::variant<double>>`. A new function `get_from_variant` comes up in my mind in order to focus on the operations with these things.

```
template<typename T_variant, typename T>
static inline auto get_from_variant(T_variant input_variant)
{
    T return_val;
    std::visit([&](auto&& arg)
        {
            return_val = static_cast<T>(arg);
            return arg;
        },
        input_variant);
    return return_val;
}
```

The tests of this `get_from_variant` function:

```
int main()
{
    //  get_from_variant function test
    std::variant<double> testNumber = 1;
    std::cout << get_from_variant<decltype(testNumber), double>(testNumber);
    
    //  The usage of recursive_transform function and get_from_variant function
    std::variant<double> variant_number = 3.14;
    
    std::vector<decltype(variant_number)> testVector1;
    testVector1.push_back(variant_number);
    testVector1.push_back(variant_number);
    testVector1.push_back(variant_number);
    std::cout << get_from_variant<std::variant<double>, double>(recursive_transform(testVector1, [](auto x){ return get_from_variant<std::variant<double>, double>(x) + 1; }).at(0)) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform Function For Various Type Nested Iterable With std::variant Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251060/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  In order to handle the compound structure with ranges and `std::variant`, such as `std::vector<std::variant<double>>` in a better way, a new function `get_from_variant` has been created.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  In my opinion, I am not sure whether the design of the function `get_from_variant` is good? Is the idea or the usage good or not? Any comment is welcome.

Comment: `get_from_variant()` might not be the best name, as there's already [`std::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) for variants. Some languages already have a `variant_cast`, but that casts between two different variants. Maybe `get_as()` is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been following this thread from the beginning, so I'm more confused than you expect readers to be by this point. It would be a good idea for you to provide a complete compilable example each time — even just as a Godbolt link, if you want to keep the question's focus on some little piece of the code.

In fact, I *prefer* to see a Godbolt link (*in addition* to seeing the code in the question as you correctly have done), as it saves me the trouble of pasting your code into Godbolt myself. :) Here's a link to your code: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5PqxPx).

---

```
std::variant<double> testNumber = 1;
```

This doesn't compile in C++20. Did it use to? If so, yikes, that's a pretty big API break for C++... but not your problem. Anyway, change it to `1.0` and recompile.

---

```
template<typename T_variant, typename T>
static inline auto
```

Lose the `static inline`. Templates are effectively inline by definition, and you don't *want* this template to be static — you don't *want* to force each translation unit to keep its own unique copy (in the case that it's not optimized away by the inliner).

I'm not a fan of `Giraffe_case`. Template parameter names should be short and `CamelCase`; here I recommend `V`.

Your `std::visit` lambda has a useless `return arg;`. In fact, this entire function should look more like

```
template<class V, class T>
auto get_from_variant(V input) {
    return std::visit([&](auto&& arg) {
        return static_cast<T>(arg);
    }, input);
}
```

With the cruft removed, we have brain cells free to focus on the next level of pedantry: You're taking `arg` by forwarding reference (`auto&&`), but you're not actually forwarding it to the `static_cast`. Maybe we should use `static_cast<T>(static_cast<decltype(arg)>(arg))` here, so that if `arg` is an rvalue reference, it'll get moved into `T`'s constructor?

But wait; `arg` will *never* be an rvalue reference, because we're visiting an lvalue `input`! So maybe we shouldn't expect to modify the `arg` we visit — we could take it as `const auto& arg`. But if we don't expect to modify `input`, maybe *it* should be taken by— yeah, wait a minute, why are we making a copy of `input` here? Just take it by const reference to begin with!

```
template<class V, class T>
auto get_from_variant(const V& input) {
    return std::visit([](const auto& arg) {
        return static_cast<T>(arg);
    }, input);
}
```

I've dropped the `[&]` from the lambda, since it doesn't require any captures.

We should also look at the template parameters to `get_from_variant`. `V` can be deduced and `T` can't; it always always always makes sense to put non-deducible parameters first.

```
template<class T, class V>
auto get_from_variant(const V& input) {
    return std::visit([](const auto& arg) {
        return static_cast<T>(arg);
    }, input);
}
```

Now our main driver looks like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qxoac1):

```
std::variant<double> testNumber = 1.0;
std::cout << get_from_variant<double>(testNumber);
    
std::vector testVector1 = {
    std::variant<double>(3.14),
    std::variant<double>(3.14),
    std::variant<double>(3.14),
};
std::cout << get_from_variant<double>(
    recursive_transform(testVector1, [](const auto& x){
        return get_from_variant<double>(x) + 1;
    }).at(0)
) << std::endl;
```

---

Meanwhile, in `recursive_transform`, you have a typo: `const T input` when you meant `const T& input`. [You can mechanically grep for these typos,](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/) and you should!

- Again, remove `static inline` from templates.
- The name `_Fn` is reserved for the implementation; just use `F`.
- Copying `func` into the lambda isn't necessary; you should use `[&]` as your default for every lambda you write (unless, as above, you can get away with plain `[]`).
- Honestly, unless you are *rabid* about following STL idioms, just pass the callback `F` by const reference and avoid ever copying it. There is a place in C++ for stateful, mutable callbacks, but `transform` is not that place.
- Your base case is more complicated than it needs to be. Let's fix that.

Putting it all together:

```
template<class T, class F>
T recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f) {
    return f(input);
}

template<class T, class F> requires is_iterable<T>
T recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f) {
    T returnObject = input;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), returnObject.begin(),
        [&](const auto& element) {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );
    return returnObject;
}
```

And then, it really seems to me that using `std::transform` here is overkill: it reads from `input` *twice*, once to make the copy and again to do the transform. Suppose we just open-coded it, like this?

```
template<class T, class F> requires is_iterable<T>
T recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f) {
    T output = input;
    for (auto&& elt : output) {
        elt = recursive_transform(elt, f);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Of course we *could* use C++20 Ranges to do something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xzYddq):

```
template<class T, class F> requires is_iterable<T>
T recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f) {
    auto transformed = input | std::views::transform([&](auto&& x) {
        return recursive_transform(x, f);
    });
    return T(transformed.begin(), transformed.end());
}
```

That's slower to compile and generates bigger code — but it might indeed be faster at runtime, if `T::value_type` is expensive to copy, because we're eliminating the copy-assignments on `T::value_type` — we're just constructing directly in place.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've not noticed that `std::variant<double> testNumber = 1;` doesn't compile in GCC and I just tested that it can be compiled in MSVC v19.27. https://godbolt.org/z/9Trv9z

Comment: @JimmyHu Protip: Clang on Godbolt uses libstdc++ by default (because Linux). If you want to test the LLVM project's libc++, you have to pass `-stdlib=libc++`, [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/z11jaj). (It also fails to compile with libc++.) The cpplang Slack tells me that this is known fallout from [P0608](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html), and so it's MSVC that is lagging the other vendors here.