# A recursive_transform for std::array with various return type

Tags: c++, array, lambda, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform for std::vector with various return type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251132/231235). Thanks to [G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251138/231235) provide further review suggestions. After digging into the topic of achieving a more generic `recursive_transform` function in both various output type and various container type, I still have no simple solution. However, based on [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251138/231235), the case of the `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list` container types may be resolved. I am trying to implement additional another overload `recursive_transform` function for `std::array`. Here's my implementation.

```
template<class T, std::size_t S, class F>
auto recursive_transform(std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [f](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}
```

The test case of `std::array`:

```
//  std::array<int, 10> -> std::array<std::string, 10>
std::array<int, 10> test_array;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    test_array[i] = 1;
}
auto recursive_transform_result5 = recursive_transform(
    test_array,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result5.at(0) << std::endl;
```

[Here's the Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/qs3b4r). The code in this link including the test cases for `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list`.

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform for std::vector with various return type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251132/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The handleable container type in the previous version of `recursive_transform` function is `std:vector`. With [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251138/231235), this handleable container type list is extended to `std::vector`, `std::deque` and `std::list`. Then, I am trying to deal with `std::array` here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  In this version of `recursive_transform` function, it seems that working well in the mentioned test case `std::array<int, 10> -> std::array<std::string, 10>`. However, there is some issues when it comes to the more complex case like `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> -> std::array<std::array<std::string, 10>, 10>` (the scalability to be improved!) If there is any suggestion or possible idea about this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ensure you pass by `const` reference consistently

The main problem with your code was that you didn't make the `std::array` overload take the input by `const` reference:

```
auto recursive_transform(std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
```

Just add `const`! See [this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/n139o1) with the nested `std::array`s working.

## Prefer using `std::begin()` and `std::end()`

It doesn't really matter if you only want to support containers from the standard library, but when writing templates, prefer using [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) instead of `->begin()` and `->end()`. The advantage is that if you are using a non-standard container somewhere that doesn't provide `begin()` and `end()` member functions, it will still be possible to overload the out-of-class `std::begin()` and `std::end()` functions to add iterator support to that class. If you use it in your algorithm templates, then your algorithms will also support those non-standard classes.