# A recursive_print Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform for std::vector with various return type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251132/231235) and [A recursive_transform for std::array with various return type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251171/231235). Based on these discussion about the recursive things, the another idea comes up in my mind that trying to implement a print function for arbitrary nested iterable things. Normally, the multiple `for` loops may be used for printing nested iterables. Maybe like this one.

```
std::vector<double> testVector1;
testVector1.push_back(1);
testVector1.push_back(20);
testVector1.push_back(-100);

decltype(testVector1) testVector2;
testVector2.push_back(10);
testVector2.push_back(90);
testVector2.push_back(-30);

std::vector<decltype(testVector1)> testVector3;
testVector3.push_back(testVector1);
testVector3.push_back(testVector2);

for (auto& outer_element : testVector3)
{
    for (auto& inner_element : outer_element)
    {
        std::cout << inner_element << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, the multiple nested `for` loop shows up when it comes to the case like `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<...>>>>`.

If the structure similar to `recursive_transform` is used in this task, that's the `recursive_print` function here.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_elements_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::begin(x)->begin();
    std::end(x)->end();
};

template<class T> requires is_iterable<T>
T recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [level](auto& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class T> requires is_iterable<T> && is_elements_iterable<T>
T recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(),
        [level](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}
```

[Here's a Godbolt link.](https://godbolt.org/z/G4ds3v) The output of the example is as below. The nested level is also displaying with this `recursive_print` function.

```
Level 0:
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
  1
  20
  -100
  Level 2:
  10
  90
  -30
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
  1
  20
  -100
  Level 2:
  10
  90
  -30
```

All suggestions are welcome.

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform for std::vector with various return type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251132/231235) and

  [A recursive_transform for std::array with various return type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251171/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The previous questions focus on the input/output content and type, but the print out operation is the main idea here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement about this code, please let me know.