# A Function Applier for Applying Various Algorithms on Nested Container Things in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, c++20, variadic

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_replace_if Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254332/231235), [A recursive_copy_if Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254178/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235) and [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235). After implemented `recursive_replace_if` and `recursive_copy_if`, I am trying to generalize the operation of applying a function on elements in nested container. The unwrap level parameter is used here instead of `std::invocable` as the termination condition of the recursion process.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation is as below.

```
//  recursive_function_applier implementation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, std::ranges::range Range, class... Args>
constexpr auto recursive_function_applier(const F& function, const Range& input, Args... args)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level >= 1)
    {
        Range output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&function, &args...](auto&& element) { return recursive_function_applier<unwrap_level - 1>(function, element, args...); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        Range output{};
        function(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            args...);
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

- Test cases with using [`std::ranges::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/copy) function

  ```
  //  std::copy test cases
  //  std::vector<int>
  std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_vector));

  //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::copy, test_vector2));

  //  std::vector<std::string>
  std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<0>(
          std::ranges::copy, test_string_vector
      )
  );

  //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<1>(
          std::ranges::copy, test_string_vector2
      )
  );

  //  std::deque<int>
  std::deque<int> test_deque;
  test_deque.push_back(1);
  test_deque.push_back(2);
  test_deque.push_back(3);
  test_deque.push_back(4);
  test_deque.push_back(5);
  test_deque.push_back(6);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_deque));

  //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
  std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::copy, test_deque2));

  //  std::list<int>
  std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_list));


  //  std::list<std::list<int>>
  std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::copy, test_list2));

  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<10>(
          std::ranges::copy,
          n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3)
          )
  );
  ```
- Test cases with using [`std::ranges::replace_copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/replace_copy) function

  ```
  //  std::ranges::replace_copy_if test cases
  //  std::vector<int>
  std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_vector, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5), 55));

  //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_vector2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5), 55));

  //  std::vector<std::string>
  std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<0>(
          std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_string_vector, [](std::string x) { return (x == "1"); }, "11"
      )
  );

  //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<1>(
          std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_string_vector2, [](std::string x) { return (x == "1"); }, "11"
      )
  );

  //  std::deque<int>
  std::deque<int> test_deque;
  test_deque.push_back(1);
  test_deque.push_back(2);
  test_deque.push_back(3);
  test_deque.push_back(4);
  test_deque.push_back(5);
  test_deque.push_back(6);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_deque, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));

  //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
  std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_deque2, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));

  //  std::list<int>
  std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_list, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));


  //  std::list<std::list<int>>
  std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_list2, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));

  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<10>(
          std::ranges::replace_copy_if,
          n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3),
          [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; },
          0
          )
  );
  ```
- Test cases with using [`std::ranges::remove_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/remove_copy) function

  ```
  //  std::remove_copy test cases
  //  std::vector<int>
  std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_vector, 5));

  //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_vector2, 5));

  //  std::vector<std::string>
  std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<0>(
          std::ranges::remove_copy, test_string_vector, "0"
      )
  );

  //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<1>(
          std::ranges::remove_copy, test_string_vector2, "0"
      )
  );

  //  std::deque<int>
  std::deque<int> test_deque;
  test_deque.push_back(1);
  test_deque.push_back(2);
  test_deque.push_back(3);
  test_deque.push_back(4);
  test_deque.push_back(5);
  test_deque.push_back(6);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_deque, 1));

  //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
  std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_deque2, 1));

  //  std::list<int>
  std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_list, 1));


  //  std::list<std::list<int>>
  std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_list2, 1));

  recursive_print(
      recursive_function_applier<10>(
          std::ranges::remove_copy,
          n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3),
          1
          )
  );
  ```
- Test cases with using [`std::ranges::remove_copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) function

  ```
  //  std::remove_copy_if test cases
  //  std::vector<int>
  std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_vector, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

  //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_vector2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

  //  std::vector<std::string>
  std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
  recursive_print(
    recursive_function_applier<0>(
        std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_string_vector, [](std::string x) { return (x == "0"); }
    )
  );

  //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
  std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
  recursive_print(
    recursive_function_applier<1>(
        std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_string_vector2, [](std::string x) { return (x == "0"); }
    )
  );

  //  std::deque<int>
  std::deque<int> test_deque;
  test_deque.push_back(1);
  test_deque.push_back(2);
  test_deque.push_back(3);
  test_deque.push_back(4);
  test_deque.push_back(5);
  test_deque.push_back(6);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_deque, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

  //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
  std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_deque2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

  //  std::list<int>
  std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_list, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));


  //  std::list<std::list<int>>
  std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
  recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_list2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

  recursive_print(
    recursive_function_applier<5>(
        std::ranges::remove_copy_if,
        n_dim_container_generator<5, std::list>(test_list, 3),
        std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)
        )
  );
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A Function Applier for Applying Various Algorithms on Nested Container Things in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <execution>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept is_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::inserter(x, std::ranges::end(x));
};

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};
#endif

//  recursive_copy_if function 
template <std::ranges::input_range Range, std::invocable<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>> UnaryPredicate>
constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    Range output{};
    std::ranges::copy_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        unary_predicate);
    return output;
}

template <
    std::ranges::input_range Range,
    class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    Range output{};
    
    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&unary_predicate](auto&& element) { return recursive_copy_if(element, unary_predicate); }
        );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_count implementation
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), target);
}

//  transform_reduce version
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), target);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [execution_policy, target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(execution_policy, element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires ((std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>))
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, std::ranges::range T, class Pred>
auto recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 1)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, predicate);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return std::count_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), predicate);
    }
}

//  recursive_function_applier implementation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, std::ranges::range Range, class... Args>
constexpr auto recursive_function_applier(const F& function, const Range& input, Args... args)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level >= 1)
    {
        Range output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&function, &args...](auto&& element) { return recursive_function_applier<unwrap_level - 1>(function, element, args...); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        Range output{};
        function(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            args...);
        return output;
    }
}

//  recursive_print implementation
template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr auto recursive_print(const Range& input, const int level = 0)
{
    auto output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range> requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const Range& input, const int level = 0)
{
    auto output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_replace_copy_if implementation
template<std::ranges::range Range, std::invocable<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>> UnaryPredicate, class T>
constexpr auto recursive_replace_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate, const T& new_value)
{
    Range output{};
    std::ranges::replace_copy_if(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        unary_predicate,
        new_value);
    return output;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range, class UnaryPredicate, class T>
requires (!std::invocable<UnaryPredicate, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_replace_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate, const T& new_value)
{
    Range output{};

    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&unary_predicate, &new_value](auto&& element) { return recursive_replace_copy_if(element, unary_predicate, new_value); }
    );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_size implementation
template<class T> requires (!std::ranges::range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return 1;
}

template<std::ranges::range Range> requires (!(std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>))
constexpr auto recursive_size(const Range& input)
{
    return std::ranges::size(input);
}

template<std::ranges::range Range> requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const Range& input)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [](auto& element) {
        return recursive_size(element);
        });
}

//  recursive_transform implementation
//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
//  from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504127/6667035
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>> &&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>> &&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

template <std::ranges::range Range>
constexpr auto get_output_iterator(Range& output)
{
    return std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output));
}

template <class T, std::invocable<T> F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return std::invoke(f, input);        //  use std::invoke() instead, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283364/231235
}

template <
    std::ranges::input_range Range,
    class F>
requires (!std::invocable<F, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Range& input, const F& f)
{
    recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Range> output{};
    
    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform(element, f); }
        );
    return output;
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
    }
}

void copy_test();
void replace_copy_if_test();
void remove_copy_test();
void remove_copy_if_test();

int main()
{
    copy_test();
    replace_copy_if_test();
    remove_copy_test();
    remove_copy_if_test();
    return 0;
}

void copy_test()
{
    //  std::copy test cases
    //  std::vector<int>
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_vector));

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::copy, test_vector2));

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<0>(
            std::ranges::copy, test_string_vector
        )
    );

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<1>(
            std::ranges::copy, test_string_vector2
        )
    );

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_deque));

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::copy, test_deque2));

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_list));


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::copy, test_list2));

    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<5>(
            std::ranges::copy,
            n_dim_container_generator<5, std::list>(test_list, 3)
            )
    );
    return;
}

void replace_copy_if_test()
{
    //  std::ranges::replace_copy_if test cases
    //  std::vector<int>
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_vector, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5), 55));

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_vector2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5), 55));

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<0>(
            std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_string_vector, [](std::string x) { return (x == "1"); }, "11"
        )
    );

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<1>(
            std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_string_vector2, [](std::string x) { return (x == "1"); }, "11"
        )
    );

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_deque, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_deque2, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_list, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::replace_copy_if, test_list2, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }, 0));

    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<5>(
            std::ranges::replace_copy_if,
            n_dim_container_generator<5, std::list>(test_list, 3),
            [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; },
            0
            )
    );
    return;
}

void remove_copy_test()
{
    //  std::remove_copy test cases
    //  std::vector<int>
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_vector, 5));

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_vector2, 5));

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<0>(
            std::ranges::remove_copy, test_string_vector, "0"
        )
    );

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<1>(
            std::ranges::remove_copy, test_string_vector2, "0"
        )
    );

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_deque, 1));

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_deque2, 1));

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_list, 1));


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy, test_list2, 1));

    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<5>(
            std::ranges::remove_copy,
            n_dim_container_generator<5, std::list>(test_list, 3),
            1
            )
    );
    return;
}

void remove_copy_if_test()
{
    //  std::remove_copy_if test cases
    //  std::vector<int>
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_vector, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_vector2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<0>(
            std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_string_vector, [](std::string x) { return (x == "0"); }
        )
    );

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<1>(
            std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_string_vector2, [](std::string x) { return (x == "0"); }
        )
    );

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_deque, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_deque2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_list, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    recursive_print(recursive_function_applier<1>(std::ranges::remove_copy_if, test_list2, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)));

    recursive_print(
        recursive_function_applier<5>(
            std::ranges::remove_copy_if,
            n_dim_container_generator<5, std::list>(test_list, 3),
            std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 5)
            )
    );
    return;
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/x5Ks59rej)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_replace_if Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254332/231235),

  [A recursive_copy_if Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254178/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235) and

  [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement a `recursive_function_applier` template function as a function applier for applying various algorithms on nested container.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Not sure the design of `recursive_function_applier` template function is a good idea or not. Whatever, this structure seems to be working fine in `std::ranges::copy`, `std::ranges::replace_copy_if`, `std::ranges::remove_copy` and `std::ranges::remove_copy_if` cases. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What does it do?

> I am trying to generalize the operation of applying a function on elements in nested container.

If you say that, I would think that [your `recursive_transform()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283546/129343) would already cover it. It seems that this "function applier" is actually more a "container algorithm applier"; it recurses a nested container to a given level, expects that every element at that point is also a container, and then calls the given function, expecting it to have a similar interface as STL algorithms such as [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy): they get two input iterators and an output iterator as arguments.

## An alternative approach

I think the only reason for this function is to deal with the fact that STL algorithms never return a container. You could say that they are not working in a [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style. If they did, then you could just easily compose your `recursive_transform()` with a `copy()` function that does return a container. So maybe you should make those instead? Consider:

```
struct SameAsInput;

template<typename Output = SameAsInput, typename Input>
auto return_copy(const Input& input) {
     std::conditional_t<
         std::is_same_v<Output, SameAsInput>,
         Input,
         Output
     > output;
     std::ranges::copy(input, std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)));
     return output;
}
```

Then instead of:

```
recursive_function_applier<0>(std::ranges::copy, test_vector);
```

You could write:

```
recursive_transform<0>(test_vector, return_copy);
```

You can make `return_copy_n()`, `return_remove_copy()`, `return_remove_copy_if()`, and so on.

## Restricting the container type

You are using the concept [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) to restrict the type of `input`. However, you want to create a container that has the same type of `input`, and not every range is a container. For example, views are ranges too. Unfortunately, there is no `std::container` concept, but you can [make one yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60449592/5481471).