# A recursive_copy_if Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_copy_if Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254178/231235) and [recursive_invocable and recursive_project_invocable Concept Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/289531/231235). I am trying to implement `recursive_copy_if` template function with unwrap level in this post.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_copy_if` Template Function

  ```
  //  recursive_copy_if function implementation with unwrap level
  template <std::size_t unwrap_level, std::ranges::input_range Range, class UnaryPredicate>
  requires(recursive_invocable<unwrap_level, UnaryPredicate, Range>)
  constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
  {
      if constexpr(unwrap_level > 1)
      {
          Range output{};

          std::ranges::transform(
              std::ranges::cbegin(input),
              std::ranges::cend(input),
              std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
              [&unary_predicate](auto&& element) { return recursive_copy_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, unary_predicate); }
              );
          return output;
      }
      else
      {
          Range output{};
          std::ranges::copy_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input),
              std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
              unary_predicate);
          return output;
      }
  }
  ```
- The used `recursive_invocable` concept

  ```
  //  is_recursive_invocable template function implementation
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, class... T>
  requires(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T...>())
  static constexpr bool is_recursive_invocable()
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == 0) {
          return std::invocable<F, T...>;
      } else {
          return is_recursive_invocable<
                      unwrap_level - 1,
                      F,
                      std::ranges::range_value_t<T>...>();
      }
  }

  //  recursive_invocable concept
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, class... T>
  concept recursive_invocable =
          is_recursive_invocable<unwrap_level, F, T...>();
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A recursive_copy_if Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <execution>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept is_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::inserter(x, std::ranges::end(x));
};

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};
#endif

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return std::size_t{0};
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
}

//  recursive_depth template function implementation with target type
template<typename T_Base, typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return std::size_t{0};
}

template<typename T_Base, std::ranges::input_range Range>
requires (!std::same_as<Range, T_Base>)
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<T_Base, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
}

//  is_recursive_invocable template function implementation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, class... T>
requires(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T...>())
static constexpr bool is_recursive_invocable()
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == 0) {
        return std::invocable<F, T...>;
    } else {
        return is_recursive_invocable<
                    unwrap_level - 1,
                    F,
                    std::ranges::range_value_t<T>...>();
    }
}

//  recursive_invocable concept
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, class... T>
concept recursive_invocable =
        is_recursive_invocable<unwrap_level, F, T...>();

//  is_recursive_project_invocable template function implementation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class Proj, class F, class... T>
requires(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T...>() &&
        recursive_invocable<unwrap_level, Proj, T...>)
static constexpr bool is_recursive_project_invocable()
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == 0) {
        return std::invocable<F, std::invoke_result_t<Proj, T...>>;
    } else {
        return is_recursive_project_invocable<
                    unwrap_level - 1,
                    Proj,
                    F,
                    std::ranges::range_value_t<T>...>();
    }
}

//  recursive_project_invocable concept
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class Proj, class F, class... T>
concept recursive_project_invocable =
        is_recursive_project_invocable<unwrap_level, Proj, F, T...>();

//  recursive_copy_if function implementation with unwrap level
template <std::size_t unwrap_level, std::ranges::input_range Range, class UnaryPredicate>
requires(recursive_invocable<unwrap_level, UnaryPredicate, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    if constexpr(unwrap_level > 1)
    {
        Range output{};
    
        std::ranges::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&unary_predicate](auto&& element) { return recursive_copy_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, unary_predicate); }
            );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        Range output{};
        std::ranges::copy_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            unary_predicate);
        return output;
    }
}

//  recursive_print implementation
template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr auto recursive_print(const Range& input, const int level = 0)
{
    auto output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range> requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const Range& input, const int level = 0)
{
    auto output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
//  from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504127/6667035
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>> &&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>> &&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

template <std::ranges::range Range>
constexpr auto get_output_iterator(Range& output)
{
    return std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output));
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
    }
}

//  Copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264642/6667035
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) \
    __M_Assert(#Expr, Expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, Msg)
#else
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) ;
#endif

void __M_Assert(const char* expr_str, bool expr, const char* file, int line, const char* msg)
{
    if (!expr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Assert failed:\t" << msg << "\n"
            << "Expected:\t" << expr_str << "\n"
            << "Source:\t\t" << file << ", line " << line << "\n";
        abort();
    }
}

void recursive_copy_if_tests()
{
    //  std::vector<int> test case
    std::vector<int> test_vector_1 = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    };

    std::vector<int> expected_result_1 = {
        2, 4, 6
    };
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<1>(test_vector_1, [](auto&& x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }) ==
        expected_result_1,
        "std::vector<int> test case failed");

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> test case
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector_1)> test_vector_2 = {
        test_vector_1, test_vector_1, test_vector_1
    };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> expected_result_2 = {
        expected_result_1, expected_result_1, expected_result_1
    };
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<2>(test_vector_2, [](auto&& x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }) ==
        expected_result_2,
        "std::vector<std::vector<int>> test case failed");
    
    //  std::vector<std::string> test case
    std::vector<std::string> test_vector_3 = {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
    };
    std::vector<std::string> expected_result_3 = {
        "1"
    };
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<1>(test_vector_3, [](auto&& x) { return (x == "1"); }) ==
        expected_result_3,
        "std::vector<std::string> test case failed");
    

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> test case
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> test_vector_4 = {
        test_vector_3, test_vector_3, test_vector_3
    };
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> expected_result_4 = {
        expected_result_3, expected_result_3, expected_result_3
    };
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<2>(test_vector_4, [](auto&& x) { return (x == "1"); }) ==
        expected_result_4,
        "std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> test case failed");

    //  std::deque<int> test case
    std::deque<int> test_deque_1;
    test_deque_1.push_back(1);
    test_deque_1.push_back(2);
    test_deque_1.push_back(3);
    test_deque_1.push_back(4);
    test_deque_1.push_back(5);
    test_deque_1.push_back(6);
    std::deque<int> expected_result_5;
    expected_result_5.push_back(1);
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<1>(test_deque_1, [](auto&& x) { return (x == 1); }) ==
        expected_result_5,
        "std::deque<int> test case failed"
    );

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>> test case
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque_1)> test_deque_2;
    test_deque_2.push_back(test_deque_1);
    test_deque_2.push_back(test_deque_1);
    test_deque_2.push_back(test_deque_1);
    std::deque<decltype(expected_result_5)> expected_result_6;
    expected_result_6.push_back(expected_result_5);
    expected_result_6.push_back(expected_result_5);
    expected_result_6.push_back(expected_result_5);
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<2>(test_deque_2, [](auto&& x) { return (x == 1); }) ==
        expected_result_6,
        "std::deque<std::deque<int>> test case failed"
    );

    //  std::list<int> test case
    std::list<int> test_list_1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::list<int> expected_result_7 = {2, 4, 6};
    M_Assert(
        recursive_copy_if<1>(test_list_1, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }) ==
        expected_result_7,
        "std::list<int> test case failed"
    );

    //  std::list<std::list<int>> test case
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list_2 = { test_list_1, test_list_1, test_list_1, test_list_1 };
    std::list<std::list<int>> expected_result_8 = {
        expected_result_7, expected_result_7, expected_result_7, expected_result_7
    };
    M_Assert(
            recursive_copy_if<2>(test_list_2, [](int x) { return (x % 2) == 0; }) ==
            expected_result_8,
            "std::list<std::list<int>> test case failed"
        );
    std::cout << "All tests passed!\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    recursive_copy_if_tests();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
All tests passed!
Computation finished at Fri Mar 29 07:36:41 2024
elapsed time: 0.00130443
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/9dzz8o3zW)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_copy_if Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254178/231235) and

  [recursive_invocable and recursive_project_invocable Concept Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/289531/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement `recursive_copy_if` template function with unwrap level in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review the implementation of `recursive_copy_if` template function and its tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Range` is not just an input range

This is something I missed in my reviews of your previous questions. The parameter `input` is clearly an input range, so it's natural to restrict its type to `std::ranges::input_range`. However, `Range` is also used to create a new object that is used as an output range. So clearly, the constraint it wrong.

You also require that it is a range that you can use `std::inserter()` on.

## What if `unwrap_level == 0`?

From your code I can see that you intend `unwrap_level` to be at least 1. However, what if the caller passes in `0`? I would add a `static_assert()` to catch this case.

Comment: _> However, `Range` is also used to create a new object that is used as an output range._ Which concept should I used in this case?

Comment: There is no `std::ranges::input_and_output_range` unfortunately, you have to create your concept that checks that it is both `std::ranges::input_range` and `is_insertable`.