# A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with std::invocable Concept and Execution Policy in C++

Tags: c++, performance, recursion, lambda, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with `std::invocable` concept in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253556/231235) and [A recursive_transform Template Function with Execution Policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251823/231235). Based on the previous questions, I am trying to consider [execution policy parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) for `recursive_transform` function here.

**The experimental implementation**

```
//  recursive_transform implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, class T, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

//  specific case for std::array
template<class ExPo, class T, std::size_t S, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(execution_policy, *input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [execution_policy, &f](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(execution_policy, element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class ExPo, template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (is_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && !std::invocable<Function, Container<Ts...>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(execution_policy, *input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output(input.size());
    std::mutex mutex;

    std::for_each(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
        [&](auto&& element)
        {
            auto result = recursive_transform(execution_policy, element, f);
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
            output.emplace_back(std::move(result));
        }
    );

    return output;
}

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<class ExPo, is_multi_array T, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (!std::invocable<F, T>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(execution_policy, input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
#endif
```

**Test cases**

```
//  std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>
std::vector<int> test_vector = {
    1, 2, 3
};
std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform(std::execution::par, test_vector, [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }).at(0) << std::endl;


//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
    test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
};
std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform(std::execution::par, test_vector2, [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }).at(0).at(0) << std::endl;

//std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::size_t>
std::cout << "recursive_count_if: " + recursive_transform(std::execution::par, test_vector2, [](std::vector<int> x) {
    return std::to_string(recursive_count_if(x, [](int number) { return number == 3; }));
    }).at(0) << std::endl;
```

The full testing code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <execution>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept is_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::inserter(x, std::ranges::end(x));
};

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};
#endif

//  recursive_count implementation
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), target);
}

//  transform_reduce version
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(), target);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [execution_policy, target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(execution_policy, element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires ((std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>))
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    });
}

//  recursive_transform implementation
template<class T, std::invocable<T> F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

//  specific case for std::array
template<class T, std::size_t S, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [&f](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && !std::invocable<Function, Container<Ts...>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;

    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );

    return output;
}

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<is_multi_array T, class F>
requires(!std::invocable<F, T>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
#endif

//  recursive_transform implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, class T, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

//  specific case for std::array
template<class ExPo, class T, std::size_t S, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(execution_policy, *input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [execution_policy, &f](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(execution_policy, element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class ExPo, template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (is_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && !std::invocable<Function, Container<Ts...>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(execution_policy, *input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output(input.size());
    std::mutex mutex;

    std::for_each(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
        [&](auto&& element)
        {
            auto result = recursive_transform(execution_policy, element, f);
            std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
            output.emplace_back(std::move(result));
        }
    );

    return output;
}

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<class ExPo, is_multi_array T, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (!std::invocable<F, T>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(execution_policy, input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
#endif

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
    }
}

int main()
{
    //  std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<int> test_vector = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform(std::execution::par, test_vector, [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }).at(0) << std::endl;


    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
        test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
    };
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform(std::execution::par, test_vector2, [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }).at(0).at(0) << std::endl;

    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::size_t>
    std::cout << "recursive_count_if: " + recursive_transform(std::execution::par, test_vector2, [](std::vector<int> x) {
        return std::to_string(recursive_count_if(x, [](int number) { return number == 3; }));
        }).at(0) << std::endl;

    //  std::deque<int> -> std::deque<std::string>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);

    auto recursive_transform_result3 = recursive_transform(
        std::execution::par,
        test_deque,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result3.at(0) << std::endl;


    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>> -> std::deque<std::deque<std::string>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

    auto recursive_transform_result4 = recursive_transform(
        std::execution::par,
        test_deque2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result4.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;


    //  std::array<int, 10> -> std::array<std::string, 10>
    std::array<int, 10> test_array;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test_array[i] = 1;
    }
    auto recursive_transform_result5 = recursive_transform(
        std::execution::par,
        test_array,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result5.at(0) << std::endl;

    //  std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> -> std::array<std::array<std::string, 10>, 10>
    std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> test_array2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test_array2[i] = test_array;
    }
    auto recursive_transform_result6 = recursive_transform(
        std::execution::par,
        test_array2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result6.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;


    //  std::list<int> -> std::list<std::string>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto recursive_transform_result7 = recursive_transform(
        std::execution::par,
        test_list,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result7.front() << std::endl;


    //  std::list<std::list<int>> -> std::list<std::list<std::string>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    auto recursive_transform_result8 = recursive_transform(
        std::execution::par,
        test_list2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result8.front().front() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/9h5M53)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with `std::invocable` concept in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253556/231235) and

  [A recursive_transform Template Function with Execution Policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251823/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  Considering [execution policy parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) for `recursive_transform` function.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I tried to add `execution_policy` parameter based on the previous experimental implementation first. If there is any possible improvement about the part of execution policy, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope someone else can have a look at the use of the mutex. Just some small things I'll note here:

## Prefer using `{}` over `0` when you don't know the type

If you don't know the type of something, don't assume that `0` is implicitly convertible to an element of that type. Prefer default-constructing it in that case. So instead of:

```
for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
```

Write:

```
for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i{}; i != input.shape()[0]; ++i)
```

Also note that I used `!=` instead of `<` here, as well as the pre-increment operator. If you already assume it's an integer, then I'd not use `decltype` here but just write `std::size_t i = 0`, to make this clear.

## Missing test cases

I don't see `std::vector<std::string>` being used as the input in any of the test cases. This is a very important case to test.