# A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with std::invocable concept in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253556/231235) and [A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with recursive_invoke_result_t and std::ranges::transform in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254096/231235). Besides the version using `std::invocable`, I am attempting to implement another type `recursive_transform` function with the unwrap level parameter so that the usage like `recursive_transform<1>(Ranges, Lambda)` is available.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `recursive_transform` function with the unwrap level parameter is as follows.

```
//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
    struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return f(input);
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

```
//  non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
int test_number = 3;
std::cout << recursive_transform<0>(test_number, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; }) << std::endl;

//  nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
std::vector<int> test_vector = {
    1, 2, 3
};
std::cout << recursive_transform<0>(test_vector, [](auto element)
    {
        element.push_back(4);
        element.push_back(5);
        return element;
    }).size() << std::endl;

//  std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>
auto recursive_transform_result = recursive_transform<1>(
    test_vector,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
);                                                                                  //  For testing

std::cout << "std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: " +
    recursive_transform_result.at(0) << std::endl;                                  //  recursive_transform_result.at(0) is a std::string

//  std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>
std::cout << "std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: " 
    << recursive_transform<1>(
        recursive_transform_result,
        [](std::string x) { return std::atoi(x.c_str()); }).at(0) + 1 << std::endl; //  std::string element to int

//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
    test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
};

auto recursive_transform_result2 = recursive_transform<2>(
    test_vector2,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
);                                                                                  //  For testing

std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result2.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;     // recursive_transform_result.at(0).at(0) is also a std::string

//  std::deque<int> -> std::deque<std::string>
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(1);

auto recursive_transform_result3 = recursive_transform<1>(
    test_deque,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result3.at(0) << std::endl;

//  std::deque<std::deque<int>> -> std::deque<std::deque<std::string>>
std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

auto recursive_transform_result4 = recursive_transform<2>(
    test_deque2,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result4.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;

//  std::list<int> -> std::list<std::string>
std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto recursive_transform_result5 = recursive_transform<1>(
    test_list,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result5.front() << std::endl;


//  std::list<std::list<int>> -> std::list<std::list<std::string>>
std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
auto recursive_transform_result6 = recursive_transform<2>(
    test_list2,
    [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result6.front().front() << std::endl;
```

The output of the test code above:

```
4
5
std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: 1
std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: 2
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
    struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return f(input);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //  non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    int test_number = 3;
    std::cout << recursive_transform<0>(test_number, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; }) << std::endl;

    //  nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    std::vector<int> test_vector = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    std::cout << recursive_transform<0>(test_vector, [](auto element)
        {
            element.push_back(4);
            element.push_back(5);
            return element;
        }).size() << std::endl;

    //  std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>
    auto recursive_transform_result = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_vector,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
    );                                                                                  //  For testing

    std::cout << "std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: " +
        recursive_transform_result.at(0) << std::endl;                                  //  recursive_transform_result.at(0) is a std::string
    
    //  std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>
    std::cout << "std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: " 
        << recursive_transform<1>(
            recursive_transform_result,
            [](std::string x) { return std::atoi(x.c_str()); }).at(0) + 1 << std::endl; //  std::string element to int

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
        test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
    };

    auto recursive_transform_result2 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_vector2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
    );                                                                                  //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result2.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;     // recursive_transform_result.at(0).at(0) is also a std::string

    //  std::deque<int> -> std::deque<std::string>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);

    auto recursive_transform_result3 = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_deque,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result3.at(0) << std::endl;

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>> -> std::deque<std::deque<std::string>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

    auto recursive_transform_result4 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_deque2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result4.at(0).at(0) << std::endl;

    //  std::list<int> -> std::list<std::string>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto recursive_transform_result5 = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_list,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result5.front() << std::endl;


    //  std::list<std::list<int>> -> std::list<std::list<std::string>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    auto recursive_transform_result6 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_list2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result6.front().front() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/bYvdKnfex)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with std::invocable concept in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253556/231235) and

  [A recursive_transform Template Function Implementation with recursive_invoke_result_t and std::ranges::transform in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254096/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The type `recursive_transform` function with the unwrap level parameter is the main idea here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `std::invoke()`

I missed this in my reviews of your earlier code, but `std::invoke(f, a)` is not always the same as `f(a)`. And especially if you use `std::invoke_result_t` to deduce the return type of calling `f`, you should use [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

## Pass a range to `std::ranges::transform()`

The nice thing about `std::ranges` algorithms is that they can take a range as a parameter instead of two iterators. So I would write:

```
std::ranges::transform(
    input,
    std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
);
```

## Missing support for arrays and some other container types

Your `recursive_invoke_result` does not handle `std::array<>` and regular arrays. Recently, user Davislor created a recursive transform implementation based on your code that does handle this, see [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283123/129343).

## Try to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully

If `unwrap_level` is higher than the nesting level of the given container, then a compile error will happen when trying to call `std::ranges::cbegin()` on a non-container value. This happens deep within nested calls to `recursive_transform()`, so it will probably produce a horrible error message. It might be possible to add a `requires` clause that checks right at the outer call whether `unwrap_level` is not higher than the nesting level of `input`. If not, then a `static_assert()` would be another option.