# A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for std::array Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257757/231235). I am following the suggestions proposed by [G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/129343/g-sliepen) in [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283364/231235). The techniques including passing a range to `std::ranges::transform()` and using [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) are performed in the updated version `recursive_transform` implementation. On the other hand, `recursive_depth` function is used here for handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully. For dealing with [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) type, another overload is proposed.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `recursive_transform` function with the unwrap level parameter is as follows.

- `recursive_transform` function implementation

  ```
  //  recursive_transform function implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
  constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
      {
          static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
              "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");   //  trying to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully
          recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
          std::ranges::transform(
              input,                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
              std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
              [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
          );
          return output;
      }
      else
      {
          return std::invoke(f, input);  //   use std::invoke()
      }
  }

  /* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array.
  */
  template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
            template<class T, std::size_t> class Container,
            typename F,
            typename T,
            std::size_t N >
  requires is_iterable<Container<T, N>>
  constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
  {
      Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

      std::transform( std::begin(input),
                      std::end(input),
                      std::begin(output),
                      [f](auto &x){ return std::invoke(f, x); }
                    );

      return output;
  }
  ```
- `recursive_depth` helper function implementation

  ```
  //  recursive_depth function implementation
  template<typename T>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return 0;
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for std::array Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
    struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
            "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");   //  trying to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            input,                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::invoke(f, input);  //   use std::invoke()
    }
}

/* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
 */
template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
          template<class T, std::size_t> class Container,
          typename F,
          typename T,
          std::size_t N >
requires is_iterable<Container<T, N>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
{
    Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

    std::transform( std::begin(input),
                    std::end(input),
                    std::begin(output),
                    [f](auto &x){ return std::invoke(f, x); }
                );

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    //  non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    int test_number = 3;
    std::cout << "non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly: \n"
              << recursive_transform<0>(test_number, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; }) << '\n';

    //  test with array container
    static constexpr std::size_t D = 3;
    auto test_array = std::array< double, D >{1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << "test with array container: \n"
              << recursive_transform<1>(test_array, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; })[0] << '\n';

    //  nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    std::vector<int> test_vector = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    std::cout << recursive_transform<0>(test_vector, [](auto element)
        {
            element.push_back(4);
            element.push_back(5);
            return element;
        }).size() << '\n';

    //  std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>
    auto recursive_transform_result = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_vector,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
    );                                                                                  //  For testing

    std::cout << "std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: " +
        recursive_transform_result.at(0) << '\n';                                  //  recursive_transform_result.at(0) is a std::string
    
    //  std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>
    std::cout << "std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: " 
        << recursive_transform<1>(
            recursive_transform_result,
            [](std::string x) { return std::atoi(x.c_str()); }).at(0) + 1 << '\n'; //  std::string element to int

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
        test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
    };

    auto recursive_transform_result2 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_vector2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
    );                                                                                  //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result2.at(0).at(0) << '\n';     // recursive_transform_result.at(0).at(0) is also a std::string

    //  std::deque<int> -> std::deque<std::string>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);

    auto recursive_transform_result3 = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_deque,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result3.at(0) << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>> -> std::deque<std::deque<std::string>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

    auto recursive_transform_result4 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_deque2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result4.at(0).at(0) << '\n';

    //  std::list<int> -> std::list<std::string>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto recursive_transform_result5 = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_list,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result5.front() << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>> -> std::list<std::list<std::string>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    auto recursive_transform_result6 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_list2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result6.front().front() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly: 
4
test with array container: 
2
5
std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: 1
std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: 2
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/sTThPeGsW)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257757/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement another version `recursive_transform` template function for dealing with various types including [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just getting better and better!

## Use a constraint instead of `static_assert()`

You can trivially turn the `static_assert()` you have in `recursive_transform()` into a constraint:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    …
}
```

The problem with the `static_assert()` is that it only triggers when your function has already recursed as much as possible. The error message that the compilers generate will then be quite large. By using a `requires` clause, the mistake is caught immediately at the outer call to `recursive_transform()`, resulting in a much shorter error message. The only drawback is that you cannot include a custom error message in this case. Here is the number of lines of error messages for each method at a given recursion depth:

| Method @ depth | GCC 12 | Clang 17 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `requires` @ 1 | 22 | 19 |
| `requires` @ 2 | 34 | 19 |
| `requires` @ 3 | 30 | 19 |
| `static_assert` @ 1 | 30 | 46 |
| `static_assert` @ 2 | 114 | 68 |
| `static_assert` @ 3 | 138 | 105 |

## Use only one method to check if a type is a container

You currently have two ways to check if a type is a container: `std::ranges::input_range` and `is_iterable`. These are slightly different, and it's best to use only one of them, on the off-chance that there is a type which satisfies one but not the other, as I imagine this would cause some very hard to debug compiler error.

I think you can just write:

```
template<…>
requires std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
{
    …
}
```

## Use `std::ranges::transform()` for `std::array`s as well

For the overload that handles `std::array`, you can use `std::ranges::transform()` just like you did in the more generic overload.

## Nested `std::array`s are not handled

Your code does not handle `std::array`s that contain other containers, including other `std::array`s.

Ideally, there is only one overload of `recursive_transform()` that handles all container types. `recursive_invoke_result_t<>` should handle arrays. The only other issue is that there is no `std::inserter<>` that works on arrays. You can add some `if constexpr` code to handle that difference, or create a `struct recursive_output_iterator<>` to give you the right output iterator.

## Call `reserve()` if possible

Some containers have a `reserve()` member function (like `std::vector` and `std::deque`), and it would help performance a lot if you called it.

## What if the input is an rvalue?

Something we haven't looked at is if it makes sense to handle inputs that are rvalues. In case the function we are passing has a return type that is the same as its input, then you can just `std::transform()` the innermost containers in-place. If not, then there still is the possibility of moving the original values in the input into the function that is being applied. I don't think even `std::ranges::transform()` does that though.

## Handling non-default-constructible containers

You are currently assuming that once you have determined the type of a container using `recursive_invoke_result_t<>`, that you can default-construct a new container. However, that might not be the case; for example, if an allocator is used that doesn't have a default constructor.

Most STL containers have a [`get_allocator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/get_allocator) member function that will return the allocater object that was used to construct it. You can pass that to the container you want to construct. Of course, that means an increase in complexity of your code. Ideally, you would create an out-of-class function that can create an empty copy of any container, so that you can write:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        auto output = clone_empty_container(input);
        std::ranges::transform(
            input,
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::invoke(f, input);
    }
}
```

You could even consider having it handle comparator and hash objects passed to containers like `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, call `reserve()` based on the size of the input, handle container adapters like `std::stack()` that take a container as a parameter in the constructor, and maybe even upcoming types like [`std::flat_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/flat_set).

Answer (score 1):

### The Inserter Fails on Most STL Structures

In particular, `std::inserter` assumes that the container has a `push_back` member function, but even within the STL, that is not the case.  Some examples of its patterns:

- `std::vector` has `.push_back` and `.emplace_back`
- `std::basic_string` has only `.push_back`
- `std:forward_list` has `.push_front()`, `.insert_after()`, and `.emplace_after` and for this purpose, you would want to iteratively`.insert_after()`.
- `std::set` has `.emplace_hint`, `.emplace` and `insert`.
- `std::map` inserts key-value pairs
- `std::array` is a fixed size and does not support insertion, but can be the target of `std::transform` without resizing.  Try that with `std::vector`, and the function will silently stop filling the `vector` when it runs out of room.
- Built-in arrays, such as `int a[10]`, have no member functions, but `std::begin()` and `std::end()` do work on them.

### Define Concepts to Test for the Type of Container

For example, in an earlier solution I posted to this, I defined the following concept:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept is_sized = requires(T x)
{
    x.size();
};
```

Which allowed me to implement the following sanity-check as an `if constexpr` expression:

```
// One last sanity check.
if constexpr( is_sized<Container<Ts...>> && is_sized<OutputC> ) {
    assert( output.size() == input.size() );
}
```

### You Don’t Need Recursive Depth as a Template Parameter

There are only two cases: container, and an object in the domain of the transformation function.¹  These can be detected by overloads with `requires` clauses, or where the type is declared to match a `concept`.  An example of both:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};


template< template<typename...> typename Container,
          typename F,
          typename... Ts >
  requires is_iterable<Container<Ts...>>
inline auto traverse ( const Container<Ts...>& input, const F& f );


/* Base case for traversal: a single input to the transformation function.
 */
template< typename T,
          std::invocable<T> F >
constexpr auto traverse( const T& input, const F& f )
{
    return std::invoke( f, input );
}
```

¹ *Pedantic note: G. Sliepen points out in a comment that the base case might itself be a container, but this implementation will work, so long as the transformation function is strongly-typed enough that it matches only the proper type of container.  So, for example, an `auto container_sum(const auto&)` might fail, but the following should work:*

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <numeric>

template<typename T>
concept is_additive = requires(T x) {
  {x + x} -> std::same_as<T>;
};

template<template<typename, typename...> class C, typename T, typename... Ts>
  requires is_iterable<C<T, Ts...>> &&
           is_additive<T> &&
           std::default_initializable<T>
constexpr T container_sum(const C<T, Ts...>& input)
{
  return std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), T(), std::plus<T>{});
}
```

*Or, instead of writing out all the template trait bounds, you could just specify the template to use: `container_sum<std::vector<double>>`.*

### Arrays Need Special Handling

A function cannot return a built-in array (such as `int a[10]`).  If you want your recursive traversal to accept these, it must convert these to `std::array` on output.

The size parameter of `std::array` also breaks template deduction, but an overload can take care of that.

### You Can Use a Transforming View

In C++20, you can get around both the different, incompatible container interfaces and the problem of some containers not being default-constructible by constructing the output container from iterators generated by a `std::ranges::transform_view` of the input.

That is, you can construct a view of the entirety of the input container, pass it through an adapter that transforms the inputs, and pass those transformed iterators to the constructors of most containers in the STL.

There are some exceptions for which that still would not work.  In particular, a `std::map` would require another overload to be able to traverse a key-value pair, and arrays still need special handling.  This is also bleeding-edge enough that it works on GCC 12.2 and the latest development version of Clang, but not (as of 2022) either `libstdc++` or `libc++` using Clang 15.0.0.

```cpp
// The recursive case.
template< template<typename...> typename Container,
          typename F,
          typename... Ts >
  requires is_iterable<Container<Ts...>>
inline auto traverse ( const Container<Ts...>& input, const F& f )
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(traverse(*std::begin(input), f));
    using OutputC = Container<TransformedValueType>;

    const auto view = std::ranges::transform_view(
      std::ranges::subrange( std::begin(input), std::end(input) ),
      [f](const auto& x)constexpr{ return traverse( x, f ); } );
    OutputC output( view.begin(), view.end() );

    // One last sanity check.
    if constexpr( is_sized<Container<Ts...>> && is_sized<OutputC> ) {
        assert( output.size() == input.size() );
    }

    return output;
}
```

### Putting it All Together

This is a rework of [an earlier answer of mine.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283123/136816).

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>   // std::invocable
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <functional> // invoke, negate
#include <iterator>   // begin, end
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

static constexpr std::size_t D = 3;
using row_t = std::array< double, D >;
using point_matrix = std::vector<row_t>;


template<class T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

template<class T>
concept is_sized = requires(T x)
{
    x.size();
};


// Prototypes in case we ever want to nest in the opposite order.
template< template<typename...> typename Container,
          typename F,
          typename... Ts >
  requires is_iterable<Container<Ts...>>
inline auto traverse ( const Container<Ts...>& input, const F& f );

template< template<class T, std::size_t> class Container,
          typename F,
          typename T,
          std::size_t N >
  requires is_iterable<Container<T, N>>
constexpr auto traverse( const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f );

template< typename T,
          typename F,
          std::size_t N >
constexpr auto traverse( const T(&input)[N], const F& f );

/* Base case for traversal: a single input to the transformation function.
 */
template< typename T,
          std::invocable<T> F >
constexpr auto traverse( const T& input, const F& f )
{
    return std::invoke( f, input );
}

/* This overload was needed to support traversing std::array.
 */
template< template<class T, std::size_t> class Container,
          typename F,
          typename T,
          std::size_t N >
  requires is_iterable<Container<T, N>>
constexpr auto traverse( const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f )
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(traverse(*std::begin(input), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType, N> output;

    std::transform( std::begin(input),
                    std::end(input),
                    std::begin(output),
                    [f](auto &x){ return traverse( x, f ); }
                  );

    return output;
}

/* Since C++ does not allow functions to return built-in arrays, we transform
 * them into std::array objects instead.
 */
template< typename T,
          typename F,
          std::size_t N >
constexpr auto traverse( const T(&input)[N], const F& f )
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(traverse(*std::begin(input), f));
    std::array< TransformedValueType, N > output;

    std::transform( std::begin(input),
                    std::end(input),
                    std::begin(output),
                    [f](auto &x){ return traverse( x, f ); }
                  );

    return output;
}

/* The recursive case.
 */
template< template<typename...> typename Container,
          typename F,
          typename... Ts >
  requires is_iterable<Container<Ts...>>
inline auto traverse ( const Container<Ts...>& input, const F& f )
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(traverse(*std::begin(input), f));
    using OutputC = Container<TransformedValueType>;

    const auto view = std::ranges::transform_view(
      std::ranges::subrange( std::begin(input), std::end(input) ),
      [f](const auto& x)constexpr{ return traverse( x, f ); } );
    OutputC output( view.begin(), view.end() );

    // One last sanity check.
    if constexpr( is_sized<Container<Ts...>> && is_sized<OutputC> ) {
        assert( output.size() == input.size() );
    }

    return output;
}


auto negative_points(const point_matrix &points) {
  return traverse( points, std::negate<double>{} );
}

int main() {

    const point_matrix points{
        {0, 0, 4},
        {0, 5, 3},
        {1, 7, 0},
        {2, 1, 4},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {4, 2, 3},
        {4, 4, 6},
        {4, 6, 7},
        {5, 0, 2},
        {6, 4, 1},
        {6, 5, 1},
        {6, 7, 0},
        {7, 4, 3}
    };

    fmt::print("Original: {}\n", points);
    fmt::print("Negative: {}\n", negative_points(points));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: *“There are only two cases: container, and an object in the domain of the transformation function.“* This is not true. You might have a transformation function that works on containers. For example, maybe you want to replace each innermost container with the sum of its values. And consider that `std::string` is a container.

Comment: @G.Sliepen That example might be a good reason for me to re-word my justification, but I don’t think it breaks my code. If you pass in a `R f(Container<T>)` and a `Container<Container<T>>`, only the recursive template matches, and it calls `traverse<Container<T>, F>`. That recursive call matches the base case, because `f` is invocable on `Container<T>`. This does not attempt to call `traverse` recursively, nor would `traverse<U, F>` match the `requires` clauses. It just invokes `f` on its `Container<T>` arguments and passes the result back up to the caller, which adds it to a `Container<R>`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen This implementation could indeed break on`std::string`. That’s because `std::string` has no `.emplace_back`, nor does the fallback I wrote work correctly because it cannot `.resize`. I believe I mentioned this in a comment to my original answer, but you’re correct that I didn’t cover that case. Of course, `std::inserter` breaks on different STL containers.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I think a more general solution would be to use `std::ranges::views::transform` or `std::ranges::transform_view` to generate an iterator pair, which then gets used to construct the return object.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I went ahead and implemented that, which simplifies the template considerably.

Comment: You are not wrong if the function you pass in has a concrete type signature, but what if you pass in a lambda with an `auto` parameter? In @JimmyHu's earlier questions about recursive algorithms, this was one of the issues that was found. There really might be situations where an explicit recursion level is desired. Of course, having recursion terminate when the transformation function can be applied is also a valid use case. Using `std::ranges::transform_view()` is interesting, and now that makes me wonder if there might be a use case for a `recursive_transform_view()`...

Comment: You might want to post your reworked code as a new Code Review question again. I would add more test cases though.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The original was an answer, not code submitted for review—but maybe people want to review it? It’s true; I haven’t tested it extensively.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I *think* (but it’s one of the things I haven’t tested) that this implementation of `traverse` should work on views, since `std::begin` and `std::end` work on them. However, I’m not convinced that a transformation function with different input and return types will work on a container with the default allocator as a template parameter.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Okay, *fine*, I addressed the case of a *generic* transformation function on containers.