# The usages of make_view Template Function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform_view Template Function which returns a view in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283820/231235). I am trying to revise the structure of `recursive_transform` template function implementation in C++. As the suggestion mentioned in [Davislor's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283827/231235), For dealing with dangling reference issue, the updated `recursive_transform` template function implementation is posted here.

**The experimental implementation**

- `make_view` template function implementation:

  ```
  template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
            std::copy_constructible F>
  requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
            std::is_object_v<F>)
  constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
  {
      return std::ranges::transform_view(
              std::views::all(input),
              [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
  }

  /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
  * safe from dangling..
  */
  template <  std::ranges::input_range T,
              std::copy_constructible F>
  requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
  constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&& input, const F& f) noexcept
  {
      return std::ranges::dangling();
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  The usages of `make_view` Template Function in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

//  is_reservable concept
template<class T>
concept is_reservable = requires(T input)
{
    input.reserve(1);
};

//  is_sized concept, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
template<class T>
concept is_sized = requires(T x)
{
    std::size(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::regular_invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::regular_invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>
                    >::type
                >;
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    std::regular_invocable<Container<T, N>> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>; 
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    typename F>
requires (
    !std::regular_invocable<F, Container<T, N>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>
                    >::type
                , N>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253039/231235
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
    }
}

namespace UL                                                //   unwrap_level
{
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                std::views::all(input),
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <  std::ranges::input_range T,
                std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    //  clone_empty_container template function implementation
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto clone_empty_container(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container> output(std::span{input});
        return output;
    }
    
    //  recursive_transform template function implementation (the version with unwrap_level template parameter)
    template<   std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
                class T,
                std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              std::ranges::view<T>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)         
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            auto output = clone_empty_container(input, f);
            if constexpr (is_reservable<decltype(output)>&&
                          is_sized<decltype(input)>)
            {
                output.reserve(input.size());
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::ranges::begin(output),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr(std::regular_invocable<F, T>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, T>, "Uninvocable?");
        }
    }

    /* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
    */
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N,
              typename F >
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                    );

        return output;
    }

    //  recursive_transform function implementation (the version with unwrap_level, without using view)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
    requires (!std::ranges::view<T>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
                "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");   //  trying to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully
            recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
            std::ranges::transform(
                input,                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
                std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
            );
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);  //   use std::invoke()
        }
    }
}

namespace NonUL
{
    
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                std::views::all(input),
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <std::ranges::input_range T,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>,
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    /* Base case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template<   typename T,
                std::regular_invocable<T> F>
    requires (std::copy_constructible<F>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform( const T& input, const F& f )
    {
        return std::invoke( f, input );
    }

    /* The recursive case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container>&&
              std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container& input, const F& f)
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container> output( std::span{view} );

        // One last sanity check.
        if constexpr( is_sized<Container> && is_sized<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container>> )
        {
            assert( output.size() == input.size() );
        }

        return output;
    }

    /* The recursive case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function for std::array
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template< template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
            typename T,
            std::size_t N,
            std::copy_constructible F>
    requires std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(                     //  Use std::ranges::transform() for std::arrays
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform(element, f); }
                    );

        // One last sanity check.
        if constexpr( is_sized<Container<T, N>> && is_sized<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>> )
        {
            assert( output.size() == input.size() );
        }

        return output;
    }
}

void tests()
{
    //  non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    std::cout << "non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly:\n";
    int test_number = 3;
    
    auto nonul_recursive_transform_output1 = NonUL::recursive_transform(test_number, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; });
    std::cout << "NonUL::recursive_transform function output: \n"
              << nonul_recursive_transform_output1 << "\n\n";

    
    //  test with non-nested std::array container
    std::cout << "test with non-nested std::array container:\n";
    static constexpr std::size_t D = 3;
    auto test_array = std::array< double, D >{1, 2, 3};
    auto nonul_recursive_transform_output2 = NonUL::recursive_transform(test_array, [](int&& element) { return element + 1; });
    std::cout << "NonUL::recursive_transform function output: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < nonul_recursive_transform_output2.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << nonul_recursive_transform_output2[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    //  TODO: test with nested std::arrays
    auto test_nested_array = std::array< decltype(test_array), D >{test_array, test_array, test_array};
    //std::cout << "test with nested std::arrays: \n"
    //          << UL::recursive_transform<2>(test_nested_array, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; })[0][0] << '\n';

    std::cout << "std::vector input test, lambda function applied on input directly:\n";
    std::vector<int> test_vector1 = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    auto ul_recursive_transform_output3 = UL::recursive_transform<0>(test_vector1, [](auto element)
        {
            element.push_back(4);
            element.push_back(5);
            return element;
        });
    std::cout << "UL::recursive_transform function output: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < ul_recursive_transform_output3.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << ul_recursive_transform_output3[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<int> test_vector2 = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    //  [A Issue to Be Addressed] Error from Clang:
    //  error: no matching function for call to '__begin'
    /*
    auto nonul_recursive_transform_output3 = NonUL::recursive_transform(test_vector2, [](int element)
        {
            return element;
        });
    std::cout << "NonUL::recursive_transform function output: \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < nonul_recursive_transform_output3.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << nonul_recursive_transform_output3[i] << " ";
    }
    */
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::vector<int> test_vector = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    auto test_priority_queue = 
        std::priority_queue<int>(std::ranges::begin(test_vector), std::ranges::end(test_vector));
    std::cout << "test with std::priority_queue container: \n"
              << UL::recursive_transform<0>(test_priority_queue, [](auto element)
                    {
                        element.push(4);
                        element.push(5);
                        element.push(6);
                        return element;
                    }).top() << '\n';

    
}

int main()
{
    tests();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly:
NonUL::recursive_transform function output: 
4

test with non-nested std::array container:
NonUL::recursive_transform function output: 
2 3 4 

std::vector input test, lambda function applied on input directly:
UL::recursive_transform function output: 
1 2 3 4 5 


test with std::priority_queue container: 
6
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/3P4T8rWP5)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform_view Template Function which returns a view in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283820/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  For dealing with dangling reference issue, the updated `recursive_transform` template function implementation is posted here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am not sure I understand the previous suggestions correctly and both implementation and the corresponding tests are posted here. If there is any misunderstanding, please let me know.

Comment: You want [`std::ranges::views::all`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view)

Comment: @Davislor Updated, thank you so much.

Comment: No. I meant, passing `input` directly to `transform_view` is fine. But what you actually want to do here is create the transformed structure, then create a view of it. And you don’t need to write that yourself; it’s `std::ranges::views::all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t really very useful.  What you want to do, in just about every case I can imagine, is create the transformed data structure.  It meets the requirements of `std::input_range`, and can be passed by reference to nearly every function that expects a view.

For the remaining cases where you really do want to pass around a small object representing a view, you can create the transformed structure and then take a view of it with `std::ranges::views::all`. This will not be able to outlive the transformed object.

Where it might do you some good is when you only need one element of a large data structure under the transformation, and it would be wasteful to fill a copy of the entire data structure with transformed data you won’t need.  But in that case, it’s more efficient to retrieve the element and apply the transformation function to it.