# A recursive_sum Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A Summation Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250790/231235) and [A recursive_transform_view Template Function Implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283747/231235). In the previous question, the implementation of `recursive_sum` template function performs summation operation on input container exhaustively. I am trying to make another version `recursive_sum` function which is used for dealing with nested iterables with unwrap level in C++.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_sum` template function implementation:

  ```
  template<   std::size_t unwrap_level,
              class T>
  requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
  constexpr auto recursive_sum(const T& input)
  {
      if constexpr (recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level == 0)
      {
          return input;
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<unwrap_level>(
              input,
              [](auto&& element){ return recursive_sum_all(element); }
          );
      }
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A recursive_sum Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

//  is_reservable concept
template<class T>
concept is_reservable = requires(T input)
{
    input.reserve(1);
};

//  is_sized concept, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
template<class T>
concept is_sized = requires(T x)
{
    std::size(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::regular_invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::regular_invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>
                    >::type
                >;
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    std::regular_invocable<Container<T, N>> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>; 
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    typename F>
requires (
    !std::regular_invocable<F, Container<T, N>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>
                    >::type
                , N>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t implementation
template<std::size_t, typename, typename, typename...>
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result { };

template<typename F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<1, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = Container1<std::invoke_result_t<F,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container1<Ts1...>> &&
            requires { typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
                                    unwrap_level - 1,
                                    F,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = Container1<
        typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
        unwrap_level - 1,
        F,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...
        >::type>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename F, typename T1, typename... Ts>
using recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, T1, Ts...>::type;

//  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253039/231235
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
    }
}

namespace UL                                                //   unwrap_level
{
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                input,
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&&) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    //  clone_empty_container template function implementation
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto clone_empty_container(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container> output(std::span{input});
        return output;
    }
    
    //  recursive_transform template function implementation (the version with unwrap_level template parameter)
    template<   std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
                class T,
                std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              std::ranges::view<T>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)         
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            auto output = clone_empty_container(input, f);
            if constexpr (is_reservable<decltype(output)>&&
                          is_sized<decltype(input)>)
            {
                output.reserve(input.size());
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::ranges::begin(output),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr(std::regular_invocable<F, T>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, T>, "Uninvocable?");
        }
    }

    /* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
    */
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N,
              typename F >
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                    );

        return output;
    }

    //  recursive_transform function implementation (the version with unwrap_level, without using view)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
    requires (!std::ranges::view<T>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
                "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");   //  trying to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully
            recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T> output{};
            std::ranges::transform(
                input,                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
                std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
            );
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);   //   use std::invoke()
        }
    }
}

namespace NonUL
{
    
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container>&&
              std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                input,
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&&) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    /* Base case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template<   typename T,
                std::regular_invocable<T> F>
    requires (std::copy_constructible<F>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform( const T& input, const F& f )
    {
        return std::invoke( f, input );
    }

    /* The recursive case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container>&&
              std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container& input, const F& f)
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container> output( std::ranges::begin(view), std::ranges::end(view) );
        
        // One last sanity check.
        if constexpr( is_sized<Container> && is_sized<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container>> )
        {
            assert( output.size() == input.size() );
        }

        return output;
    }

    /* The recursive case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function for std::array
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template< template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
            typename T,
            std::size_t N,
            std::copy_constructible F>
    requires std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(                     //  Use std::ranges::transform() for std::arrays
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform(element, f); }
                    );

        // One last sanity check.
        if constexpr( is_sized<Container<T, N>> && is_sized<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>> )
        {
            assert( output.size() == input.size() );
        }

        return output;
    }
}

/*  recursive_sum_all template function performs summation operation on input container exhaustively
*/
template<class T> requires is_summable<T>
auto recursive_sum_all(const T& input)
{
    return input;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T>
auto recursive_sum_all(const T inputArray)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::value_type
        value_type;

    decltype(recursive_sum_all(std::declval<value_type &&>())) sun_output{};
    for (auto& element : inputArray)
    {
        sun_output += recursive_sum_all(element);
    }
    return sun_output;
}

template<   std::size_t unwrap_level,
            class T>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
constexpr auto recursive_sum(const T& input)
{
    if constexpr (recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<unwrap_level>(
            input,
            [](auto&& element){ return recursive_sum_all(element); }
        );
    }
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
constexpr T recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

void recursive_sum_tests()
{
    auto test_vectors = n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, 4, int>(1, 3);

    std::cout << "Play with test_vectors:\n\n";
    
    std::cout << "recursive_sum_all function: \n";
    auto recursive_sum_all_result = recursive_sum_all(test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_sum_all_result << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "unwrap_level = 4:\n";
    auto test_output_1 = recursive_sum<4>(test_vectors);
    recursive_print(test_output_1);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "unwrap_level = 3:\n";
    auto test_output_2 = recursive_sum<3>(test_vectors);
    recursive_print(test_output_2);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "unwrap_level = 2:\n";
    auto test_output_3 = recursive_sum<2>(test_vectors);
    recursive_print(test_output_3);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "unwrap_level = 1:\n";
    auto test_output_4 = recursive_sum<1>(test_vectors);
    recursive_print(test_output_4);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "unwrap_level = 0:\n";
    auto test_output_5 = recursive_sum<0>(test_vectors);
    std::cout << test_output_5 << "\n\n";
    
    return;
}

int main()
{
    recursive_sum_tests();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Play with test_vectors:

recursive_sum_all function: 
81

unwrap_level = 4:
Level 0:
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
  Level 2:
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1
   Level 3:
   1
   1
   1


unwrap_level = 3:
Level 0:
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
 Level 1:
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3
  Level 2:
  3
  3
  3


unwrap_level = 2:
Level 0:
 Level 1:
 9
 9
 9
 Level 1:
 9
 9
 9
 Level 1:
 9
 9
 9


unwrap_level = 1:
Level 0:
27
27
27


unwrap_level = 0:
81
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/4fcPxW93M)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A Summation Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250790/231235) and

  [A recursive_transform_view Template Function Implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283747/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement `recursive_sum` template function with unwrap level parameter in this post. In this example, I think that the usage of the version `recursive_transform` with unwrap level is necessary. If there is any misunderstanding, please let me know.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review the experimental implementation of `recursive_sum` template function. The function perfroms the summation operation on specified level of container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make it more generic

Summing is a very specific operation. What if you want to calculate the product of all elements instead? Or get the minimum or maximum value? Instead of hardcoding the operation, create a `recursive_reduce()` that works like [`std::reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce). You can still have it sum by default if you don't specify which operation to perform.

## Associativity and initial values

Note that the order in which you perform operations matters. While `operator+` is often [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), it doesn't have to be. That's why in C++23, [`std::ranges::fold_left()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left) and [`std::ranges::fold_right()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_right) were introduced.

Furthermore, some value types might not have a default constructor, thus `sun_output{}` might not compile. This is why most algorithms in the STL that perform some kind of reduction take an initial value as a parameter. I recommend you add that here as well.

Sometimes you know the input is non-empty, and you want to avoid providing an initial values. C++23 introduced [`std::ranges::fold_left_first()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left_first) and related functions for this purpose.

## Meaning of the unwrap level

I was surprised by the fact that your `recursive_sum()` uses `recursive_transform()` internally, and by the output from your example code. I would rather have expected the following:

```
std::vector<std::string> words = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"};

std::cout << recursive_sum<2>(words) << '\n';
std::cout << recursive_sum<1>(words) << '\n';
```

To output:

```
:
foobarbazquux
```

Basically, the call to `recursive_sum<2>(words)` would unwrap two levels, so it would iterate over the characters in each string, whereas `recursive_sum<1>(words)` would unwrap only the vector, and add the strings together.

I think that would be more logical. Also consider math libraries that have vector and matrix types that can be iterated over; sometimes you want to sum the elements of a matrix, sometimes you want to sum matrices together, but your code will always sum the innermost elements.

Here is how I would implement a basic `recursive_sum()`:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level,
         class R,
         class T = recursive_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, R>>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<R>())
constexpr auto recursive_sum(const R& input, T init = {})
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0) {
        for (const auto& element: input) {
            init = recursive_sum(element, init);
        }
    } else {
        init += input;
    }

    return init;
}
```

Where `recursive_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, R>` would give you the type after unwrapping `R` for `unwrap_level` levels.

If you want your original behavior, the caller could then combine `recursive_transform()` and `recursive_sum()` themselves, like so:

```
auto test_output_3 = recursive_transform<2>(
    test_vectors,
    [](auto&& element){ return recursive_sum(element); }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. > I was surprised by the fact that your `recursive_sum()` uses `recursive_transform()` internally. Do you have any other idea for the implementation of `recursive_sum` function? Or there is any other better way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. I understand the opinion you mentioned. :)