# A recursive_reduce Template Function with Unwrap Level Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_sum Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284539/231235) and [A `recursive_reduce_all` Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284726/231235). Considering [the answer provided by G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284548/231235):

> ## Make it more generic
>
> Summing is a very specific operation. What if you want to calculate the product of all elements instead? Or get the minimum or maximum value? Instead of hardcoding the operation, create a `recursive_reduce()` that works like [`std::reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce). You can still have it sum by default if you don't specify which operation to perform.

I am trying to implement `recursive_reduce` template function with unwrap level in C++.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_reduce` template function implementation

  ```
  /*  recursive_reduce template function performs operation on input container with unwrap level
  */
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T>
  requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
  constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
      {
          return recursive_reduce_all(input);
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
              input,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element); }
          );
      }
  }

  //  recursive_reduce template function with execution policy
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class T>
  requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
  constexpr auto recursive_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
      {
          return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, input);
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
              execution_policy,
              input,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element); }
          );
      }
  }

  //  recursive_reduce template function with initial value
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
  requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
            std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
            std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI>)
  constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, TI init)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
      {
          return recursive_reduce_all(input, init);
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
              input,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element, init); }
          );
      }
  }

  //  recursive_reduce template function with execution policy and initial value
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
  requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
            std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
            std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI>)
  constexpr auto recursive_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
      {
          return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, input, init);
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
              execution_policy,
              input,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element, init); }
          );
      }
  }

  //  recursive_reduce template function with initial value and specified operation
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
  requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
            std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
            std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
            std::regular_invocable<
              BinaryOp,
              recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
              recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
            )
  constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
      {
          return recursive_reduce_all(input, init, binary_op);
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
              input,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element, init, binary_op); }
          );
      }
  }

  //  recursive_reduce template function with execution policy, initial value and specified operation
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
  requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
            is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
            std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
            std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
            std::regular_invocable<
              BinaryOp,
              recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
              recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
            )
  constexpr auto recursive_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
      {
          return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, input, init, binary_op);
      }
      else
      {
          return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
              execution_policy,
              input,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element, init, binary_op); }
          );
      }
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A `recursive_reduce` Template Function Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

//  is_reservable concept
template<class T>
concept is_reservable = requires(T input)
{
    input.reserve(1);
};

//  is_sized concept, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
template<class T>
concept is_sized = requires(T x)
{
    std::size(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t implementation
template<std::size_t, typename, typename, typename...>
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result { };

template<typename F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<1, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = Container1<std::invoke_result_t<F,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container1<Ts1...>> &&
            requires { typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
                                    unwrap_level - 1,
                                    F,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = Container1<
        typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
        unwrap_level - 1,
        F,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...
        >::type>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename F, typename T1, typename... Ts>
using recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, T1, Ts...>::type;

//  recursive_unwrap_type_t struct implementation
template<std::size_t, typename, typename...>
struct recursive_unwrap_type { };

template<class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
struct recursive_unwrap_type<1, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container1<Ts1...>> &&
            requires { typename recursive_unwrap_type<
                                    unwrap_level - 1,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
struct recursive_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename recursive_unwrap_type<
        unwrap_level - 1,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>
        >::type;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename T1, typename... Ts>
using recursive_unwrap_type_t = typename recursive_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, T1, Ts...>::type;

//  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253039/231235
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
    }
}

namespace UL                                                //   unwrap_level
{
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                input,
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&&) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    //  clone_empty_container template function implementation
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto clone_empty_container(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container> output(std::span{input});
        return output;
    }
    
    //  recursive_transform template function implementation (the version with unwrap_level template parameter)
    template<   std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
                class T,
                std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>() &&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              std::ranges::view<T>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)         
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            auto output = clone_empty_container(input, f);
            if constexpr (is_reservable<decltype(output)>&&
                          is_sized<decltype(input)>)
            {
                output.reserve(input.size());
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::ranges::begin(output),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr(std::regular_invocable<F, T>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, T>, "Uninvocable?");
        }
    }

    /* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
    */
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N,
              typename F >
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>> &&
              unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()          //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              )
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                    );

        return output;
    }

    //  recursive_transform function implementation (the version with unwrap_level, without using view)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
    requires (!std::ranges::view<T>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
                "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");   //  trying to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully
            recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T> output{};
            std::ranges::transform(
                input,                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
                std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
            );
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);   //   use std::invoke()
        }
    }

    //  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level, with execution policy)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class T, class F>
    requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>() &&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T> output{};
            output.resize(input.size());
            std::mutex mutex;
            std::transform(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
                [&](auto&& element)
                {
                    std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
                    return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(execution_policy, element, f);
                });
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return f(input);
        }
    }
}

/*  recursive_reduce_all template function performs operation on input container exhaustively
*/
template<class T> requires is_summable<T>
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input)
{
    return input;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          recursive_depth<T>() == 1)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input)
{
    return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input));
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input)
{
    auto result = recursive_reduce_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(input, [](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element); })
        );
    return result;
}

//  recursive_reduce_all template function with execution policy
template<class ExPo, class T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input)
{
    return input;
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          recursive_depth<T>() == 1)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input)
{
    return std::reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input));
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input)
{
    auto result = recursive_reduce_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
            execution_policy,
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element); }
            )
        );
    return result;
}

//  recursive_reduce_all template function with initial value
template<class T> requires is_summable<T>
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input1, const T& input2)
{
    return input1 + input2;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          recursive_depth<T>() == 1)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input, TI init)
{
    return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), init);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input, TI init)
{
    auto result = init + recursive_reduce_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element); })
        );
    return result;
}

//  recursive_reduce_all template function with execution policy and initial value
template<class ExPo, class T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input1, const T& input2)
{
    return input1 + input2;
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          recursive_depth<T>() == 1)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init)
{
    return std::reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), init);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init)
{
    auto result = init + recursive_reduce_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
            execution_policy,
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element); })
        );
    return result;
}

//  recursive_reduce_all template function with initial value and specified operation
template<class T, class BinaryOp>
requires (is_summable<T> &&
          std::regular_invocable<BinaryOp, T, T>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input1, const T& input2, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    return std::invoke(binary_op, input1, input2);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          recursive_depth<T>() == 1 &&
          std::regular_invocable<
            BinaryOp,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
          )
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), init, binary_op);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          std::regular_invocable<
            BinaryOp,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
          )
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    auto result = init + recursive_reduce_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element, init, binary_op); })
        );
    return result;
}

//  recursive_reduce_all template function with execution policy, initial value and specified operation
template<class ExPo, class T, class BinaryOp>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<T> &&
          std::regular_invocable<BinaryOp, T, T>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input1, const T& input2, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    return std::invoke(binary_op, input1, input2);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          recursive_depth<T>() == 1 &&
          std::regular_invocable<
            BinaryOp,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
          )
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    return std::reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), init, binary_op);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          std::regular_invocable<
            BinaryOp,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
          )
constexpr auto recursive_reduce_all(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    auto result = init + recursive_reduce_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
            execution_policy,
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element, init, binary_op); })
        );
    return result;
}

/*  recursive_reduce template function performs operation on input container with unwrap level
*/
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
    {
        return recursive_reduce_all(input);
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element); }
        );
    }
}

//  recursive_reduce template function with execution policy
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
    {
        return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, input);
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
            execution_policy,
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element); }
        );
    }
}

//  recursive_reduce template function with initial value
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, TI init)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
    {
        return recursive_reduce_all(input, init);
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element, init); }
        );
    }
}

//  recursive_reduce template function with execution policy and initial value
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI>)
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
    {
        return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, input, init);
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
            execution_policy,
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element, init); }
        );
    }
}

//  recursive_reduce template function with initial value and specified operation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
requires (is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          std::regular_invocable<
            BinaryOp,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
          )
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
    {
        return recursive_reduce_all(input, init, binary_op);
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(element, init, binary_op); }
        );
    }
}

//  recursive_reduce template function with execution policy, initial value and specified operation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range T, class TI, class BinaryOp>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
          is_summable<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<recursive_unwrap_type_t<1, T>> &&
          std::same_as<recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>, TI> &&
          std::regular_invocable<
            BinaryOp,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(),T>,
            recursive_unwrap_type_t<recursive_depth<T>(), T>>
          )
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, TI init, BinaryOp binary_op)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level == recursive_depth<T>())
    {
        return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, input, init, binary_op);
    }
    else
    {
        return UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - unwrap_level>(
            execution_policy,
            input,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_reduce_all(execution_policy, element, init, binary_op); }
        );
    }
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
constexpr T recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

void recursive_reduce_tests_vector()
{
    auto test_vectors = n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, 4, double>(1, 4);
    
    std::cout << "Play with test_vectors:\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test (unwrap_level = 4): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce_result1 = recursive_reduce<4>(test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_reduce_result1 << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce_result2 = recursive_reduce<3>(test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_reduce_result2[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test (unwrap_level = 2): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce_result3 = recursive_reduce<2>(test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_reduce_result3[0][0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::seq, unwrap_level = 4): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce_result4 = recursive_reduce<4>(std::execution::seq, test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_reduce_result4 << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par, unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce5 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::par, test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_reduce5[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par_unseq, unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce6 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::par_unseq, test_vectors);
    std::cout << recursive_reduce6[0] << "\n\n";
    
    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with initial value (unwrap_level = 4): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce7 = recursive_reduce<4>(test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1));
    std::cout << recursive_reduce7 << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with initial value (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce8 = recursive_reduce<3>(test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1));
    std::cout << recursive_reduce8[0] << "\n\n";
    
    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::seq) and initial value (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce9 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::seq, test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1));
    std::cout << recursive_reduce9[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par) and initial value (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce10 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::par, test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1));
    std::cout << recursive_reduce10[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par_unseq) and initial value (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce11 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::par_unseq, test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1));
    std::cout << recursive_reduce11[0] << "\n\n";
    
    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce12 = recursive_reduce<3>(test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1), [](auto&& input1, auto&& input2) { return input1 * input2; });
    std::cout << recursive_reduce12[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::seq), initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce13 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::seq, test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1), [](auto&& input1, auto&& input2) { return input1 * input2; });
    std::cout << recursive_reduce13[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par), initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce14 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::par, test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1), [](auto&& input1, auto&& input2) { return input1 * input2; });
    std::cout << recursive_reduce14[0] << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par_unseq), initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): \n";
    auto recursive_reduce15 = recursive_reduce<3>(std::execution::par_unseq, test_vectors, static_cast<double>(1), [](auto&& input1, auto&& input2) { return input1 * input2; });
    std::cout << recursive_reduce15[0] << "\n\n";
    
    return;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    recursive_reduce_tests_vector();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Tests finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Play with test_vectors:

recursive_reduce function test (unwrap_level = 4): 
256

recursive_reduce function test (unwrap_level = 3): 
64

recursive_reduce function test (unwrap_level = 2): 
16

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::seq, unwrap_level = 4): 
256

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par, unwrap_level = 3): 
64

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par_unseq, unwrap_level = 3): 
64

recursive_reduce function test with initial value (unwrap_level = 4): 
257

recursive_reduce function test with initial value (unwrap_level = 3): 
65

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::seq) and initial value (unwrap_level = 3): 
65

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par) and initial value (unwrap_level = 3): 
65

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par_unseq) and initial value (unwrap_level = 3): 
65

recursive_reduce function test with initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): 
17

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::seq), initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): 
17

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par), initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): 
17

recursive_reduce function test with execution policy (std::execution::par_unseq), initial value and specified operation (unwrap_level = 3): 
17

Tests finished at Thu May 25 10:34:43 2023
elapsed time: 6.5461e-05
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/bqodf5c71)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_sum Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284539/231235) and

  [A `recursive_reduce_all` Template Function Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284726/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement `recursive_reduce` template function with unwrap level.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review the `recursive_reduce()` template function implementation and its testing function `recursive_reduce_tests`.