# A recursive_fold_left_all Template Function Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, constrained-templates, c++23

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_sum Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284539/231235). I am trying to implement a recursive version `fold_left` template function in this post.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_fold_left_all` Template Function:

  ```
  /*  recursive_fold_left_all template function performs fold left operation on input container exhaustively
  */
  template<typename T>
  constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T& input)
  {
      return input;
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range T, class I,
           class F>
  constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T inputRange, I init, F f)
  {
      return std::ranges::fold_left(inputRange, init, f);
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range T, class I,
           class F>
  requires(std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
  constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T inputRange, I init, F f)
  {

      return std::invoke(f, init, recursive_fold_left_all(
          UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
              inputRange,
              [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_fold_left_all(element, I{}, f); }),
              I{}, f
          ));
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A recursive_fold_left_all Template Function Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

//  is_reservable concept
template<class T>
concept is_reservable = requires(T input)
{
    input.reserve(1);
};

//  is_sized concept, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
template<class T>
concept is_sized = requires(T x)
{
    std::size(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return std::size_t{0};
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::regular_invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::regular_invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>
                    >::type
                >;
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    std::regular_invocable<Container<T, N>> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>; 
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    typename F>
requires (
    !std::regular_invocable<F, Container<T, N>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>
                    >::type
                , N>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t implementation
template<std::size_t, typename, typename, typename...>
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result { };

template<typename F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<1, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = Container1<std::invoke_result_t<F,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container1<Ts1...>> &&
            requires { typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
                                    unwrap_level - 1,
                                    F,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
{
    using type = Container1<
        typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
        unwrap_level - 1,
        F,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...
        >::type>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename F, typename T1, typename... Ts>
using recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, T1, Ts...>::type;

//  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253039/231235
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
    }
}

namespace UL                                                //   unwrap_level
{
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                input,
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&&) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    //  clone_empty_container template function implementation
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto clone_empty_container(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container> output(std::span{input});
        return output;
    }
    
    //  recursive_transform template function implementation (the version with unwrap_level template parameter)
    template<   std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
                class T,
                std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              std::ranges::view<T>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)         
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            auto output = clone_empty_container(input, f);
            if constexpr (is_reservable<decltype(output)>&&
                          is_sized<decltype(input)>)
            {
                output.reserve(input.size());
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::ranges::begin(output),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                std::ranges::transform(
                    input,
                    std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                    [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );
            }
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr(std::regular_invocable<F, T>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, T>, "Uninvocable?");
        }
    }

    /* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
    */
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
              template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N,
              typename F >
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                    );

        return output;
    }

    //  recursive_transform function implementation (the version with unwrap_level, without using view)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
    requires (!std::ranges::view<T>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
                "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");   //  trying to handle incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully
            recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T> output{};
            std::ranges::transform(
                input,                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
                std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
            );
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);   //   use std::invoke()
        }
    }
}

namespace NonUL
{
    
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container>&&
              std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto make_view(const Container& input, const F& f) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::transform_view(
                input,
                [&f](const auto&& element) constexpr { return recursive_transform(element, f ); } );
    }

    /* Override make_view to catch dangling references.  A borrowed range is
    * safe from dangling..
    */
    template <std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (!std::ranges::borrowed_range<T>)
    constexpr std::ranges::dangling make_view(T&&) noexcept
    {
        return std::ranges::dangling();
    }

    /* Base case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template<   typename T,
                std::regular_invocable<T> F>
    requires (std::copy_constructible<F>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform( const T& input, const F& f )
    {
        return std::invoke( f, input );
    }

    /* The recursive case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template< std::ranges::input_range Container,
              std::copy_constructible F>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container>&&
              std::ranges::view<Container>&&
              std::is_object_v<F>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container& input, const F& f)
    {
        const auto view = make_view(input, f);
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container> output( std::ranges::begin(view), std::ranges::end(view) );
        
        // One last sanity check.
        if constexpr( is_sized<Container> && is_sized<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container>> )
        {
            assert( output.size() == input.size() );
        }

        return output;
    }

    /* The recursive case of NonUL::recursive_transform template function for std::array
    https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/231235
    */
    template< template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
            typename T,
            std::size_t N,
            std::copy_constructible F>
    requires std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
    {
        Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

        std::ranges::transform(                     //  Use std::ranges::transform() for std::arrays
                        input,
                        std::ranges::begin(output),
                        [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform(element, f); }
                    );

        // One last sanity check.
        if constexpr( is_sized<Container<T, N>> && is_sized<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>> )
        {
            assert( output.size() == input.size() );
        }

        return output;
    }
}

/*  recursive_fold_left_all template function performs fold left operation on input container exhaustively
*/
template<typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T& input)
{
    return input;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class I,
         class F>
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T inputRange, I init, F f)
{
    return std::ranges::fold_left(inputRange, init, f);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class I,
         class F>
requires(std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T inputRange, I init, F f)
{
    
    return std::invoke(f, init, recursive_fold_left_all(
        UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(
            inputRange,
            [&](auto&& element){ return recursive_fold_left_all(element, I{}, f); }),
            I{}, f
        ));
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
constexpr T recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

void recursive_fold_left_all_tests()
{
    auto test_vectors = n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, 4, int>(1, 3);

    std::cout << "Play with test_vectors:\n\n";
    
    std::cout << "recursive_fold_left_all function test with vectors / std::plus<>(): \n";
    auto recursive_fold_left_all_result1 = recursive_fold_left_all(test_vectors, static_cast<int>(1), std::plus<>());
    std::cout << recursive_fold_left_all_result1 << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "recursive_fold_left_all function test with vectors / std::multiplies<>(): \n";
    auto recursive_fold_left_all_result2 = recursive_fold_left_all(test_vectors, static_cast<int>(2), std::multiplies<>());
    std::cout << recursive_fold_left_all_result2 << "\n\n";

    //  From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left
    std::vector<std::pair<char, float>> data {{'A', 2.f}, {'B', 3.f}, {'C', 3.5f}};
    auto recursive_fold_left_all_result3 = recursive_fold_left_all
    (
        data | std::ranges::views::values, 2.0f, std::multiplies<>()
    );
    std::cout << "recursive_fold_left_all_result3: " << recursive_fold_left_all_result3 << '\n';

    std::array<int, 8> arr {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    // use a program defined function object (lambda-expression):
    auto recursive_fold_left_all_result4 = recursive_fold_left_all
    (
        arr, "A", [](std::string s, int x) { return s + ':' + std::to_string(x); }
    );
    std::cout << "recursive_fold_left_all_result4: " << recursive_fold_left_all_result4 << '\n';

    return;
}

int main()
{
    recursive_fold_left_all_tests();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Play with test_vectors:

recursive_fold_left_all function test with vectors / std::plus<>(): 
82

recursive_fold_left_all function test with vectors / std::multiplies<>(): 
0

recursive_fold_left_all_result3: 42
recursive_fold_left_all_result4: A:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/h74GKE4KT)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_sum Template Function Implementation with Unwrap Level in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284539/231235).
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement a recursive version `fold_left` template function in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review `recursive_fold_left_all` and all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes lots of unnecessary copies. It already starts with the function declaration:

```
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T inputRange, I init, F f)
```

Because `inputRange` is passed *by value*, a copy is made before the function even starts. And since this is called recursively, copies are made at every recursion level. But it gets worse:

```
UL::recursive_transform<recursive_depth<T>() - 1>(…)
```

Your `recursive_transform()` function produces a new container as its output. This is a temporary copy that will hold values until a regular `std::ranges::fold_left()` will fold the items in it.

I see how you got here: you wanted to do the folding itself recursively. However, consider instead just recursively *visiting* each value in the input, and then applying the fold operation to each value. If you have a `recursive_foreach()`, then you can just write:

```
template<class T, class I, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T& inputRange, I init, F f)
{
    recursive_foreach(inputRange, [&](auto& value) {
        init = std::invoke(f, init, value);
    });

    return init;
}
```

However, you can make a recursive version from scratch like so:

```
template<class T, class I, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T& value, I init, F f) {
    return std::invoke(f, init, value);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class I, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_fold_left_all(const T& inputRange, I init, F f)
{
    return std::ranges::fold_left(range, init, [&](auto& value) {
        return recursive_fold_left_all(value, I{}, f);
    });
}
```

Also note that in general, you should only need two overloads for recursive functions: the generic recursive case, and the terminal case. You should not need a third one.