# A recursive_minmax Template Function Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A Maximum Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250895/231235). Besides the function for finding maximum, I am trying to implement `recursive_minmax` template function which returns both minimum and maximum values.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_minmax` template function implementation

  ```
  template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                   std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
  requires(!(std::ranges::input_range<T>))          //  non-range overloading
  constexpr auto recursive_minmax(const T& input, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
  {
      return input;
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                   std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
  constexpr auto recursive_minmax(const T& numbers, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
  {
      return std::make_pair(
          recursive_min(numbers, comp, proj),
          recursive_max(numbers, comp, proj)
          );
  }
  ```
- `recursive_min` template function implementation

  ```
  template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                   std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
  requires(!std::ranges::input_range<T>)          //  non-range overloading
  static inline T recursive_min(T inputNumber, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
  {
      return std::invoke(proj, inputNumber);
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                   std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
  static inline auto recursive_min(const T& numbers, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
  {
      auto output = recursive_min(numbers.at(0), comp, proj);
      for (auto& element : numbers)
      {
          output = std::ranges::min(
              output,
              recursive_min(element, comp, proj),
              comp,
              proj);
      }
      return output;
  }
  ```
- `recursive_max` template function implementation

  ```
  template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                   std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
  requires(!std::ranges::input_range<T>)          //  non-range overloading
  static inline T recursive_max(T inputNumber, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
  {
      return std::invoke(proj, inputNumber);
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                   std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
  static inline auto recursive_max(const T& numbers, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
  {
      auto output = recursive_max(numbers.at(0), comp, proj);
      for (auto& element : numbers)
      {
          output = std::ranges::max(
              output,
              recursive_max(element, comp, proj),
              comp,
              proj);
      }
      return output;
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A `recursive_minmax` Template Function Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << "\n";
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << "\n";
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class T>
requires (std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
          std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
constexpr T recursive_print(const T& input, const int level = 0)
{
    T output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << "\n";
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

bool comp(int a, int b){
  return a > b;
}

template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                 std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
requires(!std::ranges::input_range<T>)          //  non-range overloading
static inline T recursive_min(T inputNumber, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    return std::invoke(proj, inputNumber);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                 std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
static inline auto recursive_min(const T& numbers, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    auto output = recursive_min(numbers.at(0), comp, proj);
    for (auto& element : numbers)
    {
        output = std::ranges::min(
            output,
            recursive_min(std::invoke(proj, element), comp, proj),
            comp,
            proj);
    }
    return output;
}

template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                 std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
requires(!std::ranges::input_range<T>)          //  non-range overloading
static inline T recursive_max(T inputNumber, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    return std::invoke(proj, inputNumber);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                 std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
static inline auto recursive_max(const T& numbers, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    auto output = recursive_max(numbers.at(0), comp, proj);
    for (auto& element : numbers)
    {
        output = std::ranges::max(
            output,
            recursive_max(std::invoke(proj, element), comp, proj),
            comp,
            proj);
    }
    return output;
}

template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                 std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
requires(!(std::ranges::input_range<T>))          //  non-range overloading
constexpr auto recursive_minmax(const T& input, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    return std::invoke(proj, input);
}

template<std::ranges::input_range T, class Proj = std::identity,
         std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
                 std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = std::ranges::less>
constexpr auto recursive_minmax(const T& numbers, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    return std::make_pair(
        recursive_min(numbers, comp, proj),
        recursive_max(numbers, comp, proj)
        );
}

void recursive_minmax_test()
{
    std::array test_array1{3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 15, 2, 6, 5};
    std::array test_array2{3, 1, 4, -1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5};
    std::vector<decltype(test_array1)> v = {test_array1, test_array2};
    auto [min, max] = recursive_minmax(v);
    std::cout << "Min value is " << min << "\n";
    std::cout << "Max value is " << max << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    recursive_minmax_test();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Min value is -1
Max value is 15
Computation finished at Sun Dec  3 08:04:27 2023
elapsed time: 3.4378e-05
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/bW76obj8x)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A Maximum Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250895/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement `recursive_minmax` template function in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review `recursive_minmax` template function implementation and all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Separate concerns

You are not following the principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Whenever you write a `recursive_foo()` function, you should separate the concern of recursively iterating over a container from applying `foo()` to each element.
Since the minmax operation is a [reduction operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_operator), ideally you'd want to write something like:

```
void recursive_minmax_test()
{
    …
    std::vector<decltype(test_array1)> v = {test_array1, test_array2};
    auto [min, max] = recursive_reduce(v, minmax);
    …
}
```

Where `minmax()` would be a generic function that takes a value and an existing min/max pair, and returns a new pair that is updated based on the given value.

The benefit should be obvious. Instead of having to write many `recursive_something()` functions, you only have to write one. If you want a recursive sum: `recursive_reduce(v, std::plus{})`, if you want a recursive minimum: `recursive_reduce(v, std::min)`, and so on.

## Allow for passing an initial value

Many standard library algorithms allow (or sometimes require) you to pass an initial value. This is very useful for several reasons:

- It avoids having to treat the first element as a special case. This is also avoids the issue you have if the container you pass in is empty.
- It allows chaining multiple reduction operations, by simply passing the result of the first reduction as an initial value for the second reduction.
- There might be cases where the initial value of the reduction operation cannot be one of the values of the container, for example when the reduced value has a different type... like with the min/max reduction!

## `recursive_minmax()` is inefficient

Your `recursive_minmax()` just calls `recursive_min()` and `recursive_max()`. That means it will iterate twice over the containers. But you only need one pass to get both the minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 2):

## Bug

You iterate the range twice, once for each partial result, which is forbidden for a simple [`std::ranges::input_range`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range).
You need at least a [`std::ranges::forward_range`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/forward_range).

## Design

This design is inefficient, not composable, nor does it take advantage of existing building blocks.

- It is inefficient because it iterates the range twice, once per sub-result.
- It is not composable, as fully flattening the range and applying some aggregate-function are not separated.
- There is already `std::views::join` for flattening a view by one level, which can be chained as needed.
  Thereafter the normal aggregate-functions will do the job just fine.

## Summary

The only building block you might want to implement, is `recursive_join` to fully flatten the range. Everything else is already done and ready for use.