# A Summation Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, boost

This is a follow-up question for
[A Summation Function For Arbitrary Nested Vector Implementation In C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250743/231235) and [A Summation Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250790/231235). I am trying to implement a `recursive_sum` function for [the Boost Multidimensional Array Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). The purpose of this `recursive_sum` function is to sum up each element in a input `boost::multi_array` data.  The recursive structure here is similar to the previous implementation for `std::vector` and the other type nested iterable. Furthermore, I found that there are several types including `boost::multi_array`, `boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array` and `boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array` in Boost.MultiArray library. I am trying to handle these types with multiple overload function as below.

```
template<class T> requires is_summable<T>
auto recursive_sum(const T& input)
{
    return input;
}

//  Deal with the boost::multi_array case
template<class T, std::size_t Dims> requires is_summable<T>
auto recursive_sum(const boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array<T, Dims>& input)
{
    T sum_output{};
    for (typename boost::multi_array<T, Dims>::index i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        sum_output += recursive_sum(input[i]);
    }
    return sum_output;
}

//  Deal with the boost::multi_array case
template<class T, std::size_t Dims> requires is_summable<T>
auto recursive_sum(const boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<T, Dims>& input)
{
    T sum_output{};
    for (typename boost::multi_array<T, Dims>::index i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        sum_output += recursive_sum(input[i]);
    }
    return sum_output;
}

//  Deal with the boost::multi_array case
template<class T, std::size_t Dims> requires is_summable<T>
auto recursive_sum(boost::multi_array<T, Dims>& input)
{
    T sum_output{};
    for (typename boost::multi_array<T, Dims>::index i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        sum_output += recursive_sum(input[i]);
    }
    return sum_output;
}
```

The used `is_summable` concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };
```

The test for this `recursive_sum` function:

```
int main()
{
    // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

    // Assign values to the elements
    int values = 0;
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                A[i][j][k] = values++;
    
    auto recursive_sum_output = recursive_sum(A);
    std::cout << "recursive_sum_output: " << recursive_sum_output;
    
    return 0;
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A Summation Function For Arbitrary Nested Vector Implementation In C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250743/231235) and

  [A Summation Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250790/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The previous question is focused on the common containers in C++ STL, such as `std::vector`. The main idea in this question is trying to implement another type summation function which can deal with `boost::multi_array`.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I found that there are three types of array structure in Boost.MultiArray library which are `boost::multi_array`, `boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array` and `boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array`. In order to handle these different type classes, there are three overload functions `recursive_sum` for dealing with each type separately. I am not sure is there any better way to simplify these overload functions. Moreover, if there is any possible improvement for this code, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Implement a recursive `std::reduce()`

You shouldn't need to special-case `boost::multi_array` and related types, as those types already act like STL containers (they provide `begin()` and `end()` for example). The main problem however is how to deduce the return type of `recursive_sum()`. Your functions seem to work because they deduce `T` from a `boost::multi_array<T, Dims>`, but do they really? Your `recursive_sum()` recurses over the *dimensions* of a `multi_array`, but it doesn't actually handle nested `multi_array`s, like for example:

```
boost::multi_array<boost::multi_array<double, 2>, 3> array;
```

The reason is that in the above case, calling `recursive_sum(array)` will deduce `T` to be a `boost::multi_array<double, 2>` instead of a `double`.

To solve this issue, I would do what [`std::reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) does, and sidestep the issue by requiring an initial value for the sum. The type of this initial value will also be the return type. For example:

```
template<class T, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, ValueType init, const Function& f)
{
    return f(init, input);
}

template<class Container, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
requires is_iterable<Container>
auto recursive_reduce(const Container& input, ValueType init, const Function& f = std::plus<ValueType>())
{
    for (const auto &element: input) {
        auto result = recursive_reduce(element, ValueType{}, f);
        init = f(init, result);
    }

    return init;
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
boost::multi_array<...> array(...);
std::cout << recursive_reduce(array, 0.0) << "\n";
```

You could perhaps write some template to find the inner-most value type, so that you can use that as a default for the template parameter `ValueType` in `recursive_reduce()`, and then you can use `{}` as the default value for `init`, and be able to write:

```
std::cout << recursive_reduce(array) << "\n";
```