# An Add/Minus Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20, boost, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [An element_wise_add Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251336/231235). The following code is the improved version based on [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251348/231235). On the other hand, the built-in function `.num_dimensions()` I used here for the part of array dimension mismatch detection.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};

//  Add operator
template<class T1, class T2> requires (is_multi_array<T1>&& is_multi_array<T2>)
auto operator+(const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
{
    if (input1.num_dimensions() != input2.num_dimensions())     //  Dimensions are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Array dimensions are different");
    }
    if (*input1.shape() != *input2.shape())                     //  Shapes are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Array shapes are different");
    }
    boost::multi_array output(input1);                          //  [ToDo] drawback to be improved: avoiding copying whole input1 array into output, but with appropriate memory allocation
    for (decltype(+input1.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input1.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = input1[i] + input2[i];
    }
    return output;
}

//  Minus operator
template<class T1, class T2> requires (is_multi_array<T1>&& is_multi_array<T2>)
auto operator-(const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
{
    if (input1.num_dimensions() != input2.num_dimensions())     //  Dimensions are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Array dimensions are different");
    }
    if (*input1.shape() != *input2.shape())                     //  Shapes are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Array shapes are different");
    }
    boost::multi_array output(input1);                          //  [ToDo] drawback to be improved: avoiding copying whole input1 array into output, but with appropriate memory allocation
    for (decltype(+input1.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input1.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = input1[i] - input2[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

The test of the add/minus operator:

```
int main()
{
    // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

    // Assign values to the elements
    int values = 0;
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                A[i][j][k] = values++;

    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                std::cout << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;

    auto sum_result = A;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sum_result = sum_result + A;
    }
    sum_result = sum_result - A;
    
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                std::cout << sum_result[i][j][k] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [An element_wise_add Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251336/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The previous question is the implementation of `element_wise_add` function for Boost.MultiArray. Based on [G. Sliepen's suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251348/231235), this kind of element-wise operations could be implemented with C++ operator overloading. As the result, here comes the operator+ and operator- overload functions for Boost.MultiArray.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  The operator+ and operator- overload functions here include the exception handling for the situation of different dimensions and shapes. Please check if this usage is appropriate. Moreover, I am still seeking another smarter method to improve the construction of `output` object. If there is any better idea for deducing the output structure from input without copying process, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (input1.num_dimensions() != input2.num_dimensions())
> {
>     throw std::logic_error("Array dimensions are different");
> }
> ```

If I'm not mistaken, the dimensions are static, and can be accessed through the array class's `dimensionality` constant, so I think this check could be part of the function `requires`ments, rather than a run-time error.

---

> ```
> if (*input1.shape() != *input2.shape())
> {
>     throw std::logic_error("Array shapes are different");
> }
> ```

Is it possible to create an array with `num_dimensions() == 0`? I think we could use a (probably `static_`) `assert`ion to prove to ourselves and later maintainers that dereferencing the pointer returned by `shape()` is safe.

I believe `*input1.shape()` could be written as `input1.size()`, which is simpler.

---

> ```
> for (decltype(+input1.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input1.shape()[0]; i++)
> ```

Isn't `input1.shape()[0]` simply `*input1.shape()`? i.e. `input1.size()` again.

---

```
boost::multi_array output(input1);
```

So... the type of the output array is always the same as the type of `input1`? This seems very arbitrary, and could lead to unexpected type differences when simply changing `a + b` to `b + a`.

Perhaps we could use `decltype(input1[0] + input2[0])` to get a more appropriate "common" element type for the output?

---

It might be neater to implement `operator+=` instead, and then implement `operator+` using `operator+=`.

(And similarly for `operator-=` and `operator-`).