# An element_wise_multiplication and an element_wise_division Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20, boost, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [An element_wise_add Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251336/231235) and [An Add/Minus Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251379/231235). Besides the basic element-wise add / minus operations, I am trying to implement an `element_wise_multiplication` function and an `element_wise_division` function here for Boost.MultiArray. The new concept `is_multiplicable`, `is_divisible` and `is_multi_array_dimensionality_equal` (as [user673679's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/275356/231235) mentioned, considering the dimensions are static, the checking statement has been added in the function `requires`ments) used here are as below.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_multiplicable = requires(T x)
{
    x * x;
};

template<typename T>
concept is_divisible = requires(T x)
{
    x / x;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept is_multi_array_dimensionality_equal =
is_multi_array<T1> && is_multi_array<T2> && requires(T1 x, T2 y)
{
    T1::dimensionality == T2::dimensionality;
};
```

The another used concept `is_multi_array`:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};
```

The implementation of  `element_wise_multiplication` function and `element_wise_division` function:

```
//  Multiplication
template<is_multiplicable T1, is_multiplicable T2>
auto element_wise_multiplication(const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
{
    return input1 * input2;
}

template<is_multi_array T1, is_multi_array T2>
requires (is_multi_array_dimensionality_equal<T1, T2>)
auto element_wise_multiplication(const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
{
    if (input1.num_dimensions() != input2.num_dimensions())     //  Dimensions are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
        throw std::logic_error("Array dimensions are different");
    if (*input1.shape() != *input2.shape())                     //  Shapes are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
        throw std::logic_error("Array shapes are different");
    boost::multi_array output(input1);                          //  drawback to be improved: avoiding copying whole input1 array into output, but with appropriate memory allocation
    for (decltype(+input1.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input1.shape()[0]; ++i)
        output[i] = element_wise_multiplication(input1[i], input2[i]);
    return output;
}

template<typename T>
concept is_divisible = requires(T x)
{
    x / x;
};

//  Division
template<is_divisible T1, is_divisible T2>
auto element_wise_division(const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
{
    if (input2 == 0)
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    return input1 / input2;
}

template<is_multi_array T1, is_multi_array T2>
requires (is_multi_array_dimensionality_equal<T1, T2>)
auto element_wise_division(const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
{
    if (input1.num_dimensions() != input2.num_dimensions())     //  Dimensions are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
        throw std::logic_error("Array dimensions are different");
    if (*input1.shape() != *input2.shape())                     //  Shapes are different, unable to perform element-wise add operation
        throw std::logic_error("Array shapes are different");
    boost::multi_array output(input1);                          //  drawback to be improved: avoiding copying whole input1 array into output, but with appropriate memory allocation
    for (decltype(+input1.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input1.shape()[0]; ++i)
        output[i] = element_wise_division(input1[i], input2[i]);
    return output;
}
```

The test for the `element_wise_multiplication` function and the `element_wise_division` function:

```
int main()
{
    // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

    // Assign values to the elements
    int values = 1;
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                A[i][j][k] = values++;

    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                std::cout << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;

    auto test_result = A;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        test_result = element_wise_multiplication(test_result, A);
    }
    test_result = element_wise_division(test_result, A);
    
    for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
                std::cout << test_result[i][j][k] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [An element_wise_add Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251336/231235) and
  [An Add/Minus Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251379/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The previous questions are the implementation of add / minus operations for Boost.MultiArray and I am trying to implement an `element_wise_multiplication` function and `element_wise_division` function here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  There are three new concepts `is_multiplicable`, `is_divisible` and `is_multi_array_dimensionality_equal` have been implemented here. I am not sure is this a good practice although it seems to work fine with the test example mentioned above. On the other hand, the reason for not overloading the operator* and operator/ directly is that the symbol `*` and `/` are hard to indicate element-wise multiplication and division clearly. There are some more complex high dimensional matrix multiplication calculations maybe like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63074/819308). If there is any further suggestion about this idea, please let me know.