# An Element-wise Increment and Decrement Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, boost, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform Template Function for BoostMultiArray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251620/231235) and [An Add/Minus Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251379/231235). Besides the add / minus operator for Boost.MultiArray, I am trying to implement an element-wise increment operator and decrement operator as below. The `recursive_transform` template function is used here to handle the element-wise incresing and decresing work.

```
//  Element Increment Operator
//  Define nonmember prefix increment operator
template<class T> requires is_multi_array<T>
auto operator++(T& input)
{
    input = recursive_transform(input, [](auto& x) {return x + 1; });
    return input;
}

//  Define nonmember postfix increment operator
template<class T> requires is_multi_array<T>
auto operator++(T& input, int i)
{
    auto output = input;
    input = recursive_transform(input, [](auto& x) {return x + 1; });
    return output;
}

//  Element Decrement Operator
//  Define nonmember prefix decrement operator
template<class T> requires is_multi_array<T>
auto operator--(T& input)
{
    input = recursive_transform(input, [](auto& x) {return x - 1; });
    return input;
}

//  Define nonmember postfix decrement operator
template<class T> requires is_multi_array<T>
auto operator--(T& input, int i)
{
    auto output = input;
    input = recursive_transform(input, [](auto& x) {return x - 1; });
    return output;
}
```

The used `recursive_transform` template function and the other concepts:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_back_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::back_inserter(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_elements_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::begin(x)->begin();
    std::end(x)->end();
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

template<class T, class F>
auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

template<class T, std::size_t S, class F>
auto recursive_transform(const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [f](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>>&& is_iterable<Container<Ts...>> && !is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
// non-recursive version
auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(f(*input.cbegin()));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;

    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output),
        [&](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );

    return output;
}

template<class T, class F> requires (is_multi_array<T>)
auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The test of the nonmember postfix increment operator for Boost.MultiArray is as below.

```
// Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
typedef array_type::index index;
array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

// Assign values to the elements
int values = 1;
for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            A[i][j][k] = values++;

std::cout << "A:" << std::endl;
for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;

auto B = A++;

std::cout << "After executing auto B = A++" << std::endl;

std::cout << "A:" << std::endl;
for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;

std::cout << "B:" << std::endl;
for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << B[i][j][k] << std::endl;
```

The whole experimental code can be checked at [here](https://gist.github.com/Jimmy-Hu/b76591fb1ad9317f9a0548fe4d70ff1f).

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform Template Function for BoostMultiArray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251620/231235) and

  [An Add/Minus Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251379/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The previous question [A recursive_transform Template Function for BoostMultiArray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251620/231235) focused on `recursive_transform` template function and [An Add/Minus Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251379/231235) just mentioned that the `+` and `-` operator for Boost.MultiArray. I am trying to propose the `++` and `--` operator overloading implementation here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am not sure if this is a good idea to call another function (such as the usage of `recursive_transform` template function here) in `++` and `--` operator. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
auto operator++(T& input)
{
    input = recursive_transform(input, [](auto& x) {return x + 1; });
```

So the outer call to `operator++` causes recursion, but the recursive call uses `+ 1` instead of `++`. There might be types where these operations are not equivalent, where only one of the two operations is supported, and/or where one of them has very different performance. Make sure you use `operator++` on all levels of the recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About the part of using `operator++` on all levels of the recursion, this means in both prefix increment operator and postfix increment operator?

Comment: Yes, the prefix version should `return ++x`, the postfix version `return x++`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the recursion process, there is something like `boost::detail::multi_array::const_sub_array` which can't apply `++` successfully. Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: Well if it's `const` you cannot modify it, so `++` and `--` operators can't be used on them. There is nothing you can do about that.