# A ones Function for Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, boost, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [An Element-wise Increment and Decrement Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251684/231235) and [A recursive_transform Template Function for BoostMultiArray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251620/231235). I am trying to implement a `ones` function which can construct a new Boost.MultiArray object with the given dimension and assign each value to `1`. This `ones` function is also based on `recursive_transform` template function. The value assignment task is handled by `[](auto& x) { return 1; }` lambda function which is passed into `recursive_transform`.

The main implementation of `ones` function is as below.

```
template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto ones(boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims> size)
{
    boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> output(size);
    return recursive_transform(output, [](auto& x) { return 1; });
}
```

Just for convenience, the used `recursive_transform` template function can also be checked here.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_back_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::back_inserter(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_elements_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::begin(x)->begin();
    std::end(x)->end();
};

template<typename T>
concept is_element_visitable = requires(T x)
{
    std::visit([](auto) {}, *x.begin());
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };


template<class T, class F>
auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

template<class T, std::size_t S, class F>
auto recursive_transform(const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [f](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>>&& is_iterable<Container<Ts...>> && !is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
// non-recursive version
auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(f(*input.cbegin()));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;

    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output),
        [&](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );

    return output;
}

template<class T, class F> requires (is_multi_array<T>)
auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The test of this `ones` function:

```
auto A = ones<double, 3>(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

typedef decltype(A)::index index;

std::cout << "A:" << std::endl;
for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;
```

The whole experimental code can be checked at [here](https://gist.github.com/Jimmy-Hu/74cf5e27f6edc42ecae58eef236aed1b).

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [An Element-wise Increment and Decrement Operator For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251684/231235) and

  [A recursive_transform Template Function for BoostMultiArray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251620/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The template function `ones` has been created in this question.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please check the implementation of `ones` function above. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make it more generic

What if I want twos or threes? What if `T` is a `std::string`?

## Consider avoiding recursion in this case

Since you only pass in the size of the outer `multi_array` to `ones()`, it doesn't make sense to call `recursive_transform()`. You can access all the elements of the `multi_array` directly, and initialize them with [`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

```
template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto filled_multi_array(boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims> size, const T &value)
{
    boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> output(size);
    std::fill_n(output.data(), output.num_elements(), value);
    return output;
}
```

As a bonus, since you now pass a value to the function, it can deduce the type of it, so you no longer have to specify any template parameters:

```
auto A = filled_multi_array(boost::extents[3][4][2], 1.0);
```