# A filled_multi_array Template Function for Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, boost

This is a follow-up question for [A ones Function for Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251764/231235). Thanks to [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251832/231235), the mentioned method which can set various initial value is better in generic purpose usage. However, the previous function specified the input type which must be `boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims>`. The type issue happened in some cases, an example is as below. The object `filled_multi_array1` is created first with `filled_multi_array(boost::extents[3][4][2], 1.0)`. This works well. I want to create a `filled_multi_array2` object which size is as same as `filled_multi_array1` and the initial value is `2.0`. This doesn't work in existed version of `filled_multi_array` function.

```
auto filled_multi_array1 = filled_multi_array(boost::extents[3][4][2], 1.0);
auto filled_multi_array2 = filled_multi_array<double, filled_multi_array1.dimensionality>(filled_multi_array1.shape(), 2.0);

for (decltype(filled_multi_array2)::index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (decltype(filled_multi_array2)::index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (decltype(filled_multi_array2)::index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << filled_multi_array2[i][j][k] << std::endl;
```

Then, I found that the type returned from `.shape()` function is this one `const boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_base::size_type*`. It seems that the another function overloading is needed to handle the above `filled_multi_array2` case. The experimental code of the `filled_multi_array` function with the input type `const boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_base::size_type*` is as follows.

```
template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto filled_multi_array(const boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_base::size_type* size, const T& value)
{
    boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> output(reinterpret_cast<boost::array<size_t, NumDims> const&>(*size));
    std::fill_n(output.data(), output.num_elements(), value);
    return output;
}
```

With this overloaded function, `filled_multi_array2` object can be generated successfully and the output is like:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

The full implementation of `filled_multi_array` template function:

```
template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto filled_multi_array(boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims> size, const T& value)
{
    boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> output(size);
    std::fill_n(output.data(), output.num_elements(), value);
    return output;
}

template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto filled_multi_array(const boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_base::size_type* size, const T& value)
{
    boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> output(reinterpret_cast<boost::array<size_t, NumDims> const&>(*size));
    std::fill_n(output.data(), output.num_elements(), value);
    return output;
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A ones Function for Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251764/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The another overloaded `filled_multi_array` function has been added here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am trying to handle both cases, including the one with the specified shape directly and the other one with `.shape()` function (the shape is referenced from another Boost.MultiArray object). If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks bad, but that's not your fault. `boost::multi_array` just has a terrible interface. In any case, you want to avoid passing the shape twice, because this can give problems:

```
auto large_array = filled_multi_array(boost::extents[1][2][3][4][5], 1.0);
auto small_array = filled_multi_array(boost::extents[1], 1.0);
auto another_array = filled_multi_array<double, large_array.dimensionality>(small_array.shape(), 2.0);
```

The above will compile without errors, but might crash at runtime, since `small_array.shape()` is a pointer to an array that doesn't have as many elements as expected. I don't know why the interface is so terrible, if they would have `.shape()` return a (reference to a) `boost::array<size_t, NumDims>` it would all be checkable at compile time and without needing `reinterpret_cast`s.

So to prevent errors, you want to avoid having to pass two separate pieces of information. One possibility is just passing the array whose shape you want to copy as an argument:

```
template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto filled_multi_array(const boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> &input, const T& value) {
    boost::multi_array<T, NumDims> output(reinterpret_cast<boost::array<size_t, NumDims> const&>(input.shape()));
    std::fill_n(output.data(), output.num_elements(), value);
    return output;
}
```

But that interface will create confusion: does the following line modify the input?

```
filled_multi_array(filled_multi_array1, 2.0);
```

Another possibility is to keep just the first `filled_multi_array()` variant, but create a helper function to create a `extent_gen` from a `multi_array`:

```
template<std::size_t NumDims>
auto get_extents(const boost::multi_array &input) {
    boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims> output;

    // Set the shape of output according to input.shape(),
    // left as an exercise to the reader.
    ...

    return output;
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
auto filled_multi_array1 = filled_multi_array(boost::extents[3][4][2], 1.0);
auto filled_multi_array2 = filled_multi_array(get_extents(filled_multi_array1), 2.0);
```