# A get_extents helper function for Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, boost

This is a follow-up question for [A filled_multi_array Template Function for Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251865/231235). Based on [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251880/231235), there is another `get_extents` template function mentioned for handling retrieving `boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims>` type size information from a `multi_array`. I am trying to implement this `get_extents` template function here.

```
template<class T, std::size_t NumDims>
auto get_extents(const boost::multi_array<T, NumDims>& input) {
    boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims> output;
    std::vector<size_t> shape_list;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NumDims; i++)
    {
        shape_list.push_back(input.shape()[i]);
    }
    std::copy(shape_list.begin(), shape_list.end(), output.ranges_.begin());
    return output;
}
```

I am trying to copy shape content into the `output` object. In general cases, `boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen` object is always constructed by `boost::extents[][][]...`. However, I am not sure how to use `boost::extents` in this context and I fill the values of shape information into `output.ranges_` instead. It works with the following testing code.

```
auto filled_multi_array1 = filled_multi_array(boost::extents[3][4][2], 1.0);
auto filled_multi_array2 = filled_multi_array(get_extents(filled_multi_array1), 2.0);

//  Checking shape
std::cout << "filled_multi_array2.shape()[0]:" << filled_multi_array2.shape()[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "filled_multi_array2.shape()[1]:" << filled_multi_array2.shape()[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "filled_multi_array2.shape()[2]:" << filled_multi_array2.shape()[2] << std::endl;

for (decltype(filled_multi_array2)::index i = 0; i != filled_multi_array2.shape()[0]; ++i)
    for (decltype(filled_multi_array2)::index j = 0; j != filled_multi_array2.shape()[1]; ++j)
        for (decltype(filled_multi_array2)::index k = 0; k != filled_multi_array2.shape()[2]; ++k)
            std::cout << filled_multi_array2[i][j][k] << std::endl;
```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A filled_multi_array Template Function for Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251865/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The `extent_gen` function implementation is the main part in this question.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  The `shape_list` which type is `std::vector<size_t>` in `get_extents` function is used just for copying shape data into `output.ranges_`. The reason why I create a `std::vector` for this operation is that there is neither `.begin()` function nor `.end()` function in `input.shape()`. Something like `std::copy(input.shape().begin(), input.shape().end(), output.ranges_.begin());` doesn't work. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Comment: May I ask, What are you developing?

Comment: Some programs for multidimensional data processing experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Avoid unnecessary temporary variables

There still is no need for the temporary vector `shape_list`, just use [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
boost::detail::multi_array::extent_gen<NumDims> output;
std::copy_n(input.shape(), NumDims, output.ranges_.begin());
```

Please take some time to look at the list of all the [STL algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). There are lots of useful functions there that will save you a lot of time. You don't have to remember them all, but get a feel for the type of functionality it provides, and next time you have a problem you might remember that some existing algorithm might solve it for you. The [World Map of C++ STL Algorithms](https://www.fluentcpp.com/getthemap/) is also a great resource to build intuition for it.