# A Sine Template Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, boost, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [An element_wise_add Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251336/231235). Besides the basic add operation applying onto each element, I am trying to implement a sine template function which can apply `std::sin()` on each element. A new concept `with_std_sin` is created as below.

```
template<typename T>
concept with_std_sin = requires(T x)
{
    std::sin(x);
};
```

The main body of this `sin` template function is here. The similar recursive technique is also used in order to go through all elements.

```
template<class T> requires (with_std_sin<T>)
auto sin(const T& input)
{
    return std::sin(input);
}

template<class T> requires (is_multi_array<T>)
auto sin(const T& input)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = sin(input[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The test of this `sin` template function:

```
// Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
typedef array_type::index index;
array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

// Assign values to the elements
int values = 1;
for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            A[i][j][k] = values++;

for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << A[i][j][k] << std::endl;

auto test_result = sin(A);

for (index i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        for (index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
            std::cout << test_result[i][j][k] << std::endl;
```

All suggestions are welcome.

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [An element_wise_add Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251336/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The previous question is the implementation of applying add operation onto each element in Boost.MultiArray. The main idea in this question is to implement a `sin` template function for calculating trigonometric sine value of each element.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  In my opinion, I am not sure is this a good idea about the implementation and the usage of the `with_std_sin` concept here. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very simple and clean. I would change the name of `with_std_sin` though. There are some [guidelines for naming concepts](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1851r0.html#proposal) that suggest that it should be named `sinable`. That looks a bit weird, but everything I can think of to describe "something that std::sin supports" looks weird in some way, so it is as good as any name.

However, consider that you might want to apply many other functions to the contents of a `boost::multi_array` as well, not just `std::sin`. In that case, a `recursive_transform()` that handles `multi_array`s is the way to go, so you could "just" write:

```
auto test_result = recursive_transform(A, [](auto &x){return std::sin(x);});
```

Or at least use that to define `sin()`, `cos()` and so on in therms of `recursive_transform()` without having to duplicate code.