euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for Image in C++
This is a follow-up question for Manhattan distance calculation between two images in C++. For learning C++23 and researching purposes, I am attempting to implement a function euclidean_distance for calculating Euclidean distance between two images input. The foumula of Euclidean distance calculation is as below.
Given two two-dimensional inputs X1 and X2 with size N1 x N2. The Euclidean distance of X1 and X2 is defined as
$$
\begin{split}
D_{Euclidean}(X_{1}, X_{2}) & = \left\|X_{1} - X_{2}\right\| \\
        & = \sqrt{\sum_{k_{1} = 1}^{N_{1}} \sum_{k_{2} = 1}^{N_{2}} {( X_{1}(k_{1}, k_{2}) - X_{2}(k_{1}, k_{2}) )}^{2}}
\end{split}
$$
The experimental implementation

euclidean_distance template function implementation
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<class ExPo, arithmetic ElementT = double>
    requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static ElementT euclidean_distance(
        ExPo execution_policy,
        const Image<ElementT>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT>& input2
        )
    {
        if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        auto function = [&](const Image<ElementT>& _input1, const Image<ElementT>& _input2)
            {
                return std::pow(recursive_reduce(pow(execution_policy, subtract(_input1, _input2), 2.0).getImageData(), ElementT{}), 0.5);
            };
        return std::invoke(function, input1, input2);
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<arithmetic ElementT = double>
    constexpr static ElementT euclidean_distance(
        const Image<ElementT>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT>& input2
        )
    {
        if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        auto function = [&](const Image<ElementT>& _input1, const Image<ElementT>& _input2)
            {
                return std::pow(recursive_reduce(pow(subtract(_input1, _input2), 2.0).getImageData(), ElementT{}), 0.5);
            };
        return std::invoke(function, input1, input2);
    }
}


recursive_reduce template function implementation
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  recursive_reduce template function implementation
    //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251310/231235
    template<class T, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
    requires(std::regular_invocable<Function, ValueType, T>)
    constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, ValueType init, const Function& f)
    {
        return std::invoke(f, init, input);
    }

    template<std::ranges::range Container, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
    constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const Container& input, ValueType init, const Function& f = std::plus<ValueType>())
    {
        for (const auto& element : input) {
            init = recursive_reduce(element, init, f);
        }
        return init;
    }
}


pow template function implementation
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template<arithmetic ElementT = double, arithmetic ExpT = double>
    constexpr static auto pow(const Image<ElementT>& input, ExpT exp)
    {
        return pixelwiseOperation([&](auto&& element) { return std::pow(element, exp); }, input);
    }

    //  pow template function implementation
    template<class ExPo, arithmetic ElementT = double, arithmetic ExpT = double>
    requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static auto pow(ExPo execution_policy, const Image<ElementT>& input, ExpT exp)
    {
        return pixelwiseOperation(execution_policy, [&](auto&& element) { return std::pow(element, exp); }, input);
    }
}


pixelwiseOperation template function implementation
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  pixelwiseOperation template function implementation
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto pixelwiseOperation(auto op, const Args&... inputs)
    {
        auto transformed_data = recursive_transform<unwrap_level>(
                op,
                inputs.getImageData()...);
        auto output = Image<recursive_unwrap_type_t<unwrap_level, decltype(transformed_data)>>(
            transformed_data,
            first_of(inputs...).getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  pixelwiseOperation template function implementation
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class InputT>
    requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static auto pixelwiseOperation(ExPo execution_policy, auto op, const Image<InputT>& input1)
    {
        auto transformed_data = recursive_transform<unwrap_level>(
                                    execution_policy,
                                    op,
                                    (input1.getImageData()));
        auto output = Image<recursive_unwrap_type_t<unwrap_level, decltype(transformed_data)>>(
            transformed_data,
            input1.getSize());
        return output;
    }
}



Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for Image in C++
//  Developed by Jimmy Hu

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

namespace TinyDIP
{
    struct RGB
    {
        std::uint8_t channels[3];
    };

    struct RGB_DOUBLE
    {
        double channels[3];
    };

    using GrayScale = std::uint8_t;

    struct HSV
    {
        double channels[3];    //  Range: 0 <= H < 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 255
    };

    struct BMPIMAGE
    {
        std::filesystem::path FILENAME;

        unsigned int XSIZE;
        unsigned int YSIZE;
        std::uint8_t FILLINGBYTE;
        std::uint8_t* IMAGE_DATA;
    };
    
    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458312/6667035
    template <typename>
    struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};

    template <typename ...T>
    struct is_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T>
    concept image_element_standard_floating_point_type =
        std::same_as<double, T>
        or std::same_as<float, T>
        or std::same_as<long double, T>
    ;

    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> or is_complex<T>::value;

    //  recursive_depth function implementation
    template<typename T>
    constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
    {
        return std::size_t{0};
    }

    template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
    constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
    {
        return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
    }

    //  recursive_depth template function implementation with target type
    template<typename T_Base, typename T>
    constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
    {
        return std::size_t{0};
    }

    template<typename T_Base, std::ranges::input_range Range>
    requires (!std::same_as<Range, T_Base>)
    constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
    {
        return recursive_depth<T_Base, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
    }

    //  recursive_reduce template function implementation
    //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251310/231235
    template<class T, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
    requires(std::regular_invocable<Function, ValueType, T>)
    constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, ValueType init, const Function& f)
    {
        return std::invoke(f, init, input);
    }

    template<std::ranges::range Container, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
    constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const Container& input, ValueType init, const Function& f = std::plus<ValueType>())
    {
        for (const auto& element : input) {
            init = recursive_reduce(element, init, f);
        }
        return init;
    }

    template<typename T>
    concept is_recursive_reduceable = requires(T x)
    {
        recursive_reduce(x, T{});
    };

    //  recursive_unwrap_type_t struct implementation
    template<std::size_t, typename, typename...>
    struct recursive_unwrap_type { };

    template<class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
    struct recursive_unwrap_type<1, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
    {
        using type = std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>;
    };

    template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
    requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container1<Ts1...>> &&
                requires { typename recursive_unwrap_type<
                                        unwrap_level - 1,
                                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
                                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
    struct recursive_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
    {
        using type = typename recursive_unwrap_type<
            unwrap_level - 1,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>
            >::type;
    };

    template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename T1, typename... Ts>
    using recursive_unwrap_type_t = typename recursive_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, T1, Ts...>::type;

    //  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
    template<std::size_t, typename, typename>
    struct recursive_invoke_result { };

    template<typename T, typename F>
    struct recursive_invoke_result<0, F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

    template<std::size_t unwrap_level, std::copy_constructible F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>> &&
            requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<unwrap_level - 1, F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
    struct recursive_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container<Ts...>>
    {
        using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<unwrap_level - 1, F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
    };

    template<std::size_t unwrap_level, std::copy_constructible F, typename T>
    using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, T>::type;

    //  recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t implementation
    template<std::size_t, typename, typename, typename...>
    struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result { };

    template<std::copy_constructible F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
    struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<1, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
    {
        using type = Container1<std::invoke_result_t<F,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>>;
    };

    template<std::size_t unwrap_level, std::copy_constructible F, class...Ts1, template<class...>class Container1, typename... Ts>
    requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container1<Ts1...>> &&
                requires { typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
                                        unwrap_level - 1,
                                        F,
                                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
                                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
    struct recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container1<Ts1...>, Ts...>
    {
        using type = Container1<
            typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<
            unwrap_level - 1,
            F,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Container1<Ts1...>>,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...
            >::type>;
    };

    template<std::size_t unwrap_level, std::copy_constructible F, typename T1, typename... Ts>
    using recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_variadic_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, T1, Ts...>::type;

    //  recursive_array_invoke_result struct implementation
    template<std::size_t, typename, typename, typename...>
    struct recursive_array_invoke_result { };

    template<   typename F, 
                template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
                typename T,
                std::size_t N,
                typename... Ts>
    struct recursive_array_invoke_result<1, F, Container<T, N>, Ts...>
    {
        using type = Container<
            std::invoke_result_t<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>,
            N>;
    };

    template<   std::size_t unwrap_level,
                typename F, 
                template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
                typename T,
                std::size_t N,
                typename... Ts>
    requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>> &&
                requires { typename recursive_array_invoke_result<
                                        unwrap_level - 1,
                                        F,
                                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>,
                                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
    struct recursive_array_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container<T, N>, Ts...>
    {
        using type = Container<
            typename recursive_array_invoke_result<
            unwrap_level - 1,
            F,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>,
            std::ranges::range_value_t<Ts>...
            >::type, N>;
    };

    template<   std::size_t unwrap_level,
                typename F,
                template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
                typename T,
                std::size_t N,
                typename... Ts>
    using recursive_array_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_array_invoke_result<unwrap_level, F, Container<T, N>, Ts...>::type;

    template<std::size_t index = 1, typename Arg, typename... Args>
    constexpr static auto& get_from_variadic_template(const Arg& first, const Args&... inputs)
    {
        if constexpr (index > 1)
            return get_from_variadic_template<index - 1>(inputs...);
        else
            return first;
    }

    //  first_of template function implementation
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr static auto& first_of(const Args&... inputs) {
        return get_from_variadic_template<1>(inputs...);
    }

    template<typename OutputIt, std::copy_constructible NAryOperation, typename InputIt, typename... InputIts>
    OutputIt transform(OutputIt d_first, NAryOperation op, InputIt first, InputIt last, InputIts... rest) {
        while (first != last) {
            *d_first++ = op(*first++, (*rest++)...);
        }
        return d_first;
    }

    //  recursive_transform template function for the multiple parameters cases (the version with unwrap_level)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::copy_constructible F, class Arg1, class... Args>
    requires(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<Arg1>())
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const F& f, const Arg1& arg1, const Args&... args)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, Arg1, Args...> output{};
            transform(
                std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                [&f](auto&& element1, auto&&... elements) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(f, element1, elements...); },
                std::ranges::cbegin(arg1),
                std::ranges::cend(arg1),
                std::ranges::cbegin(args)...
            );
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::regular_invocable<F, Arg1, Args...>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, arg1, args...);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, Arg1, Args...>, "The function passed to recursive_transform() cannot be invoked"
                                                                    "with the element types at the given recursion level.");
        }
    }

    //  recursive_transform template function for std::array (the version with unwrap_level)
    template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
                template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
                typename T,
                std::size_t N,
                typename F,
                class... Args>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const F& f, const Container<T, N>& arg1, const Args&... args)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            recursive_array_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, Container, T, N, Args...> output{};
            
            transform(
                std::ranges::begin(output),
                [&f](auto&& element1, auto&&... elements) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(f, element1, elements...); },
                std::ranges::cbegin(arg1),
                std::ranges::cend(arg1),
                std::ranges::cbegin(args)...
            );
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr(std::regular_invocable<F, Container<T, N>, Args...>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, arg1, args...);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, Container<T, N>, Args...>, "The function passed to recursive_transform() cannot be invoked"
                                                                                "with the element types at the given recursion level.");
        }
    }

    //  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level, with execution policy)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class T, class F>
    requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
            unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const F& f, const T& input)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            recursive_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T> output{};
            output.resize(input.size());
            std::mutex mutex;
            std::transform(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
                [&](auto&& element)
                {
                    std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
                    return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(execution_policy, f, element);
                });
            return output;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::regular_invocable<F, T>)
        {
            return std::invoke(f, input);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::regular_invocable<F, T>,  "The function passed to recursive_transform() cannot be invoked"
                                                          "with the element types at the given recursion level.");
        }
    }

    #ifdef USE_BOOST_ITERATOR
    #include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

    //  recursive_transform for the binary operation cases (the version with unwrap_level, with execution policy)
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class T1, class T2, class F>
    requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> &&
            unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>())
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const F& f, const T1& input1, const T2& input2)
    {
        if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
        {
            recursive_variadic_invoke_result_t<unwrap_level, F, T1, T2> output{};
            assert(input1.size() == input2.size());
            std::mutex mutex;

            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10457201/6667035
            //  Reference: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html
            std::for_each(execution_policy,
                boost::make_zip_iterator(
                    boost::make_tuple(std::ranges::cbegin(input1), std::ranges::cbegin(input2))
                ),
                boost::make_zip_iterator(
                    boost::make_tuple(std::ranges::cend(input1), std::ranges::cend(input2))
                ),
                [&](auto&& elements)
                {
                    auto result = recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(execution_policy, f, boost::get<0>(elements), boost::get<1>(elements));
                    std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
                    output.emplace_back(std::move(result));
                }
            );

            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            return f(input1, input2);
        }
    }
    #endif

    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.emplace_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            if (sizes.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image size vector is empty!");
            }
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(sizes),
                    std::ranges::cend(sizes),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    ));
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                 std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data = std::move(input);
            auto count = std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(sizes), std::ranges::cend(sizes), 1, std::multiplies());
            if (image_data.size() != count) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(rows), std::ranges::end(rows));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  at_without_boundary_check template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at_without_boundary_check(indexInput...));
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  get function implementation
        constexpr ElementT get(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set function implementation
        constexpr ElementT& set(const std::size_t index) noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr bool set(const TupleT location, const ElementT draw_value)
        {
            if (checkBoundaryTuple(location))
            {
                image_data[tuple_location_to_index(location)] = draw_value;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        //  cast template function implementation
        template<typename TargetT>
        constexpr Image<TargetT> cast()
        {
            std::vector<TargetT> output_data;
            output_data.resize(image_data.size());
            std::transform(
                std::ranges::cbegin(image_data),
                std::ranges::cend(image_data),
                std::ranges::begin(output_data),
                [](auto& input){ return static_cast<TargetT>(input); }
                );
            Image<TargetT> output(output_data, size);
            return output;
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }
  
        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize() const noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return size[index];
        }

        //  getStride function implementation
        constexpr std::size_t getStride(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            if(index == 0)
            {
                return std::size_t{1};
            }
            std::size_t output = std::size_t{1};
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            {
                output *= size[i];
            }
            return output;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        //  print function implementation
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 4)
            {
                for(std::size_t a = 0; a < size[3]; ++a)
                {
                    os << "group = " << a << "\n";
                    for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                        {
                            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                            {
                                //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                                os << +at(x, y, z, a) << separator;
                            }
                            os << "\n";
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
        {
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    os << "( ";
                    for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                    }
                    os << ")" << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            os << "\n";
            return;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }
        
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //  write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //  archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }
        
#endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

        //  checkBoundaryTuple template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr bool checkBoundaryTuple(const TupleT location)
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = std::tuple_size<TupleT>{};
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (std::cmp_greater_equal(index, size[parameter_pack_index]))
                    return false;
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
                return true;
            };
            return std::apply([&](auto&&... args) { return ((function(args))&& ...);}, location);
        }

        //  tuple_location_to_index template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr std::size_t tuple_location_to_index(TupleT location)
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;
            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                    position += index * stride;
                    stride *= size[i++];
                };
            std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {((update_position(args)), ...);}, location);
            return position;
        }

#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }
#endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;

    //  zeros template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto zeros(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = Image<ElementT>(sizes...);
        return output;
    }

    //  ones template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto ones(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = zeros<ElementT>(sizes...);
        output.setAllValue(1);
        return output;
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, typename Urbg, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    requires std::uniform_random_bit_generator<std::remove_reference_t<Urbg>>
    constexpr static auto rand(Urbg&& urbg, Sizes... sizes)
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Sizes) == 1)
        {
            return rand(std::forward<Urbg>(urbg), sizes..., sizes...);
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<ElementT> image_data((... * sizes));
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143753/6667035
            //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/294739/231235
            auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<ElementT>{};
            std::ranges::generate(image_data, [&dist, &urbg]() { return dist(urbg); });

            return Image<ElementT>{std::move(image_data), sizes...};
        }
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Size>
    inline auto rand(Size... size)
    {
        return rand<ElementT>(std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}, size...);
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, typename Urbg>
    requires std::uniform_random_bit_generator<std::remove_reference_t<Urbg>>
    constexpr auto rand(Urbg&& urbg) -> ElementT
    {
        auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<ElementT>{};
        return dist(urbg);
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double>
    inline auto rand()
    {
        return rand<ElementT>(std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    }

    //  check_size_same template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        if(x.getSize() != y.getSize())
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
    }

    //  pixelwiseOperation template function implementation
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto pixelwiseOperation(auto op, const Args&... inputs)
    {
        auto transformed_data = recursive_transform<unwrap_level>(
                op,
                inputs.getImageData()...);
        auto output = Image<recursive_unwrap_type_t<unwrap_level, decltype(transformed_data)>>(
            transformed_data,
            first_of(inputs...).getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  pixelwiseOperation template function implementation
    template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class InputT>
    requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static auto pixelwiseOperation(ExPo execution_policy, auto op, const Image<InputT>& input1)
    {
        auto transformed_data = recursive_transform<unwrap_level>(
                                    execution_policy,
                                    op,
                                    (input1.getImageData()));
        auto output = Image<recursive_unwrap_type_t<unwrap_level, decltype(transformed_data)>>(
            transformed_data,
            input1.getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  subtract Template Function Implementation
    template<class InputT>
    constexpr static Image<InputT> subtract(const Image<InputT>& input1, const Image<InputT>& input2)
    {
        check_size_same(input1, input2);
        return pixelwiseOperation(std::minus<>{}, input1, input2);
    }

    //  subtract Template Function Implementation
    template<class InputT>
    constexpr static auto subtract(const std::vector<Image<InputT>>& input1, const std::vector<Image<InputT>>& input2)
    {
        if (input1.size() != input2.size())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        return recursive_transform<1>(
            [](auto&& input1_element, auto&& input2_element)
            {
                return subtract(input1_element, input2_element);
            }, input1, input2);
    }

    //  subtract Function Implementation
    constexpr static Image<RGB> subtract(const Image<RGB>& input1, const Image<RGB>& input2)
    {
        check_size_same(input1, input2);
        return pixelwiseOperation(
                [](RGB x, RGB y)
                {
                    RGB rgb;
                    for(std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        rgb.channels[channel_index] = 
                        std::clamp(
                            x.channels[channel_index] - 
                            y.channels[channel_index],
                            0,
                            255);
                    }
                    return rgb;
                },
                input1,
                input2
            );
    }

    //  subtract Template Function Implementation
    template<class InputT>
    requires((std::same_as<InputT, RGB_DOUBLE>) || (std::same_as<InputT, HSV>))
    constexpr static auto subtract(const Image<InputT>& input1, const Image<InputT>& input2)
    {
        check_size_same(input1, input2);
        return pixelwiseOperation(
                [](InputT x, InputT y)
                {
                    InputT output;
                    for(std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        output.channels[channel_index] = x.channels[channel_index] - y.channels[channel_index];
                    }
                    return output;
                },
                input1,
                input2
            );
    }

    template<arithmetic ElementT = double, arithmetic ExpT = double>
    constexpr static auto pow(const Image<ElementT>& input, ExpT exp)
    {
        return pixelwiseOperation([&](auto&& element) { return std::pow(element, exp); }, input);
    }

    //  pow template function implementation
    template<class ExPo, arithmetic ElementT = double, arithmetic ExpT = double>
    requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static auto pow(ExPo execution_policy, const Image<ElementT>& input, ExpT exp)
    {
        return pixelwiseOperation(execution_policy, [&](auto&& element) { return std::pow(element, exp); }, input);
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<class ExPo, arithmetic ElementT = double>
    requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static ElementT euclidean_distance(
        ExPo execution_policy,
        const Image<ElementT>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT>& input2
        )
    {
        if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        auto function = [&](const Image<ElementT>& _input1, const Image<ElementT>& _input2)
            {
                return std::pow(recursive_reduce(pow(execution_policy, subtract(_input1, _input2), 2.0).getImageData(), ElementT{}), 0.5);
            };
        return std::invoke(function, input1, input2);
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<arithmetic ElementT = double>
    constexpr static ElementT euclidean_distance(
        const Image<ElementT>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT>& input2
        )
    {
        if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        auto function = [&](const Image<ElementT>& _input1, const Image<ElementT>& _input2)
            {
                return std::pow(recursive_reduce(pow(subtract(_input1, _input2), 2.0).getImageData(), ElementT{}), 0.5);
            };
        return std::invoke(function, input1, input2);
    }
}

void euclidean_distanceTest(
    const std::size_t size = 10)
{
    auto image1 = TinyDIP::rand(size);
    image1.print();
    auto image2 = TinyDIP::rand(size);
    image2.print();
    std::cout << TinyDIP::euclidean_distance(image1, image2) << '\n';
    return;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    euclidean_distanceTest();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    if (elapsed_seconds.count() != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " second.\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The output of the test code above:
0.00953878  0.793826    0.787568    0.351912    0.833895    0.694636    0.163848    0.0579395   0.219172    0.676219    
0.140255    0.860773    0.393177    0.637718    0.014191    0.77525 0.922339    0.535531    0.458486    0.863946    
0.061585    0.710707    0.677495    0.457914    0.540013    0.189894    0.104913    0.272731    0.115147    0.14457 
0.0905744   0.365802    0.716256    0.116334    0.567808    0.276346    0.367001    0.200893    0.70761 0.0115439   
0.647412    0.855382    0.427456    0.0396235   0.912786    0.196954    0.828956    0.675386    0.672302    0.0495413   
0.824086    0.397766    0.764772    0.898586    0.296644    0.364155    0.722149    0.292458    0.962176    0.803809    
0.570412    0.67506 0.378828    0.0743278   0.95646 0.616681    0.403286    0.635898    0.907844    0.541698    
0.710255    0.188468    0.808019    0.929266    0.363417    0.6621  0.721711    0.947205    0.428294    0.0187146   
0.420924    0.557457    0.434015    0.706958    0.191962    0.0301461   0.9609  0.534201    0.563921    0.122965    
0.565863    0.43144 0.630872    0.850531    0.370597    0.672137    0.169076    0.0822077   0.149035    0.247578    

0.168285    0.843105    0.657036    0.49907 0.403636    0.127684    0.847465    0.602907    0.916902    0.32087 
0.769749    0.203595    0.644306    0.93603 0.0433569   0.285287    0.743387    0.607781    0.409895    0.620389    
0.655659    0.294953    0.255711    0.901229    0.572798    0.51097 0.992912    0.556429    0.967994    0.29534 
0.79683 0.402363    0.129807    0.416974    0.231549    0.96138 0.900083    0.0585958   0.263341    0.438653    
0.125402    0.0854539   0.751981    0.876683    0.458296    0.361919    0.497827    0.953104    0.253608    0.0802022   
0.399071    0.90848 0.477797    0.168661    0.630785    0.668727    0.50102 0.469149    0.69789 0.967891    
0.40852 0.173924    0.294486    0.301277    0.364493    0.935996    0.877132    0.326757    0.454739    0.0595974   
0.885442    0.620615    0.253535    0.853081    0.685319    0.216334    0.359545    0.681171    0.813771    0.0932207   
0.171663    0.784122    0.330633    0.546402    0.696646    0.860106    0.101267    0.722567    0.922364    0.599609    
0.143226    0.0128522   0.174708    0.704985    0.490047    0.136345    0.965322    0.751993    0.745104    0.0659145   

4.37208
Computation finished at Sat Dec 21 16:30:48 2024
elapsed time: 0.000227424 seconds.

Godbolt link is here.
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
Manhattan distance calculation between two images in C++.

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to implement euclidean_distance template function in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please check the implementation of euclidean_distance template function and the related code.



You need a pixelwiseOperation() that takes two images as input.  You should also use std::hypot.

What actually happens here, if I read it right (I had to rely a lot on the assembly view), is:

Create an image that represents the difference.
Create an image that represents the square of that difference.
Sum the whole thing and take the square root.

In my view that's two unnecessary temporary images. That would be even worse for a 8-bits-per-channel image (due to expansion on the intermediate results). This computation could be done in one pass over the images, without allocating any extra images, that could be similarly abstracted into some sort of two-input map-reduce, or perhaps that would be called a zipWith-reduce?

auto function = [&](const Image<ElementT>& _input1, const Image<ElementT>& _input2)
    {
        return std::pow(recursive_reduce(pow(subtract(_input1, _input2), 2.0).getImageData(), ElementT{}), 0.5);
    };
return std::invoke(function, input1, input2);


I acknowledge that I don't know what I'm talking about (being a "C with classes" kind of C++ user), but couldn't you just return std::pow(... instead of using a lambda and std::invoke-ing it?
