# A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235). Thanks to [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251997/231235). Based on the mentioned suggestion, the naming of the function for getting the element count in arbitrary nested iterables is updated into `recursive_size`. Here, I am trying to implement the functions (`recursive_count` and `recursive_count_if`) which purpose are similar to `std::count` and `std::count_if` and can be used in various type arbitrary nested iterable things. In the template function `recursive_count`, the first parameter is an input nested iterable object and the second parameter is the target value to search for.

```
//  recursive_count implementation
template<class T1, class T2> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T1> && is_iterable<T1>)
auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)
{
    return std::count(input.begin(), input.end(), target);
}

//  for loop version
template<class T1, class T2> requires (is_elements_iterable<T1>)
auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)
{
    size_t output{};
    for (auto &element : input)
    {
        output += recursive_count(element, target);
    }
    return output;
}
```

In the template function `recursive_count_if`, the first parameter is also an input nested iterable object and the second parameter is a unary predicate which returns `​true` for the required elements.

```
//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<class T1, class T2> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T1> && is_iterable<T1>)
auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    return std::count_if(input.begin(), input.end(), predicate);
}

//  for loop version
template<class T1, class T2> requires (is_elements_iterable<T1>)
auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    size_t output{};
    for (auto &element : input)
    {
        output += recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Some test cases for `recursive_count` template function:

```
//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
std::vector<int> test_vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2;
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);

// determine how many integers in a std::vector<std::vector<int>> match a target value.
int target1 = 3;
int target2 = 5;
int num_items1 = recursive_count(test_vector2, target1);
int num_items2 = recursive_count(test_vector2, target2);
std::cout << "number: " << target1 << " count: " << num_items1 << '\n';
std::cout << "number: " << target2 << " count: " << num_items2 << '\n';

// std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(2);
test_deque.push_back(3);

std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

// determine how many integers in a std::deque<std::deque<int>> match a target value.
int num_items3 = recursive_count(test_deque2, target1);
int num_items4 = recursive_count(test_deque2, target2);
std::cout << "number: " << target1 << " count: " << num_items3 << '\n';
std::cout << "number: " << target2 << " count: " << num_items4 << '\n';
```

Some test cases for `recursive_count_if` template function:

```
//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
std::vector<int> test_vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2;
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);

// use a lambda expression to count elements divisible by 3.
int num_items1 = recursive_count_if(test_vector2, [](int i) {return i % 3 == 0; });
std::cout << "#number divisible by three: " << num_items1 << '\n';

// std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(2);
test_deque.push_back(3);

std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

// use a lambda expression to count elements divisible by 3.
int num_items2 = recursive_count_if(test_deque2, [](int i) {return i % 3 == 0; });
std::cout << "#number divisible by three: " << num_items2 << '\n';
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/WErYWe)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  - The function for getting the element count in arbitrary nested iterables is renamed into `recursive_size`.
  - Besides the total element count, I am trying to implement the functions (`recursive_count` and `recursive_count_if`) which purpose are similar to `std::count` and `std::count_if` and can be used in various type arbitrary nested iterable things here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  As similar as [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251997/231235) mentioned, there is another version of the last overload `recursive_count` template function implementation with `std::transform_reduce`:

  ```
  //  transform_reduce version
  template<class T1, class T2> requires (is_elements_iterable<T1>)
  auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)
  {
      return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [target](auto& element) {
          return recursive_count(element, target);
          });
  }
  ```

  Also, there is another version of the last overload `recursive_count_if` template function implementation with `std::transform_reduce`:

  ```
  //  transform_reduce version
  template<class T1, class T2> requires (is_elements_iterable<T1>)
  auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
  {
      return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto& element) {
          return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
          });
  }
  ```

  I am wondering which version is more readable.

  [A Godbolt link for this (using `std::transform_reduce`) version is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/a5scY8)

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Comment: Instead of asking for a review of one algorithm at a time, maybe it makes sense to write a library with recursive versions of all the STL algorithms, and submit that as one review?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thank you for the comment. If building a library about these recursive functions then submitting as one review is better than asking one by one. I am going to do that.

Comment: FWIW, I think "please review my library" might fall too easily foul of the site rules like "provide the code, not [merely] a link to the code" and "keep the amount of code manageable." On the other hand, it would definitely reduce the amount of repetition happening in these questions. Jimmy has to keep explaining what `concept is_iterable`  does, for example.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Based on your comment, it seems not a good idea to propose "a library" to review, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `recursive_count_if` is a bad API to begin with, because by design it can't work on a lot of types. Consider:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = {{"hello"}, {"world"}};
auto size5 = [](std::string s) { return s.size() == 5; };
auto n = recursive_count_if(v, size5);
```

With your current implementation, this doesn't work, right?

Worse, if the STL's `std::string` were non-explicitly constructible from `char`, like this—

```
std::string example = 'x';  // fortunately does not compile today
```

—then the above snippet *would* compile, and set `n` to zero. Because it would call `size5('h')`, `size5('e')`, `size5('l')`, and so on, each of which would evaluate to `false`. This is certainly not what the programmer intended!

I think the user of this API should have to tell the function explicitly how many "levels" to unwrap downward: `recursive_count_if<0>(r, p)` should be `std::ranges::count_if(r, p)`, and then `recursive_count_if<1>(r, p)` should be what the user intends in the above snippet, and so on.

In fact, maybe you should just implement a `flatten` filter that takes a "range of ranges of `E`" and returns a "range of `E`." Then `recursive_count_if<1>(r, p)` would simply be `std::ranges::count_if(flatten(r), p)`, and `recursive_count_if<2>(r, p)` would be `std::ranges::count_if(flatten(flatten(r)), p)`, and so on. I like that API a lot better.

Comment: Good point about `std::string`. But maybe it can be made to work if recursion stops automatically if, for `recursive_count()`, the container's `value_type` matches `T2` (or rather, that `T2{}==(*T1{}.begin())` is a valid expression), and in the case of `recursive_count_if`, if `T2::operator()(*T1{}.begin())` is a valid expression?

Comment: @G.Sliepen I also think so. The point is to make recursion stops properly in the right time based on the type matching process.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I am trying to implement the function which could be used like `recursive_count_if<N>(r, p)`. However, the function template can't be designed with the syntax similar to `template<std::size_t N, class T1, class T2>` because function template partial specialization is not allowed. If there is any hint to deal with this problem, please let me know.

Comment: @JimmyHu: You're trying to specialize `foo<0, T1, T2>` differently from `foo<N, T1, T2>`, right? Think about how you could use `if constexpr` here; or, pre-C++17, think about what you could do with overload resolution if `foo<I, T1, T2>` consists of the single statement `return fooImpl<T1, T2>(std::index_constant<I>(), r, p);`. </hint>

Comment: @G.Sliepen: Think about when `p` is a generic lambda. In general, "figuring out the argument type of a callable" is a fool's errand. See https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/12/perennial-impossibilities/#detect-the-first-argument-type-of-a-function

Comment: @Quuxplusone: That's a very informative blog post. Although I'm not suggesting to determine the type of parameter `T2` takes, but just to check whether applying `T2` to a `T1` works. That should be more well-defined, but of course might be surprising if you use a generic lambda and it matches the `value_type` of the outer container when you expect it to go down to the inner-most container.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: Right, "check whether applying `p` to a `T1` is well-formed" is easy and unambiguous; but then it requires the user to define their predicate `p` so that it is SFINAE-friendly, which generic lambdas aren't, in general. E.g. try your idea with `recursive_count_if(vec_of_vec_of_string, [](const auto& s) { return s.starts_with("foo"); })`. It blows up because `p(vec_of_vec_of_string[0])` seems well-formed yet when we go to instantiate `p`'s body we find that `vector<string>` has no member function `starts_with` (and by then it's too late to backtrack).

Comment: Vice versa, if `p` were, like, `[](auto x) { return x.size()==5; }`, then the question arises whether we might want to apply it at _multiple_ levels! Is this like that ["How many squares do you see?"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+many+squares&iax=images&ia=images) brainteaser? :) Really, I just think it's a bad API. Using a library API as simple as `count_if` shouldn't require the user to solve a puzzle.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I am trying to implement another version of `recursive_count_if` with specified value_type based on G. Sliepen's comments, please check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235