# A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Specified value_type for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235) and [A recursive_count_if Function with Automatic Type Deducing from Lambda for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252325/231235). As [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252375/231235) `Don't try to deduce the predicate's parameter type` and [Quuxplusone's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252154/231235) mentioned `I think the user of this API should have to tell the function explicitly how many "levels" to unwrap downward`, I am trying to implement another version `recursive_count_if` template function with unwrap level parameter. Thanks to Quuxplusone for providing the hint of using `if constexpr` to achieve this.

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T1, class T2> requires (is_iterable<T1>)
auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 1)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto& element) {
            return recursive_count_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, predicate);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return std::count_if(input.begin(), input.end(), predicate);
    }
}
```

The used `is_iterable` concept is as below. I keep it in order to get nicer error messages if user accidentily try to apply this `recursive_count_if()` on something that can not be iterated over.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};
```

Some test cases are as below. With this version `recursive_count_if`, you can always use `auto` keyword in the input lambda parameter.

```
//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
std::vector<int> test_vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2;
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);

// use a lambda expression to count elements divisible by 3.
int num_items1 = recursive_count_if<2>(test_vector2, [](auto& i) {return i % 3 == 0; });
std::cout << "#number divisible by three: " << num_items1 << '\n';

// std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(2);
test_deque.push_back(3);

std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

// use a lambda expression to count elements divisible by 3.
int num_items2 = recursive_count_if<2>(test_deque2, [](auto& i) {return i % 3 == 0; });
std::cout << "#number divisible by three: " << num_items2 << '\n';

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = { {"hello"}, {"world"} };
auto size5 = [](auto& s) { return s.size() == 5; };
auto n = recursive_count_if<2>(v, size5);
std::cout << "n:" << n << std::endl;

//  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> case
std::vector<decltype(test_vector2)> test_vector3;
test_vector3.push_back(test_vector2);
test_vector3.push_back(test_vector2);
test_vector3.push_back(test_vector2);
std::cout << recursive_count_if<1>(test_vector3,
    [test_vector2](auto& element)
    {
        return std::equal(element.begin(), element.end(), test_vector2.begin());
    }) << std::endl;
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/7P6b7W)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Specified value_type for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235) and

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Automatic Type Deducing from Lambda for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252325/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  This version of `recursive_count_if` template function is with unwrap level parameter, you can always use `auto` keyword in the input lambda parameter.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  With the given unwrap level parameter, the behavior of `recursive_count_if` template function may be more clear and be easy to use. If there is any further possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would expect the predicate not have a generic `T`-type. `F` for function, or `Pred` for predicate would be normal.
2. I suggest not copying the predicate internally. Standard algorithms generally only copy it until they finally use it, and then only use that one single copy.

   To that end, wrap it in a `std::reference_wrapper` if it isn't already wrapped, and don't mark it `const` so mutable predicates still work.

   ```
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<F, std::unwrap_reference_t<F>>)
       return recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, std::ref(predicate));
   ```
3. Retaining your previous behavior for `unwrap_level == 0` would be interesting.

   Otherwise, make it an error.
4. You could give `unwrap_level` a useful default. Like `1` or maybe `0` if you implement the previous suggestion.
5. Not sure how far you want to go, but it would be nice if the function was more SFINAE-friendly if the template-arguments don't work together.