# A batch_recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, strings, recursion, vectors, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235) and [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235). The function `recursive_count_if` is Implemented with **a `std::ranges::range` input** and **a predicate**. I am attempting to implement a function `batch_recursive_count_if` in order to handle the use cases of multiple predicates (as the example as below) via [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) technique.

```
auto predicator1 = [](auto& i) {return i == 1; };
auto predicator2 = [](auto& i) {return i == 2; };
auto predicator3 = [](auto& i) {return i == 3; };
auto predicator4 = [](auto& i) {return i == 4; };
auto predicator5 = [](auto& i) {return i == 5; };
auto predicator6 = [](auto& i) {return i == 6; };
auto predicator7 = [](auto& i) {return i == 7; };
auto predicator8 = [](auto& i) {return i == 8; };
auto predicator9 = [](auto& i) {return i == 9; };
auto predicator10 = [](auto& i) {return i == 10; };
```

The API shape is like `std::vector<int> counts = batch_recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(ranges, predicate1, predicate2, predicate3, ...);` which includes the extended the predicate parameters and the return type is a `std::vector` (to represent a sequence of output which is the result of each predicate).

**The experimental implementation**

```
//  recursive_count_if implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::range T, class Pred>
auto recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 1)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, predicate);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return std::count_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), predicate);
    }
}

//  batch_recursive_count_if implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::range T, class Pred1>
constexpr auto batch_recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred1& predicate1)
{
    std::vector<decltype(recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicate1))> output;
    output.push_back(recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicate1));
    return output;
}

template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::range T, class Pred1, class... Preds>
constexpr auto batch_recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred1& predicate1, const Preds&... predicates)
{
    auto output1 = batch_recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicate1);
    auto output2 = batch_recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicates...);
    output1.insert(std::ranges::cend(output1), std::ranges::cbegin(output2), std::ranges::cend(output2));
    return output1;
}
```

**Test cases**

The test cases below include:

- Counting `int` element in `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` which is equal to specified number.
- Counting `int` element in `std::deque<std::deque<int>>` which is equal to specified number.
- Counting `std::string` element in `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` which is equal to specified string.
- Counting `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` element in `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` which is equal to specified pattern.

```
//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
std::cout << "std::vector<std::vector<int>> case:" << '\n';
std::vector<int> test_vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2;
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);

// use lambda expressions to count the elements which is equal to 1 to 10.
auto predicator1 = [](auto& i) {return i == 1; };
std::cout << "#number is 1: " << recursive_count_if<2>(test_vector2, predicator1) << '\n';

auto predicator2 = [](auto& i) {return i == 2; };
auto predicator3 = [](auto& i) {return i == 3; };
auto predicator4 = [](auto& i) {return i == 4; };
auto predicator5 = [](auto& i) {return i == 5; };
auto predicator6 = [](auto& i) {return i == 6; };
auto predicator7 = [](auto& i) {return i == 7; };
auto predicator8 = [](auto& i) {return i == 8; };
auto predicator9 = [](auto& i) {return i == 9; };
auto predicator10 = [](auto& i) {return i == 10; };

auto batch_output1 = batch_recursive_count_if<2>(test_vector2, predicator1, predicator2, predicator3, predicator4, predicator5, predicator6, predicator7, predicator8, predicator9, predicator10);
std::cout << "Each element in batch_output1: " << '\n';
for (auto& element : batch_output1)
{
    std::cout << element << '\n';
}
std::cout << '\n';

// std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
std::cout << "std::deque<std::deque<int>> case:" << '\n';
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(2);
test_deque.push_back(3);

std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

// use lambda expressions to count the elements which is equal to 1 to 10.
std::cout << "#number is 1: " << recursive_count_if<2>(test_deque2, predicator1) << '\n';

auto batch_output2 = batch_recursive_count_if<2>(test_deque2, predicator1, predicator2, predicator3, predicator4, predicator5, predicator6, predicator7, predicator8, predicator9, predicator10);
std::cout << "Each element in batch_output1: " << '\n';
for (auto& element : batch_output2)
{
    std::cout << element << '\n';
}
std::cout << '\n';

// std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> case
std::cout << "std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>:" << '\n';
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = { {"hello"}, {"world"} };
auto is_hello = [](auto& i) { return i == "hello"; };
auto is_world = [](auto& i) { return i == "world"; };
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output of is_hello:" << recursive_count_if<2>(v, is_hello) << std::endl;
auto batch_output3 = batch_recursive_count_if<2>(v, is_hello, is_world);
std::cout << "Each element in batch_output1: " << '\n';
for (auto& element : batch_output3)
{
    std::cout << element << '\n';
}
std::cout << '\n';

//  Count specific std::vector<std::vector<int>> element in std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> case
std::cout << "Count specific std::vector<std::vector<int>> element in std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> case:" << std::endl;
std::vector<decltype(test_vector2)> test_vector3;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    test_vector3.push_back(test_vector2);
}

auto batch_output4 = batch_recursive_count_if<1>(test_vector3,
    [test_vector2](auto& element)
    {
        if (element.size() != test_vector2.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return std::equal(element.begin(), element.end(), test_vector2.begin());
    },
    [test_vector2](auto& element)
    {
        auto vector_for_comparison = test_vector2;
        vector_for_comparison.push_back(std::vector<int>{12, 2, 3});
        if (element.size() != vector_for_comparison.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return std::equal(vector_for_comparison.begin(), vector_for_comparison.end(), vector_for_comparison.begin());
    });
for (auto& element : batch_output4)
{
    std::cout << element << '\n';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

The output of the test code above:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> case:
#number is 1: 3
Each element in batch_output1:
3
3
6
6
0
0
3
3
3
3

std::deque<std::deque<int>> case:
#number is 1: 3
Each element in batch_output1:
3
3
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>:
recursive_count_if output of is_hello:1
Each element in batch_output1:
1
1

Count specific std::vector<std::vector<int>> element in std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> case:
3
0
```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A batch_recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
//#define USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array/base.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_array/collection_concept.hpp>
#endif

template<typename T>
concept is_back_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::back_inserter(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::inserter(x, std::ranges::end(x));
};

template<typename T>
concept is_minusable = requires(T x) { x - x; };

template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept is_minusable2 = requires(T1 x1, T2 x2) { x1 - x2; };

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};
#endif

template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept is_std_powable = requires(T1 x1, T2 x2)
{
    std::pow(x1, x2);
};

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_count implementation

//  recursive_count implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T& input, const auto& target)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
            "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [&target](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count<unwrap_level - 1>(element, target);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return (input == target) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

//  recursive_count implementation (the version without unwrap_level)
template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const auto& target)
{
    return recursive_count<recursive_depth<Range>()>(input, target);
}

//  recursive_count implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), target);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [execution_policy, target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(execution_policy, element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires ((std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>))
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::range T, class Pred>
auto recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 1)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, predicate);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return std::count_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), predicate);
    }
}

//  batch_recursive_count_if implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::range T, class Pred1>
constexpr auto batch_recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred1& predicate1)
{
    std::vector<decltype(recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicate1))> output;
    output.push_back(recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicate1));
    return output;
}

template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, std::ranges::range T, class Pred1, class... Preds>
constexpr auto batch_recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred1& predicate1, const Preds&... predicates)
{
    auto output1 = batch_recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicate1);
    auto output2 = batch_recursive_count_if<unwrap_level>(input, predicates...);
    output1.insert(std::ranges::cend(output1), std::ranges::cbegin(output2), std::ranges::cend(output2));
    return output1;
}

//  recursive_max implementation
template<std::totally_ordered T>
constexpr auto recursive_max(T number)
{
    return number;
}

template<std::ranges::range T>
constexpr auto recursive_max(const T& numbers)
{
    auto maxValue = recursive_max(numbers.at(0));
    for (auto& element : numbers)
    {
        maxValue = std::max(maxValue, recursive_max(element));
    }
    return maxValue;
}

//  recursive_print implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr void recursive_print(const T& input, const std::size_t level = 0)
{
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << input << '\n';
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr void recursive_print(const Range& input, const std::size_t level = 0)
{
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::for_each(input, [level](auto&& element) {
        recursive_print(element, level + 1);
    });
}

//  recursive_size implementation
template<class T> requires (!std::ranges::range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return 1;
}

template<std::ranges::range Range> requires (!(std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>))
constexpr auto recursive_size(const Range& input)
{
    return std::ranges::size(input);
}

template<std::ranges::range Range> requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const Range& input)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [](auto& element) {
        return recursive_size(element);
        });
}

//  recursive_reduce implementation
//  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251310/231235
template<class T, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, ValueType init, const Function& f)
{
    return f(init, input);
}

template<std::ranges::range Container, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const Container& input, ValueType init, const Function& f = std::plus<ValueType>())
{
    for (const auto& element : input) {
        auto result = recursive_reduce(element, ValueType{}, f);
        init = f(init, result);
    }
    return init;
}

template<typename T>
concept is_recursive_reduceable = requires(T x)
{
    recursive_reduce(x, T{});
};

template<typename T>
concept is_recursive_sizeable = requires(T x)
{
    recursive_size(x);
};

//  arithmetic_mean implementation
template<class T = double, is_recursive_sizeable Container>
constexpr auto arithmetic_mean(const Container& input)
{
    if (recursive_size(input) == 0) //  Check the case of dividing by zero exception
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    }
    return (recursive_reduce(input, T{})) / (recursive_size(input));
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
    struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_transform implementation
template <class T, std::invocable<T> F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

template <
    std::ranges::input_range Range,
    class F>
    requires (!std::invocable<F, Range>)
    constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Range& input, const F& f)
{
    recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Range> output{};

    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform(element, f); }
    );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_copy_if function 
template <std::ranges::input_range Range, std::invocable<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>> UnaryPredicate>
constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    Range output{};
    std::ranges::copy_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        unary_predicate);
    return output;
}

template <
    std::ranges::input_range Range,
    class UnaryPredicate>
    requires (!std::invocable<UnaryPredicate, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
    constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    Range output{};

    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&unary_predicate](auto&& element) { return recursive_copy_if(element, unary_predicate); }
    );
    return output;
}


//  recursive_transform_reduce implementation
template<class Input, class T, class UnaryOp, class BinaryOp = std::plus<T>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform_reduce(const Input& input, T init, const UnaryOp& unary_op, const BinaryOp& binop = std::plus<T>())
{
    return binop(init, unary_op(input));
}

template<std::ranges::range Input, class T, class UnaryOp, class BinaryOp = std::plus<T>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform_reduce(const Input& input, T init, const UnaryOp& unary_op, const BinaryOp& binop = std::plus<T>())
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::begin(input), std::end(input), init, binop, [&](auto& element) {
        return recursive_transform_reduce(element, T{}, unary_op, binop);
        });
}

//  With execution policy
template<class ExPo, class Input, class T, class UnaryOp, class BinaryOp = std::plus<T>>
//requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const Input& input, T init, const UnaryOp& unary_op, const BinaryOp& binop = std::plus<T>())
{
    return binop(init, unary_op(input));
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::range Input, class T, class UnaryOp, class BinaryOp = std::plus<T>>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform_reduce(ExPo execution_policy, const Input& input, T init, const UnaryOp& unary_op, const BinaryOp& binop = std::plus<T>())
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::begin(input), std::end(input), init, binop, [&](auto& element) {
        return recursive_transform_reduce(execution_policy, element, T{}, unary_op, binop);
        });
}


template<typename T>
concept can_calculate_variance_of = requires(const T & value)
{
    (std::pow(value, 2) - value) / std::size_t{ 1 };
};

template<typename T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    using type = T;
};

template <std::ranges::range T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>
    : recursive_iter_value_t_detail<std::iter_value_t<T>>
{ };

template<typename T>
using recursive_iter_value_t = typename recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type;

//  population_variance function implementation (with recursive_transform_reduce template function)
template<class T = double, is_recursive_sizeable Container>
requires (can_calculate_variance_of<recursive_iter_value_t<Container>>)
constexpr auto population_variance(const Container& input)
{
    if (recursive_size(input) == 0) //  Check the case of dividing by zero exception
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    }
    auto mean = arithmetic_mean<T>(input);
    return recursive_transform_reduce(std::execution::par,
        input, T{}, [mean](auto& element) {
            return std::pow(element - mean, 2);
        }, std::plus<T>()) / recursive_size(input);
}

//  population_standard_deviation implementation
template<class T = double, is_recursive_sizeable Container>
requires (can_calculate_variance_of<recursive_iter_value_t<Container>>)
constexpr auto population_standard_deviation(const Container& input)
{
    if (recursive_size(input) == 0) //  Check the case of dividing by zero exception
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    }
    return std::pow(population_variance(input), 0.5);
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
        std::fill(std::ranges::begin(output), std::ranges::end(output), element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
    }
}

void batch_recursive_count_if_test1();

int main()
{
    batch_recursive_count_if_test1();
    return 0;
}


void batch_recursive_count_if_test1()
{
    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
    std::cout << "std::vector<std::vector<int>> case:" << '\n';
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2;
    test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
    test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);
    test_vector2.push_back(test_vector);

    // use lambda expressions to count the elements which is equal to 1 to 10.
    auto predicator1 = [](auto& i) {return i == 1; };
    std::cout << "#number is 1: " << recursive_count_if<2>(test_vector2, predicator1) << '\n';

    auto predicator2 = [](auto& i) {return i == 2; };
    auto predicator3 = [](auto& i) {return i == 3; };
    auto predicator4 = [](auto& i) {return i == 4; };
    auto predicator5 = [](auto& i) {return i == 5; };
    auto predicator6 = [](auto& i) {return i == 6; };
    auto predicator7 = [](auto& i) {return i == 7; };
    auto predicator8 = [](auto& i) {return i == 8; };
    auto predicator9 = [](auto& i) {return i == 9; };
    auto predicator10 = [](auto& i) {return i == 10; };

    auto batch_output1 = batch_recursive_count_if<2>(test_vector2, predicator1, predicator2, predicator3, predicator4, predicator5, predicator6, predicator7, predicator8, predicator9, predicator10);
    std::cout << "Each element in batch_output1: " << '\n';
    for (auto& element : batch_output1)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
    std::cout << "std::deque<std::deque<int>> case:" << '\n';
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);

    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

    // use lambda expressions to count the elements which is equal to 1 to 10.
    std::cout << "#number is 1: " << recursive_count_if<2>(test_deque2, predicator1) << '\n';

    auto batch_output2 = batch_recursive_count_if<2>(test_deque2, predicator1, predicator2, predicator3, predicator4, predicator5, predicator6, predicator7, predicator8, predicator9, predicator10);
    std::cout << "Each element in batch_output1: " << '\n';
    for (auto& element : batch_output2)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> case
    std::cout << "std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>:" << '\n';
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = { {"hello"}, {"world"} };
    auto is_hello = [](auto& i) { return i == "hello"; };
    auto is_world = [](auto& i) { return i == "world"; };
    std::cout << "recursive_count_if output of is_hello:" << recursive_count_if<2>(v, is_hello) << std::endl;
    auto batch_output3 = batch_recursive_count_if<2>(v, is_hello, is_world);
    std::cout << "Each element in batch_output1: " << '\n';
    for (auto& element : batch_output3)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    //  Count specific std::vector<std::vector<int>> element in std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> case
    std::cout << "Count specific std::vector<std::vector<int>> element in std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> case:" << std::endl;
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector2)> test_vector3;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        test_vector3.push_back(test_vector2);
    }

    auto batch_output4 = batch_recursive_count_if<1>(test_vector3,
        [test_vector2](auto& element)
        {
            if (element.size() != test_vector2.size())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return std::equal(element.begin(), element.end(), test_vector2.begin());
        },
        [test_vector2](auto& element)
        {
            auto vector_for_comparison = test_vector2;
            vector_for_comparison.push_back(std::vector<int>{12, 2, 3});
            if (element.size() != vector_for_comparison.size())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return std::equal(vector_for_comparison.begin(), vector_for_comparison.end(), vector_for_comparison.begin());
        });
    for (auto& element : batch_output4)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return;
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/bvjT4WYYe)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235) and

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The function `batch_recursive_count_if` to handle the use cases of multiple predicates is implemented here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any suggestion about this implementation, please let me know.