# A recursive_transform Template Function with Calling reserve for Performance Improvement

Tags: c++, performance, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for std::array Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283546/231235). Following the suggestion mentioned in [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235), the function `recursive_transform` implementation is updated. The constraint using `requires` clause is performed instead of using `static_assert()`. The `is_iterable` concept is replaced by `std::ranges::input_range` in STL. Moreover, `std::ranges::transform()` is used in the overload that handles `std::array`. For the part of performance acceleration, another overload is added for those containers with `reserve()` member function. To separate the version for dealing with containers with / without `reserve` member function, additional concept `is_reservable` is added in this post.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementations of `recursive_transform` function and the used `is_reservable` concept are as follows.

- `recursive_transform` function implementation:

  ```
  //  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
  requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              !is_reservable<T>)                          //
  constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
      {
          recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
          std::ranges::transform(
              input,                                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
              std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
              [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
          );
          return output;
      }
      else
      {
          return std::invoke(f, input);                   //   use std::invoke()
      }
  }

  //  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level, reserve space)
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
  requires (  unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&      //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
              is_reservable<T>) 
  constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
      {
          recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
          output.reserve(input.size());                   //  Call reserve() if possible, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
          std::ranges::transform(
              input,                                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
              std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
              [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
          );
          return output;
      }
      else
      {
          return std::invoke(f, input);                   //   use std::invoke()
      }
  }

  /* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
  */
  template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
            template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
            typename T,
            std::size_t N,
            typename F >
  requires std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>
  constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
  {
      Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

      std::ranges::transform(                     //  Use std::ranges::transform() for std::arrays as well
                      input,
                      std::begin(output),
                      [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                  );

      return output;
  }
  ```
- `is_reservable` concept implementation:

  ```
  template<class T>
  concept is_reservable = requires(T input)
  {
      input.reserve(1);
  };
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A recursive_transform Template Function with Calling reserve for Performance Improvement

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <execution>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
concept is_reservable = requires(T input)
{
    input.reserve(1);
};

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>
                    >::type
                >;
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    std::invocable<Container<T, N>> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, Container<T, N>>; 
};

template<template<typename, std::size_t> typename Container,
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    typename F>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<T, N>>&&          //  F cannot be invoked to Container<Ts...> directly
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = Container<
                    typename recursive_invoke_result<
                        F,
                        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>
                    >::type
                , N>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

//  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&        //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
            !is_reservable<T>)                          //
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            input,                                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::invoke(f, input);                   //   use std::invoke()
    }
}

//  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level, reserve space)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
requires (  unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()&&      //  handling incorrect unwrap levels more gracefully, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
            is_reservable<T>) 
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
        output.reserve(input.size());                   //  Call reserve() if possible, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283563/231235
        std::ranges::transform(
            input,                                      //  passing a range to std::ranges::transform()
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return std::invoke(f, input);                   //   use std::invoke()
    }
}

/* This overload of recursive_transform is to support std::array
 */
template< std::size_t unwrap_level = 1,
          template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
          typename T,
          std::size_t N,
          typename F >
requires std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<T, N>& input, const F& f)
{
    Container<recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T>, N> output;

    std::ranges::transform(                     //  Use std::ranges::transform() for std::arrays as well
                    input,
                    std::begin(output),
                    [&f](auto&& element){ return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
                );

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    //  non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    int test_number = 3;
    std::cout << "non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly: \n"
              << recursive_transform<0>(test_number, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; }) << '\n';

    //  test with non-nested std::array container
    static constexpr std::size_t D = 3;
    auto test_array = std::array< double, D >{1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << "test with non-nested std::array container: \n"
              << recursive_transform<1>(test_array, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; })[0] << '\n';

    //  test with nested std::arrays
    auto test_nested_array = std::array< decltype(test_array), D >{test_array, test_array, test_array};
    //std::cout << "test with nested std::arrays: \n"
    //          << recursive_transform<2>(test_nested_array, [](auto&& element) { return element + 1; })[0][0] << '\n';

    //  nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly
    std::vector<int> test_vector = {
        1, 2, 3
    };
    std::cout << recursive_transform<0>(test_vector, [](auto element)
        {
            element.push_back(4);
            element.push_back(5);
            return element;
        }).size() << '\n';

    //  std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>
    auto recursive_transform_result = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_vector,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
    );                                                                                  //  For testing

    std::cout << "std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: " +
        recursive_transform_result.at(0) << '\n';                                  //  recursive_transform_result.at(0) is a std::string
    
    //  std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>
    std::cout << "std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: " 
        << recursive_transform<1>(
            recursive_transform_result,
            [](std::string x) { return std::atoi(x.c_str()); }).at(0) + 1 << '\n'; //  std::string element to int

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> -> std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
        test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
    };

    auto recursive_transform_result2 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_vector2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); }
    );                                                                                  //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result2.at(0).at(0) << '\n';     // recursive_transform_result.at(0).at(0) is also a std::string

    //  std::deque<int> -> std::deque<std::string>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(1);

    auto recursive_transform_result3 = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_deque,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result3.at(0) << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>> -> std::deque<std::deque<std::string>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);

    auto recursive_transform_result4 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_deque2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing

    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result4.at(0).at(0) << '\n';

    //  std::list<int> -> std::list<std::string>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto recursive_transform_result5 = recursive_transform<1>(
        test_list,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result5.front() << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>> -> std::list<std::list<std::string>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    auto recursive_transform_result6 = recursive_transform<2>(
        test_list2,
        [](int x)->std::string { return std::to_string(x); });                          //  For testing
    std::cout << "string: " + recursive_transform_result6.front().front() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
non-nested input test, lambda function applied on input directly: 
4
test with non-nested std::array container: 
2
5
std::vector<int> -> std::vector<std::string>: 1
std::vector<string> -> std::vector<int>: 2
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
string: 1
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/o6rxdorvP)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform Template Function with Unwrap Level for std::array Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283546/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  - The constraint using `requires` clause is performed instead of using `static_assert()`.
  - New concept `is_reservable` is proposed and another overload calling `reserve()` member function is added.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review the updated version `recursive_transform` template function. I am not sure there is any other better way to deal with containers with / without `reserve` member function for performance improvement. Any other further suggestion is welcome, certainly.

Comment: At this point, you’ve seen my previous answers and implementations (which remove the recursive-depth parameter, add support for additional types of containers, etc.) You’ve basically seen my suggestions. =

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for the comments. I want to reserve the capability to deal with the case `auto container_sum(const auto&)` and there are some related discussions about this issue in [Quuxplusone's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252053/a-recursive-count-if-function-for-various-type-arbitrary-nested-iterable-impleme#comment496788_252154). If there is any misunderstanding, please let me know.

Comment: U post a solution for `container_sum` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283581/136816), although it’s not so simple and would add `std::valarray` objects together rather than taking their sums.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for the comments. Let me think about the suggested opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid code duplication

You have two versions of `recursive_transform()` that look very similar, and only differ in whether `reserve()` is called. I would avoid the code duplication here by making use of `if constexpr`:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
requires (unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>()) 
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    …
    recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
    if constexpr (is_reservable<decltype(output)>) {
        output.reserve();
    }
    …
}
```