# An arithmetic_mean Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235) and [A Summation Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251295/231235). I am trying to implement an `arithmetic_mean` template function for calculating the arithmetic mean value of various type arbitrary nested iterable things. The `recursive_reduce` function (thanks to [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251310/231235)) and the `recursive_size` function are used here. Because both `recursive_reduce` function and `recursive_size` function are needed in the `arithmetic_mean` function here, there are two new concepts `is_recursive_reduceable` and `is_recursive_sizeable` created as follows.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_recursive_reduceable = requires(T x)
{
    recursive_reduce(x, 0.0);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_recursive_sizeable = requires(T x)
{
    recursive_size(x);
};
```

Next, the main part of `arithmetic_mean` template function:

```
template<class T> requires (is_recursive_reduceable<T> && is_recursive_sizeable<T>)
auto arithmetic_mean(const T& input)
{
    return (recursive_reduce(input, 0.0)) / (recursive_size(input));
}
```

Some test cases of this `arithmetic_mean` template function.

```
//  std::vector<int> case
std::vector<int> test_vector = {
    1, 2, 3
};
auto arithmetic_mean_result1 = arithmetic_mean(test_vector);
std::cout << arithmetic_mean_result1 << std::endl;

//  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2 = {
    test_vector, test_vector, test_vector
};
auto arithmetic_mean_result2 = arithmetic_mean(test_vector2);
std::cout << arithmetic_mean_result2 << std::endl;

// std::deque<int> case
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(1);
auto arithmetic_mean_result3 = arithmetic_mean(test_deque);
std::cout << arithmetic_mean_result3 << std::endl;

// std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
auto arithmetic_mean_result4 = arithmetic_mean(test_deque2);
std::cout << arithmetic_mean_result4 << std::endl;
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/x8bz4W)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235) and

  [A Summation Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251295/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The `arithmetic_mean` template function is the main part here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am not sure if it is a good idea to add `is_recursive_sizeable` and `is_recursive_reduceable` concepts here. Moreover, I am wondering that the name of used concept is understandable.

Comment: Arithmetic mean, even of two integers, has more [pitfalls](//stackoverflow.com/q/6735259/4850040) than you might expect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply printing output, it would be better to have self-checking unit tests, so you can fail your build as soon as you break something, rather than having to notice a change in the output.

You probably want to include some tests with very large (positive and negative) values to make sure you get accurate results with these, and don't fall foul of integer overflow (which will cause gross inaccuracy with unsigned types, and is Undefined Behaviour with signed integer types).

It's disappointing that there are no tests using primitive types other than `int`.