# Non-nested std::deque and std::list Generator Function for arithmetic_mean Function Testing in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, unit-testing, boost, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A non-nested test_vectors_generator Function for arithmetic_mean Function Testing in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252870/231235) and [An arithmetic_mean Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252732/231235). Besides `std::vector` test cases generated from `test_vectors_generator` template function, I am trying to implement `std::deque` and `std::list` test cases with `test_deques_generator` and `test_lists_generator` functions.

**The usage description**

Similar to the usage of `test_vectors_generator`, there are also four parameters in both `test_deques_generator` function and `test_lists_generator` function. The first one is a start iteration number of each element, the second one is a end iteration number of each element, the third one is a step size and the fourth one is the element count of each container.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `test_deques_generator` and `test_lists_generator` functions are as below.

```
namespace ts
{
    //...
    template<class T> requires (!is_iterable<T>)
    constexpr auto test_deques_generator(T start, T end, T step, std::size_t element_count)
    {
        if (element_count == 1)
        {
            std::list<std::deque<T>> output(((end - start) / step) + 1);
            T i = 0;            // incrementor
            std::for_each(output.begin(), output.end(), [&](auto& item) { i+=step; item = std::deque<T>{ i }; });
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            std::list<std::deque<T>> output{};
            auto test_deques = test_deques_generator(start, end, step, element_count - 1);
            std::for_each(test_deques.begin(), test_deques.end(), [&](const auto item) {
                    for (T i = start; i <= end; i += step)
                    {
                        auto new_element = item;
                        new_element.push_back(i);
                        output.push_back(new_element);
                    }
                });
            return output;
        }
    }

    template<class T> requires (!is_iterable<T>)
    constexpr auto test_lists_generator(T start, T end, T step, std::size_t element_count)
    {
        if (element_count == 1)
        {
            std::list<std::list<T>> output(((end - start) / step) + 1);
            T i = 0;            // incrementor
            std::for_each(output.begin(), output.end(), [&](auto& item) { i+=step; item = std::list<T>{ i }; });
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            std::list<std::list<T>> output{};
            auto test_deques = test_lists_generator(start, end, step, element_count - 1);
            std::for_each(test_deques.begin(), test_deques.end(), [&](const auto item) {
                    for (T i = start; i <= end; i += step)
                    {
                        auto new_element = item;
                        new_element.push_back(i);
                        output.push_back(new_element);
                    }
                });
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

The used `is_iterable` concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    *std::begin(x);
    std::end(x);
};
```

**Test cases**

1. Test cases of `test_deques_generator` and `test_lists_generator` template functions

The `recursive_print` template function (refer to the previous question [A recursive_print Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251208/231235)) is also used here. The output of `recursive_print(ts::test_deques_generator(1, 3, 1, 3));` is as follows.

```
Level 0:
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 2
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 3
 Level 1:
 1
 2
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 2
 2
 Level 1:
 1
 2
 3
 Level 1:
 1
 3
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 3
 2
 Level 1:
 1
 3
 3
 Level 1:
 2
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 2
 1
 2
 Level 1:
 2
 1
 3
 Level 1:
 2
 2
 1
 Level 1:
 2
 2
 2
 Level 1:
 2
 2
 3
 Level 1:
 2
 3
 1
 Level 1:
 2
 3
 2
 Level 1:
 2
 3
 3
 Level 1:
 3
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 3
 1
 2
 Level 1:
 3
 1
 3
 Level 1:
 3
 2
 1
 Level 1:
 3
 2
 2
 Level 1:
 3
 2
 3
 Level 1:
 3
 3
 1
 Level 1:
 3
 3
 2
 Level 1:
 3
 3
 3
```

The output of `recursive_print(ts::test_lists_generator(1, 3, 1, 3));` is as follows.

```
Level 0:
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 2
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 3
 Level 1:
 1
 2
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 2
 2
 Level 1:
 1
 2
 3
 Level 1:
 1
 3
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 3
 2
 Level 1:
 1
 3
 3
 Level 1:
 2
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 2
 1
 2
 Level 1:
 2
 1
 3
 Level 1:
 2
 2
 1
 Level 1:
 2
 2
 2
 Level 1:
 2
 2
 3
 Level 1:
 2
 3
 1
 Level 1:
 2
 3
 2
 Level 1:
 2
 3
 3
 Level 1:
 3
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 3
 1
 2
 Level 1:
 3
 1
 3
 Level 1:
 3
 2
 1
 Level 1:
 3
 2
 2
 Level 1:
 3
 2
 3
 Level 1:
 3
 3
 1
 Level 1:
 3
 3
 2
 Level 1:
 3
 3
 3
```

2. Test cases for `arithmetic_mean` template function

With [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) tool, the `std::deque` and `std::list` test cases for `arithmetic_mean` template function can be implemented as the following code.

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_char)
{
    typedef char TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_int)
{
    typedef int TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_short)
{
    typedef short TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_long)
{
    typedef long TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_long_long_int)
{
    typedef long long int TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_unsigned_char)
{
    typedef unsigned char TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_float)
{
    typedef float TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_double)
{
    typedef double TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_deques_generator_long_double)
{
    typedef long double TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_deques_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_char)
{
    typedef char TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_int)
{
    typedef int TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_short)
{
    typedef short TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_long)
{
    typedef long TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_long_long_int)
{
    typedef long long int TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_unsigned_char)
{
    typedef unsigned char TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_float)
{
    typedef float TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_double)
{
    typedef double TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lists_generator_long_double)
{
    typedef long double TestType;

    TestType start_num = 1;
    TestType end_num = 50;
    TestType step_num = 1;

    for (auto& each_test_vector : ts::test_lists_generator(start_num, end_num, step_num, 3))
    {
        //    Generate expected_value
        double expected_value = 0;
        for (auto& each_item : each_test_vector)
        {
            expected_value += each_item;
        }
        expected_value = expected_value / static_cast<double>(each_test_vector.size());

        BOOST_TEST(expected_value == arithmetic_mean(each_test_vector));
    }
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/Y68nK3)

Note: The compiling output from Godbolt is `<Compilation failed>` and the error message is `Killed - processing time exceeded`. This seems to be caused by [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) tool is too large.

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A non-nested test_vectors_generator Function for arithmetic_mean Function Testing in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252870/231235) and
  [An arithmetic_mean Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252732/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The `std::deque` test cases and `std::list` test cases for `arithmetic_mean` template function have been added.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am trying to verify the correctness of `arithmetic_mean` template function as complete as possible, including various container, various element type. If there is any suggestion or possible improvement of these test cases, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Make the desired container type a template parameter

You are duplicating a lot of code, when the only thing that changes is the type of container that your are returning. You should make the container type a template parameter, for example like so:

```
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T> requires (!is_iterable<T>)
constexpr auto test_generator(T start, T end, T step, std::size_t element_count)
{
    ...
    std::list<Container<T>> output;
    ...
}
```

Then you can write:

```
auto data = test_generator<std::deque>(0, 10, 1, 3);
```

The template template parameter is not as flexible as you might think though, for example you cannot use a custom container class that is not a template itself, nor can you easily say you want to use a non-standard allocator for the container. You can also do what the STL does for container adapters, like [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) for example:

```
template<class T, class Container = std::vector<T>> requires (!is_iterable<T>)
constexpr auto test_generator(T start, T end, T step, std::size_t element_count)
{
    ...
    std::list<Container> output;
    ...
}
```

Then you have to use it like so:

```
auto data = test_generator<int, std::deque<int>>(0, 10, 1, 3);
```

You can also add another `requires` check for the container type of course.

## Consider a non-recursive implementation

Your implementation uses recursion; each recursion builds a list with an `element_count` of one less than the previous one. It doesn't look very efficient to me; every layer except the outer one builds a list that you discard afterwards. You can instead generate the desired list without using recursion at all, by just writing a cascaded counter (think of how a [mechanical tally counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_counter) works). Here is a possible implementation:

```
template<class T, class Container = std::vector<T>>
constexpr auto test_generator(T start, T end, T step, std::size_t element_count)
{
    std::list<Container> output;

    Container counters;
    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(counters), element_count, start);

    while (true) {
        output.push_back(counters);

        std::size_t n_reset{};
        for (auto &counter: counters) {
            counter += step;

            if (counter <= end)
                break;

            counter = start;
            if (++n_reset == element_count)
                return output;
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is that this implementation stores the values in the opposite order as your implementation, but that should not be too hard to change if necessary.

## Consider writing a `std::generator` instead

What if, instead of a `std::list<Container<T>>`, you would want a `std::vector<Container<T>>`? What if you want to avoid having to store the whole result before being able to iterate through it? It would be even more flexible if you wrote a real generator function, like:

```
template<class T, class Container = std::vector<T>> requires(...)
std::generator<Container> test_generator(T start, T end, T step, std::size_t element_count)
{
    Container counters;
    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(counters), element_count, start);

    while (true) {
        co_yield counters;

        std::size_t n_reset{};
        for (auto &counter: counters) {
            counter += step;

            if (counter <= end)
                break;

            counter = start;
            if (++n_reset == element_count)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like so:

```
for (auto vec: test_generator(1, 3, 1, 3)) {
    for (auto el: vec)
        std::cout << el << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You could also make this work for older versions of C++ if you make `test_generator` a `class` that has `begin()` and `end()` functions that return iterators.

Comment: Good review! I wonder if `std::ranges::iota_view` could be used here.