# A Various Container Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Function Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, unit-testing, boost, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [std::array and std::vector Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252488/231235) and [std::deque and std::list Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252605/231235). The only thing different in the previous implemented `n_dim_vector_generator`, `n_dim_array_generator`, `n_dim_deque_generator` and `n_dim_list_generator` functions is the type of container. After checking [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252946/231235) in the question [Non-nested std::deque and std::list Generator Function for arithmetic_mean Function Testing in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252930/231235), I found that there is a way to implement a more generic template function `n_dim_container_generator`.

**The usage description**

For example, `auto test_vector = n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, 2, 3, int>(1);` is expected to create a "test_vector" object which type is `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. The content of this `test_vector` should as same as the following code.

```
std::vector<int> vector1;
vector1.push_back(1);
vector1.push_back(1);
vector1.push_back(1);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> test_vector;
test_vector.push_back(vector1);
test_vector.push_back(vector1);
test_vector.push_back(vector1);
```

There are five key parameters in the usage of `n_dim_container_generator`. With the mentioned example above, the first one `std::vector` is the type of the container in output structure, the second one `2` represents the nested layers, the third parameter `3` represents the element count in each layer, the fourth parameter `int` represents the type of base elements and the final one `1` represents the base element input which would be filled in.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `n_dim_container_generator` template function is as follows.

```
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        Container<decltype(n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, times, T>(input))> output;
        output.resize(times);
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, times, T>(input));
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

With the `recursive_print` template function (refer to the previous question [A recursive_print Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251208/231235)), the `n_dim_container_generator` template function could be tested as the following code.

```
auto test_vector = n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, 2, 3, int>(1);
recursive_print(test_vector);
```

The output is as below.

```
Level 0:
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 1
 Level 1:
 1
 1
 1
```

In order to make sure the functionality of `n_dim_container_generator`, the various test cases have been implemented.

1. The use cases of `std::vector`

With [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) tool, the various use cases of nested `std::vector` structure are implemented as below.

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_1dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_2dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_3dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_4dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_5dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_6dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_7dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_8dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(vector_test_9dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}
```

[A Godbolt link (`std::vector` part) is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/ffPbvW)

Note: The compiling output from Godbolt is `<Compilation failed>` and the error messages are `Killed - processing time exceeded` and `virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory`. This issue seems to be caused by [Boost.Test](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) tool is too large and the multidimensional container structure is too complex. If the enough memory and compile time resource is available, the test output is like:

```
Running 90 test cases...

*** No errors detected
```

2. The use cases of `std::deque` and `std::list`

When it comes to the cases of `std::deque` and `std::list`, the test code can get based on the above code by replacing the keyword `vector` into `deque` and `list`. The result can be checked as follows.

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(deque_test_1dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}
```

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_short)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef short TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_long)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_long_long_int)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long long int TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_unsigned_char)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef unsigned char TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_float)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef float TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(list_test_1dimension_long_double)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef long double TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/E75e8f)

Furthermore, with [Test case template with automated registration](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_organization_templates.html#ref_BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE), the various element type can be listed in `boost::mpl::list` and the test cases can be generated automatically.

```
typedef boost::mpl::list<char, int, short, long, long long int, unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned short int, unsigned long int, float, double, long double> test_types;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_1dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_2dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_3dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_4dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_5dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_6dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_7dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_8dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_9dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(vector_test_10dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 10;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::vector, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_vector_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_1dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_2dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_3dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_4dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_5dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_6dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_7dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_8dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_9dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(deque_test_10dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 10;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::deque, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_deque_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_1dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 1;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_2dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 2;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_3dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 3;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_4dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 4;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_5dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 5;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_6dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 6;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_7dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 7;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_8dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 8;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_9dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 9;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(list_test_10dimension, T, test_types)
{
    constexpr int nested_layer = 10;
    constexpr int element_count = 3;
    typedef T TestType;
    TestType input = 1;

    BOOST_TEST((n_dim_container_generator<std::list, nested_layer, element_count, TestType>(input)) == 
                (n_dim_list_generator<nested_layer, TestType>(input, element_count)));
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/6d1hdY)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [std::array and std::vector Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252488/231235) and

  [std::deque and std::list Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252605/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement a `n_dim_container_generator` function which can generate various container type arbitrary nested iterables in this question.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Although there are a lot of test cases above, I still think that it is hard to verify `n_dim_container_generator` template function. There are too many possible usages and if there is any potential defect existed, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Template vs. function parameters

Template parameters should normally be used for things that affect the type of the result, but not for other things. The template parameter `times` does not affect the type of the result, so it can just be a regular function parameter:

```
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        Container<decltype(n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times))> output;
        output.resize(times);
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
        return output;
    }
}
```

## Avoid unnecessary default initialization

By calling `output.resize(times)`, you force the container to default construct all elements, right before you overwrite all elements. The solution is to use `reserve()` instead, and `push_back()` the elements you want to add:

```
output.reserve(times);
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(output), times, n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
```

## Avoid repetition

You are repeating the recursive call to the function with `dim - 1` twice, once to get its return type and once to actually get a value. You can avoid the repetition by just getting a value first:

```
auto element = n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times);
Container<decltype(element)> output;
output.reserve(times);
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(output), times, element);
```

## Make use of the constructors that fill the container for you

The constructors of `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::deque` all have an overload that take a `count` and a `const T &element` as an argument, and will construct a container with the given element repeated `count` times. That's exactly what you are trying to do manually. So you can just make use of those constructors and write:

```
template<template<class...> class Container = std::vector, std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<Container, dim - 1, T>(input, times));
    }
}
```

## Non-deducible template parameters without a default value must come before template parameters with a default value

You gave the template parameter `Container` a default value, but you can actually never write something like:

```
auto data = n_dim_container_generator<2>(1, 3);
```

To fix this, make sure `std::size_t dim` comes first:

```
template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
```

Comment: My first interpretation of "*repeating the call*" was that the run-time work was being performed twice, rather than repeating the source code for it in non-evaluated context as argument to `decltype()`.  I wish I could suggest a better wording for that.

Comment: @TobySpeight Maybe "call expression"? But yeah, I couldn't find something better either.