# Avoiding requires clause if possible on a series recursive function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_transform_reduce Function for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253272/231235), [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235), [A Summation Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251295/231235), [An arithmetic_mean Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252732/231235), [A recursive_transform Template Function with Execution Policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251823/231235) and [A population_variance Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253131/231235). Thanks to [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253280/231235). I am trying to perform the suggestion that `avoiding the requires clause if possible by using the concept name instead of class in the template parameter list`. As the result, the improved version of `recursive_count` function, `recursive_count_if` function, `recursive_size` function, `recursive_reduce` function, `arithmetic_mean` function, `recursive_transform` function, `recursive_transform_reduce` function and `population_variance` function are as below.

```
template<typename T>
concept is_back_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::back_inserter(x);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_elements_iterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::begin(x)->begin();
    std::end(x)->end();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept is_std_powable = requires(T1 x1, T2 x2)
{
    std::pow(x1, x2);
};

template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

//  recursive_count implementation
template<std::ranges::range T1, class T2> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T1>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)
{
    return std::count(input.begin(), input.end(), target);
}

//  transform_reduce version
template<is_elements_iterable T1, class T2>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [target](auto& element) {
        return recursive_count(element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<std::ranges::range T1, class T2> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T1>)
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    return std::count_if(input.begin(), input.end(), predicate);
}

//  transform_reduce version
template<is_elements_iterable T1, class T2>
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
        });
}

//  recursive_size implementation
template<class T> requires (!std::ranges::range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return 1;
}

template<std::ranges::range T> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return input.size();
}

template<is_elements_iterable T>
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [](auto& element) {
        return recursive_size(element);
        });
}

//  recursive_reduce implementation
template<class T, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const T& input, ValueType init, const Function& f)
{
    return f(init, input);
}

template<std::ranges::range Container, class ValueType, class Function = std::plus<ValueType>>
constexpr auto recursive_reduce(const Container& input, ValueType init, const Function& f = std::plus<ValueType>())
{
    for (const auto& element : input) {
        auto result = recursive_reduce(element, ValueType{}, f);
        init = f(init, result);
    }
    return init;
}

template<typename T>
concept is_recursive_reduceable = requires(T x)
{
    recursive_reduce(x, T{});
};

template<typename T>
concept is_recursive_sizeable = requires(T x)
{
    recursive_size(x);
};

//  arithmetic_mean implementation
template<class T = double, is_recursive_sizeable Container>
constexpr auto arithmetic_mean(const Container& input)
{
    if (recursive_size(input) == 0) //  Check the case of dividing by zero exception
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    }
    return (recursive_reduce(input, T{})) / (recursive_size(input));
}

//  recursive_transform implementation
template<class T, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

template<class T, std::size_t S, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), 
        [f](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && std::ranges::range<Container<Ts...>> && !is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
// non-recursive version
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(f(*input.cbegin()));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}

template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;

    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output),
        [&](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(element, f);
        }
    );

    return output;
}

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<is_multi_array T, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
#endif

//  With execution policy
template<class ExPo, class T, class F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

template<class ExPo, class T, std::size_t S, class F>
requires std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const std::array<T, S>& input, const F& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));

    std::array<TransformedValueType, S> output;
    std::transform(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(),
        [execution_policy, f](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(execution_policy, element, f);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<class ExPo, template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> && std::ranges::range<Container<Ts...>> && !is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
// non-recursive version
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(f(*input.cbegin()));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output(input.size());
    std::transform(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(), f);
    return output;
}

template<class ExPo, template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>> && is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(recursive_transform(*input.cbegin(), f));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output(input.size());

    std::transform(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(), output.begin(),
        [&](auto& element)
        {
            return recursive_transform(execution_policy, element, f);
        }
    );

    return output;
}

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<class ExPo, is_multi_array T, class F>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
{
    boost::multi_array output(input);
    for (decltype(+input.shape()[0]) i = 0; i < input.shape()[0]; i++)
    {
        output[i] = recursive_transform(execution_policy, input[i], f);
    }
    return output;
}
#endif

//  recursive_transform_reduce implementation
template<class Input, class T, class UnaryOp, class BinaryOp = std::plus<T>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform_reduce(const Input& input, T init, const UnaryOp& unary_op, const BinaryOp& binop = std::plus<T>())
{
    return binop(init, unary_op(input));
}

template<std::ranges::range Input, class T, class UnaryOp, class BinaryOp = std::plus<T>>
constexpr auto recursive_transform_reduce(const Input& input, T init, const UnaryOp& unary_op, const BinaryOp& binop = std::plus<T>())
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), init, binop, [&](auto& element) {
        return recursive_transform_reduce(element, T{}, unary_op, binop);
        });
}

template<typename T>
concept can_calculate_variance_of = requires(const T & value)
{
    (std::pow(value, 2) - value) / std::size_t{ 1 };
};

template<typename T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail
{
    using type = T;
};

template <std::ranges::range T>
struct recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>
    : recursive_iter_value_t_detail<std::iter_value_t<T>>
{ };

template<typename T>
using recursive_iter_value_t = typename recursive_iter_value_t_detail<T>::type;

//  population_variance function implementation (with recursive_transform_reduce template function)
template<class T = double, is_recursive_sizeable Container>
requires (can_calculate_variance_of<recursive_iter_value_t<Container>>)
constexpr auto population_variance(const Container& input)
{
    if (recursive_size(input) == 0) //  Check the case of dividing by zero exception
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    }
    auto mean = arithmetic_mean<T>(input);
    return recursive_transform_reduce(std::execution::par,
        input, T{}, [mean](auto& element) {
        return std::pow(element - mean, 2);
        }, std::plus<T>()) / recursive_size(input);
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/6jnMoE)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_transform_reduce Function for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253272/231235),

  [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235),

  [A Summation Function For Boost.MultiArray in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251295/231235),

  [An arithmetic_mean Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252732/231235),

  [A recursive_transform Template Function with Execution Policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251823/231235) and

  [A population_variance Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253131/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  - Avoiding requires clause if possible
  - Considering the warning `potential divide by 0`, `if-throw` statement is added in `arithmetic_mean` function and `population_variance` function.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  After using the concept name instead of `class` in the template parameter list, I am not sure if concept name is still clear. Is it a good idea to remove the prefix `is_` in the usage as above? If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this update seems primarily based on the changes to the concepts and `requires` clauses, that’s what I’m going to focus on.

## `is_do_thingable` is an anti-pattern.

This is really an abuse of the idea of concepts:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_back_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::back_inserter(x);
};

// ...

template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept is_std_powable = requires(T1 x1, T2 x2)
{
    std::pow(x1, x2);
};
```

If you find yourself writing `do_thingable` concepts for every `do_thing()` function, I’d say you’re really missing the point of concepts. The point of concepts is not to dig out the guts of your algorithm, take every `do_x`, `do_y`, and `do_z` operation out of the body, and then write a `requires` clause that repeats that entire body as `requires do_xable<T> && do_yable<T> && do_zable<T>`. The point is to consider what *kind* of type your algorithm is supposed to work for. It’s about *SEMANTICS*, not *syntax*.

For example, instead of `is_std_powable<T, U>`, you (probably) want something like `floating_point<T> and (floating_point<U> or integral<U>)`. Or even better `arithmetic<T>`. Or maybe just `number<T>`. The point is, the concept is not about what you’re *doing* to the `T`, it’s about what that `T` is conceptually supposed to *be* (note the key word: “*CONCEPTually*”). If you’re raising it to a power, it’s probably supposed to be a number. If it’s not a number, then even though it might “work” with `std::pow()` (for example, you can raise `true` to the power of `false`)… it’s probably not what you want. `bool` works *syntactically* with `std::pow()`… but probably not *semantically* for any real-use purpose.

## I think you missed the point of the advice.

It looks like previous reviews suggested that you “[avoid] the `requires` clause if possible by using the concept name instead of class in the template parameter list”. That does not mean that you should eliminate *ALL* `requires` clauses, or that `requires` clauses are a bad thing in any way. It just means that instead of:

```
template <typename Container>
requires std::ranges::range<Container>
auto func(...
```

you should probably prefer:

```
template <std::ranges::range Container>
auto func(...
```

There’s no difference between the two options… except the second is shorter and easier to read, and you’re not repeating the type, so there’s less chance of screwing up.

But *this*:

```
template <is_funcable T>
auto func(T)
```

… is pretty useless. It tells me nothing about what I need for `T` to be used with `func()`… except that `T` can be used with `func()`. Which… I mean… duh, right?

This is much more useful:

```
template <typename T>
requires movable<T> and equality_comparable<T>
auto func(T)
```

*That* gives me useful information about what types I can use with `func()`, without spelling out the entire algorithm in the constraints. And the fact that it’s a `requires` clause (and not a single concept in the template preamble) isn’t a problem at all.

## Try to use standard concepts wherever possible

As near as I can tell, the purpose of `is_elements_iterable<T>` is to test that `T` is a range, and that each value in `T` is also a range.

So what is the difference between `is_elements_iterable<T>` and `std::ranges::range<T> and std::ranges::range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>`? I can’t see any, which means the latter is a better option. (And there are even better options, which I’ll get to later.)

Using existing (especially standard) concepts is especially important with concepts (as opposed to type traits and SFINAE), because of normalization and subsumption. We’ll get to that next.

## `recursive_count()`

Let’s start with the function signatures you have.

```
template<std::ranges::range T1, class T2> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T1>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)

template<is_elements_iterable T1, class T2>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T1& input, const T2 target)
```

Now, for starters, let’s use more descriptive names than `T1` and `T2`. `T1` is always going to be a container or view—a range—so why not call it that? (As for `T2`, that can be anything, so it could just be `T`.)

So why are you taking `target` by value? Imagine I have a `vector` of `string`s, and I want to count the number of times a particular very long string appears in the vector. If `target` is being taken by value, then it’s being copied. Why? Does it need to be? I can’t imagine why. Taking it by `const&` would avoid the unnecessary copy.

So, rewriting your concepts a bit (temporarily), this is what we’ve got so far:

```
template <typename Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::range<Range> and (!is_elements_iterable<Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)

template <typename Range, typename T>
requires is_elements_iterable<Range>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
```

Let’s pull out just the constraints:

```
requires std::ranges::range<Range> and (!is_elements_iterable<Range>)

requires is_elements_iterable<Range>
```

`is_elements_iterable` sorta-kinda implies `std::ranges::range` (not technically, because of the way `is_elements_iterable` is written… but practically, yes). So your constraints are really just:

```
requires (!is_elements_iterable<Range>)

requires is_elements_iterable<Range>
```

Now this is *NOT* the way to use constraints. This is what you’d have to do with type traits and SFINAE, because type traits and SFINAE don’t understand ordering or subsumption. But concepts do understand those things. Concepts understands that if you have two functions, and one is unconstrained while the other requires `is_elements_iterable`, then anything that satisfies `is_elements_iterable` should use the second function. You don’t need to specifically say that anything that *DOESN’T* satisfy `is_elements_iterable` should use the first; concepts already understands that.

Subsumption means that `requires foo<T> and bar<T>` is more constrained than `requires foo<T>`, so if something satisfies both the `foo` and `bar` constraints, it will choose the first requires clause. If something only satisfies `foo`, it will choose the second. If something only satisfies `bar`, or neither `foo` nor `bar`, then neither will work.

So what you really want is just:

```
/* nothing, no constraints or requires clause */

requires is_elements_iterable<Range>
```

… and this will do pretty much the exact same thing as what you’ve got.

Well, almost. You also want to constrain the range, so:

```
requires std::ranges::range<Range>

requires std::ranges::range<Range> and is_elements_iterable<Range>
```

And you don’t just want a range, you want an *input* range (because you’re only reading the elements, not writing them), so:

```
requires std::ranges::input_range<Range>

requires std::ranges::input_range<Range> and is_elements_iterable<Range>
```

And as mentioned earlier, you can replace `is_elements_iterable` with standard concepts like so:

```
requires std::ranges::input_range<Range>

requires std::ranges::input_range<Range> and std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
```

*This* is a good set of constraints. Anything that’s not an input range won’t work with either function. Anything that is will work with the first one. Anything that is *AND* whose values are also input ranges will work with the second.

Now let’s put those back with the rest of the function signatures:

```
template <typename Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<Range>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)

template <typename Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<Range> and std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
```

Finally, let’s move as much of those constraints into the template prologue, for readability:

```
template <std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)

template <std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
```

That gives you two constrained function templates, both requiring that the first argument is an input range.

(You could also constrain the second type by making a type trait that gets the recursive value type… probably called `recursive_range_value_t<Range>`, and use that with `std::equality_comparable_with`.)

Now, as for the implementations:

```
template <std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(input.begin(), input.end(), target);
}
```

This seems wrong. You require that the input is a range… but that only means that it supports `std::ranges::begin(input)` and `std::ranges::end(input)`. It does *NOT* mean it supports `input.begin()` or `input.end()`. For example, C arrays work with `std::ranges::begin(array)` and `std::ranges::end(array)`, but not with `array.begin()` or `array.end()`. Your concepts require `std::ranges::begin(input)` and `std::ranges::end(input)`, so that’s what you should use.

Of course, if you’re doing that, you might as well use `std::ranges::count()` rather than `std::count()`, unless you need the execution policy.

```
template <std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [target](auto& element) {
        return recursive_count(element, target);
        });
}
```

Again, your constraints require `std::ranges::begin(input)` and `std::ranges::end(input)`, not `std::begin(input)` and `std::end(input)`.

You have yet another unnecessary copy of `target` in the lambda capture. There’s no reason not to capture it by reference, and avoid a copy.

Also, I always recommend to prefer `auto&&` unless you have a good reason not to. In this case, `auto&` or `auto const&` will *USUALLY* work… but there are pathological cases where it might fail (like with `vector<bool>`). `auto&&` *ALWAYS* works; it *ALWAYS* does the right thing.

## `recursive_count_if()`

```
//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<std::ranges::range T1, class T2> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T1>)
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    return std::count_if(input.begin(), input.end(), predicate);
}

//  transform_reduce version
template<is_elements_iterable T1, class T2>
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const T1& input, const T2 predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
        });
}
```

Most of what went for `recursive_count()` goes for `recursive_count_if()`

## `recursive_size()`

```
//  recursive_size implementation
template<class T> requires (!std::ranges::range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return 1;
}

template<std::ranges::range T> requires (!is_elements_iterable<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return input.size();
}

template<is_elements_iterable T>
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [](auto& element) {
        return recursive_size(element);
        });
}
```

Once again, let’s start with just the constraints:

```
requires (!std::ranges::range<T>)

requires std::ranges::range<T> and (!is_elements_iterable<T>)

requires is_elements_iterable<T>
```

Again, this is how you’d use type traits and SFINAE, not concepts. You should take advantage of subsumption:

```
// no requires clause; unconstrained

requires std::ranges::range<T>

requires std::ranges::range<T> and is_elements_iterable<T>
```

… and standard concepts (and better type names)…:

```
// no requires clause; unconstrained

requires std::ranges::input_range<Range>

requires std::ranges::input_range<Range> and std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
```

… which gives:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_size(T const&)

template <std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr auto recursive_size(Range const&)

template <std::ranges::input_range Range>
requires std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_size(Range const&)
```

Couple other things. First, the non-range version just returns `1`, which is an `int`. Thing is, the size type is almost always an *unsigned* type. You’re going to create surprises if `recursive_size(x)` returns an unsigned type for ranges and a signed type for non-ranges. You probably want to return something like `std::size_t{1}`, not just `1`.

Second, overload 2 uses `input.size()`. This is not guaranteed to work for a lot of reasons. `std::size()` and `std::ranges::size()` only work for ranges that can figure out their size in constant time (which usually means they have a `.size()` function… but not always, like for C arrays). So it won’t work for `std::forward_list`, for example—for those types, you’d have to do `std::distance(std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input))`. The best solution would probably to use `if constexpr`, and test for `std::ranges::sized_range`, and then use `std::ranges::size()` if you can, and `std::distance()` if you can’t.

## `recursive_reduce()`

Nothing new here. Except… you probably don’t want to use `std::plus<ValueType>`. You probably just want to use `std::plus<>` (and you probably want to have it as the default for the first overload). Why? Well, `plus<T>` means `c = a + b` where `a`, `b`, and `c` *are all the same type* (which is `T`). `plus<>` means that they can all be different types, and the type of `c` will be properly deduced.

## `arithmetic_mean()`

```
//  arithmetic_mean implementation
template<class T = double, is_recursive_sizeable Container>
constexpr auto arithmetic_mean(const Container& input)
{
    if (recursive_size(input) == 0) //  Check the case of dividing by zero exception
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero exception"); //  Handle the case of dividing by zero exception
    }
    return (recursive_reduce(input, T{})) / (recursive_size(input));
}
```

Okay, let’s start with the pointless constraint here. Literally *EVERYTHING* is “`recursive_size`-able”. If it’s an input range, it will use overload 2 or 3, and if it’s *ANYTHING ELSE* it will use overload 1 and return `1`. So `is_recursive_sizeable` is a completely meaningless concept.

(Also, literally everything is “`recursive_reduce`-able”, though you don’t even use that constraint.)

Ironically, you have the first template parameter unconstrained, and the second constrained, when the second could be literally anything, but the first *must* be some kind of arithmetic type… and probably a floating point type. I’d recommend the following instead:

```
template <std::floating_point ReturnType = double, typename T>
constexpr auto arithmetic_mean(T const& input) -> ReturnType

// Note that the return type is explicitly specified. Why? Because otherwise
// it will be the result of:
//    recursive_reduce(input, ReturnType{}) / recursive_size()
// ... which may not be ReturnType (for example, if ReturnType is float, and
// input contains doubles, then the result will be double).
```

You call `recursive_size()` twice in the function, but that seems unwise. If your input is a million elements large, recursively, getting the size may not be all that quick. There’s no reason not to call it once and save the result.

Also, this is a very technical note, but this isn’t the most efficient or numerically stable way to calculate the mean. Rather than going through the input twice—once to count and one to sum—you could go through it just once with a `pair<ReturnType, size_t>` and get the size and the sum together simultaneously. There are also ways to calculate the mean as a running tally, which could avoid unnecessary over- or underflows.

## `recursive_transform()`

`recursive_transform()` is mostly just more of the same as above.

I should note that rather than using `back_inserter`, which only supports `vector`, `deque`, and `list`, you could use `std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output))` to support `set`, `map`, hash maps, and more.

*HOWEVER…*

```
template<template<class...> class Container, class Function, class... Ts>
requires (is_back_inserterable<Container<Ts...>> && std::ranges::range<Container<Ts...>> && !is_elements_iterable<Container<Ts...>>)
// non-recursive version
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Container<Ts...>& input, const Function& f)
{
    using TransformedValueType = decltype(f(*input.cbegin()));
    Container<TransformedValueType> output;
    std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}
```

I don’t think this is a good idea at all. I get what you’re trying to do. If `Container` is a `vector<int>`, and `Function` is `std::to_string`, you want the result to be automatically `vector<string>`. There are two problems with this:

1. It doesn’t really work. It will work with the most basic container types, like `vector` and `list`… but it won’t work for `map`. What if I have a `map<int, string>` and I want to do a transform that lower-cases all the strings and gives me a new `map<int, string>`? Then this function won’t work. (And I know I said it would work for simple container types like `vector`, but it won’t even work for that. If you use a `std::pmr::vector<int>` and `to_string()`, you won’t get a `std::pmr::vector<std::string>`, you’ll get a `std::vector<std::string>`.)
2. It’s not flexible. What if I want to transform a `list<string>` into a `vector<int>`? Can’t do it. What if I want to take a `vector<string>`, and lower-case all the strings *in-place*? Can’t do it.

There’s a reason why standard algorithms use output iterators rather than clever tricks like this; output iterators *always* work, for *everything*, and they’re infinitely flexible.

## `recursive_transform_reduce()` and `population_variance()`

More of the same.

## Summary

I think you misunderstood the recommendation to put concepts in the template parameter list, rather than the `requires` clause. I don’t think that was intended to suggest you should avoid `requires` clauses *generally*. I think what was meant was *EXACTLY* what was said: if you already have a concept, and you *can* put it in the template parameter list rather than the requires clause, then you should do that, just because it simplifies the function signature, and makes it harder to screw up and easier to read. But if you *don’t* have a concept *or* you *can’t* put it in the requires clause (because, it would be unwieldy, or because it’s a conjunction or disjunction), then don’t worry about it.

I also think you misunderstand the purpose of concepts. Concepts are not meant to be simple syntactic checks like `is_plusable` to check for `a + b`. If a type doesn’t support `operator+`, then there’s already a tool to detect that: the compiler; if some code requires `operator+`, the code will fail to compile for types without it. (If you really want pretty or descriptive error messages, you can always use type traits and `static_assert`.)

[Concepts are meant to be *SEMANTIC* checks](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#t20-avoid-concepts-without-meaningful-semantics). They won’t protect you from any and all syntactic issues. For example, `std::ranges::range` will probably be `true` for a signal transmission class with member functions `begin()` and `end()` that begin and end a transmission. If you use a signal transmission with a function like `recursive_count()`… well, that’s just nonsense, and that’s on you; concepts aren’t meant to save you from nonsense like that (presumably, other aspects of the type system will probably save you, though).

Also, concepts are not like type traits and SFINAE. Concepts understand the idea of “more specialized” in a way that type traits and SFINAE do not. You should take advantage of subsumption, and of constraint normalization, when using concepts.

And finally, don’t try to be too clever with your interfaces. Avoid interfaces that take decisions away from the user (unless those decisions are objectively bad). If an interface is too complex or has too many options, you can always add an overload with a simpler interface that internally calls the more complex interface with sane defaults. Being able to choose what type of container I get as output from a function is a *VERY* handy ability to have, even if there are common defaults. Not having that ability is not a feature, it’s a problem.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I wonder how much of the OPs code could be replaced with regular algorithms and some kind of recursive iterator, for example instead of `recursive_transform_reduce(container, ...)` do `std::transform_reduce(recursive_begin(container), recursive_end(container), ...)`. You mention that output iterators always work, however in case of a `recursive_transform()` for example, you'd have to prepare a recursive destination up front to write to, I don't think a `recursive_inserter()` would be possible, at least not one that copies the input structure perfectly.

Comment: Possible for a specific case, perhaps, but probably not generally. Yeah, I think a recursive iterator or container is a much better idea than a recursive algorithm. A thing that bugged me writing the answer (that I didn’t mention, because I was focused on the concepts) was `vector<string>` (or `vector<vector<string>>`)… would you want to iterate over the strings or the chars? Seems to me the answer is almost always going to be the strings. You can’t control that with the algorithm. But with a task-specific container/iterator, you could (and then use all normal algorithms).

Comment: We already looked at the `vector<string>` issue in an earlier question, you can make it work in *some* situations by only recursing while the `UnaryOp`/`BinaryOp` you pass to the recursive algorithm cannot be applied on the value type of the container at the current level. I'm not sure it could be made to work with a generic kind of `recursive_iterator`.