# A recursive_count Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235) and [A Function Applier for Applying Various Algorithms on Nested Container Things in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254384/231235). I am trying to use unwrap level template parameter as the termination condition of the recursion process in `recursive_count` template function.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `recursive_count` function is as below.

```
//  recursive_count implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T, typename ValueType>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T& input, const ValueType& target)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [&target](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count<unwrap_level - 1>(element, target);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        if (input == target)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

The `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`, `std::deque<int>`, `std::deque<std::deque<int>>`, `std::list<int>` and `std::list<std::list<int>>` type input test case has been listed as below.

```
std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_vector, 5) << std::endl;

//  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_vector2, 5) << std::endl;

//  std::vector<std::string>
std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_string_vector, "0") << std::endl;

//  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_string_vector2, "0") << std::endl;

//  std::deque<int>
std::deque<int> test_deque;
test_deque.push_back(1);
test_deque.push_back(2);
test_deque.push_back(3);
test_deque.push_back(4);
test_deque.push_back(5);
test_deque.push_back(6);
std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_deque, 1) << std::endl;

//  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_deque2, 1) << std::endl;

//  std::list<int>
std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_list, 1) << std::endl;


//  std::list<std::list<int>>
std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_list2, 1) << std::endl;

std::cout << recursive_count<11>(
        n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3),
        1
        ) << std::endl;
```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <execution>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept is_inserterable = requires(T x)
{
    std::inserter(x, std::ranges::end(x));
};

#ifdef USE_BOOST_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY
template<typename T>
concept is_multi_array = requires(T x)
{
    x.num_dimensions();
    x.shape();
    boost::multi_array(x);
};
#endif

//  recursive_copy_if function 
template <std::ranges::input_range Range, std::invocable<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>> UnaryPredicate>
constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    Range output{};
    std::ranges::copy_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        unary_predicate);
    return output;
}

template <
    std::ranges::input_range Range,
    class UnaryPredicate>
constexpr auto recursive_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate)
{
    Range output{};
    
    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&unary_predicate](auto&& element) { return recursive_copy_if(element, unary_predicate); }
        );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_count implementation
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), target);
}

//  transform_reduce version
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T, typename ValueType>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T& input, const ValueType& target)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [&target](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count<unwrap_level - 1>(element, target);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        if (input == target)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

//  recursive_count implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::count(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), target);
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_count(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [execution_policy, target](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count(execution_policy, element, target);
        });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation
template<class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (with execution policy)
template<class ExPo, class T, std::invocable<T> Pred>
requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
constexpr std::size_t recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return predicate(input) ? 1 : 0;
}

template<class ExPo, std::ranges::input_range Range, class Pred>
requires ((std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>) && (!std::invocable<Pred, Range>))
constexpr auto recursive_count_if(ExPo execution_policy, const Range& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(execution_policy, std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
        return recursive_count_if(element, predicate);
    });
}

//  recursive_count_if implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, std::ranges::range T, class Pred>
auto recursive_count_if(const T& input, const Pred& predicate)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 1)
    {
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [predicate](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count_if<unwrap_level - 1>(element, predicate);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        return std::count_if(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), predicate);
    }
}

//  recursive_function_applier implementation
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class F, std::ranges::range Range, class... Args>
constexpr auto recursive_function_applier(const F& function, const Range& input, Args... args)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level >= 1)
    {
        Range output{};
        std::ranges::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            [&function, &args...](auto&& element) { return recursive_function_applier<unwrap_level - 1>(function, element, args...); }
        );
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        Range output{};
        function(
            std::ranges::cbegin(input),
            std::ranges::cend(input),
            std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
            args...);
        return output;
    }
}

//  recursive_print implementation
template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr auto recursive_print(const Range& input, const int level = 0)
{
    auto output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& x)
        {
            std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
            return x;
        }
    );
    return output;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range> requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_print(const Range& input, const int level = 0)
{
    auto output = input;
    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
    std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
        [level](auto&& element)
        {
            return recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        }
    );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_replace_copy_if implementation
template<std::ranges::range Range, std::invocable<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>> UnaryPredicate, class T>
constexpr auto recursive_replace_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate, const T& new_value)
{
    Range output{};
    std::ranges::replace_copy_if(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        unary_predicate,
        new_value);
    return output;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range, class UnaryPredicate, class T>
requires (!std::invocable<UnaryPredicate, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_replace_copy_if(const Range& input, const UnaryPredicate& unary_predicate, const T& new_value)
{
    Range output{};

    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&unary_predicate, &new_value](auto&& element) { return recursive_replace_copy_if(element, unary_predicate, new_value); }
    );
    return output;
}

//  recursive_size implementation
template<class T> requires (!std::ranges::range<T>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const T& input)
{
    return 1;
}

template<std::ranges::range Range> requires (!(std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>))
constexpr auto recursive_size(const Range& input)
{
    return std::ranges::size(input);
}

template<std::ranges::range Range> requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>)
constexpr auto recursive_size(const Range& input)
{
    return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::begin(input), std::end(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [](auto& element) {
        return recursive_size(element);
        });
}

//  recursive_transform implementation
//  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
//  from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504127/6667035
template<typename, typename>
struct recursive_invoke_result { };

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
requires (
    !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>> &&
    std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>> &&
    requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
{
    using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
};

template<typename F, typename T>
using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

template <std::ranges::range Range>
constexpr auto get_output_iterator(Range& output)
{
    return std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output));
}

template <class T, std::invocable<T> F>
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
{
    return f(input);
}

template <
    std::ranges::input_range Range,
    class F>
requires (!std::invocable<F, Range>)
constexpr auto recursive_transform(const Range& input, const F& f)
{
    recursive_invoke_result_t<F, Range> output{};
    
    std::ranges::transform(
        std::ranges::cbegin(input),
        std::ranges::cend(input),
        std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
        [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform(element, f); }
        );
    return output;
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_vector, 5) << std::endl;

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_vector2, 5) << std::endl;

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_string_vector, "0") << std::endl;

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_string_vector2, "0") << std::endl;

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_deque, 1) << std::endl;

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_deque2, 1) << std::endl;

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_list, 1) << std::endl;


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_list2, 1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << recursive_count<11>(
            n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3),
            1
            ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/6ofMj1)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_count Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251983/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235) and

  [A Function Applier for Applying Various Algorithms on Nested Container Things in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254384/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The implementation of `recursive_count` function with unwrap level is the main idea here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  In the base comparison part, not sure using `input == target` as the equivalence condition is OK because `ValueType` and `T` may be different. The definition of `==` operator between `ValueType` and `T` is required in this design. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Comparing using `==` is fine

> In the base comparison part, not sure using `input == target` as the equivalence condition is OK because `ValueType` and `T` may be different.

This is fine, it does exactly what [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) does, and I wouldn't know how else to compare two values for equivalence, apart from passing a predicate function, but then it would become a `recursive_count_if()`.

## Use `std::ranges::count`

For the non-recursive version of `recursive_count()`, you can just call `std::ranges::count()`:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return std::ranges::count(input, target);
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `std::ranges::transform_reduce()` in C++20, but it might come in C++23.

## Make use of `auto` parameter types

While this doesn't change anything, it might make the code clearer if you use `auto` for parameters that you don't want the caller to explicitly pass template types for, and `template<>` for those that it should. So for example:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const auto& input, const auto& target)
{
    ...
}
```

## Avoid code duplication

You have two versions of `recursive_count()`, one which takes an `unwrap_level` parameter, and another which doesn't. You can avoid implementing the latter version by calling the first one with the maximum recursion depth of the `input` argument:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range Range, typename T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const T& target)
{
    return recursive_count<recursive_depth<Range>()>(input, target);
}
```

Implementing `recursive_depth()` is left as an excercise.

## Consider checking if `unwrap_level` is too high

If you call `recursive_count()` with an `unwrap_level` higher than the recursion depth of `input`, you'll get a very long and unreadable compiler error message. Consider adding a constraint or `static_assert()` to make it easier to debug this. For example:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T, typename ValueType>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T& input, const ValueType& target)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
                      "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to G. Sliepen's answer:

### Return Type

- `std::count` returns a `difference_type` (i.e. `std::ptrdiff_t`).
- `std::transform_reduce` returns a `std::size_t` (because that's what we specify as the "init" argument).
- The other two return statements `return 1;` and `return 0;` are `int`egers.

So with the `auto` return type, the user will get a type depending on what version of the function they call, and how exactly they call it.

I'd probably just go with specifying `std::size_t` for the return type, but an argument could be made for using `difference_type` from the relevant iterator traits instead.