# A recursive_depth function for calculating depth of nested types implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_count Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269309/231235). A function `recursive_depth` for calculating depth of nested iterables is mentioned in [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269309/231235). I am trying to implement `recursive_depth` function in this post.

- Given non-nested types `char`, `int`, the outputs of `recursive_depth` template function are `0`.
- Given nested types such as `std::vector<int>`, `std::deque<int>` and `std::list<int>`, the outputs of `recursive_depth` template function are `1`.
- Given nested types such as `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, `std::deque<std::deque<int>>` and `std::list<std::list<int>>`, the outputs of `recursive_depth` template function are `2`.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_depth` function implementation

  ```
  //  recursive_depth function implementation
  template<typename T>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return 0;
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
  }
  ```

**The testing code**

The non-nested type `char`, non-nested type `int`, `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, `std::deque<int>`, `std::deque<std::deque<int>>`, `std::list<int>` and `std::list<std::list<int>>` are tested.

```
void recursive_depth_test();

int main()
{
    recursive_depth_test();
}

void recursive_depth_test()
{
    //  non-nested type `char`
    char test_char = 'A';
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_char)>() << '\n';
    
    //  non-nested type `int`
    int test_int = 100;
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_int)>() << '\n';
    
    //  std::vector<int>
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_vector)>() << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_vector2)>() << '\n';

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_deque)>() << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_deque2)>() << '\n';

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_list)>() << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_list2)>() << '\n';
}
```

The output of the testing code above:

```
0
0
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/jTb9jWbca)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_count Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269309/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The experimental implementation of `recursive_depth` function is proposed here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  What would you expect the output of `std::vector<std::string>` case? In this experimental implementation, the output would be `2`. If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is straightforward and correct as far as I can tell.

> What would you expect the output of `std::vector<std::string>` case?

I expect it to be 2, as both `std::vector` and `std::string` are ranges. We have had this discussion [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252154/129343), and in case you want to have recursion stop when reaching a certain type, you might want to introduce another template, perhaps named `recursive_depth_until`.