# A recursive_depth Function Implementation with Target Type Parameter in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20, constrained-templates

This is a follow-up question for [A `recursive_depth` function for calculating depth of nested types implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269376/231235). I am rethinking about the proposed `recursive_depth` function. When it comes to the type `std::string`, the output is always `1` because the base type is `char`. However, why it is `1`, not `0` from the perspective of encapsulation? Therefore, I am trying to implement another version `recursive_depth` function with target type in this post. Additional input here is the target base type, the output `0` will be given for the type `std::string` when target base type is equal to `std::string`.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_depth` template function implementation

  ```
  //  recursive_depth function implementation with target type
  template<typename T_Base, typename T>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return std::size_t{0};
  }

  template<typename T_Base, std::ranges::input_range Range>
  requires (!std::same_as<Range, T_Base>)
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return recursive_depth<T_Base, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  A recursive_depth Function Implementation with Target Type Parameter in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

//  recursive_depth function implementation with target type
template<typename T_Base, typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return std::size_t{0};
}

template<typename T_Base, std::ranges::input_range Range>
requires (!std::same_as<Range, T_Base>)
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<T_Base, std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
}

void recursive_depth_test();

int main()
{
    recursive_depth_test();
}

void recursive_depth_test()
{
    //  std::string cases
    std::string test_string = "123";
    std::cout << "Giving base type std::string:" << recursive_depth<decltype(test_string), decltype(test_string)>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Giving base type char:" << recursive_depth<char, decltype(test_string)>() << '\n';
    
    //  non-nested type `char` case
    char test_char = 'A';
    std::cout << "non-nested type `char` case: " << recursive_depth<char, decltype(test_char)>() << '\n';
    
    //  non-nested type `int` case
    int test_int = 100;
    std::cout << "non-nested type `int` case: " << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_int)>() << '\n';
    
    //  std::vector<int> case
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    std::cout << "std::vector<int> case: " << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_vector)>() << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>> case
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    std::cout << "std::vector<std::vector<int>> case: " << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_vector2)>() << '\n';

    //  std::deque<int> case
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    std::cout << "std::deque<int> case: "  << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_deque)>() << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>> case
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    std::cout << "std::deque<std::deque<int>> case: "  << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_deque2)>() << '\n';

    //  std::list<int> case
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << "std::list<int> case: "  << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_list)>() << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>> case
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    std::cout << "std::list<std::list<int>> case: "  << recursive_depth<int, decltype(test_list2)>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::list<std::list<int>> with given base type std::list<int>: "  << recursive_depth<std::list<int>, decltype(test_list2)>() << '\n';
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Giving base type std::string:0
Giving base type char:1
non-nested type `char` case: 0
non-nested type `int` case: 0
std::vector<int> case: 1
std::vector<std::vector<int>> case: 2
std::deque<int> case: 1
std::deque<std::deque<int>> case: 2
std::list<int> case: 1
std::list<std::list<int>> case: 2
std::list<std::list<int>> with given base type std::list<int>: 1
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/G4E9nrz47)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A `recursive_depth` function for calculating depth of nested types implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269376/231235).
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement another version `recursive_depth` function with target type in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Should it keeps the name `recursive_depth` or it's better to rename it by something like `unwrap_times_to_target_type`? Also, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you construct objects in your test cases if you are only testing static properties of the types?

Comment: _get_nested_type_depth()_ , _get_depth()_ . Possibly  _type_depth()_