# A recursive_count function with recursive_depth for unwrap_level checking in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, template, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [A recursive_depth function for calculating depth of nested types implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269376/231235) and [A recursive_count Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269309/231235). I am trying to follow [G. Sliepen's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269309/231235) to implement another version of `recursive_count` function using `recursive_depth` for unwrap_level checking.

**The experimental implementation**

- `recursive_count` function:

  ```
  //  recursive_count implementation

  //  recursive_count implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
  template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T>
  constexpr auto recursive_count(const T& input, const auto& target)
  {
      if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
      {
          static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
              "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");
          return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [&target](auto&& element) {
              return recursive_count<unwrap_level - 1>(element, target);
              });
      }
      else
      {
          if (input == target)
          {
              return 1;
          }
          else
          {
              return 0;
          }
      }
  }

  //  recursive_count implementation (the version without unwrap_level)
  template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
  constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const auto& target)
  {
      return recursive_count<recursive_depth<Range>()>(input, target);
  }
  ```
- `recursive_depth` function:

  ```
  //  recursive_depth function implementation
  template<typename T>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return 0;
  }

  template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
  constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
  {
      return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
  }
  ```

**The testing code**

```
void recursive_count_test()
{
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_vector, 5) << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_vector2, 5) << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_string_vector, "0") << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_string_vector2, "0") << '\n';

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_deque, 1) << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_deque2, 1) << '\n';

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_list, 1) << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_list2, 1) << '\n';

    std::cout << recursive_count<11>(
        n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3),
        1
        ) << '\n';
}
```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

//  recursive_depth function implementation
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
{
    return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + 1;
}

//  recursive_count implementation

//  recursive_count implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class T>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const T& input, const auto& target)
{
    if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
    {
        static_assert(unwrap_level <= recursive_depth<T>(),
            "unwrap level higher than recursion depth of input");
        return std::transform_reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::size_t{}, std::plus<std::size_t>(), [&target](auto&& element) {
            return recursive_count<unwrap_level - 1>(element, target);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        if (input == target)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

//  recursive_count implementation (the version without unwrap_level)
template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
constexpr auto recursive_count(const Range& input, const auto& target)
{
    return recursive_count<recursive_depth<Range>()>(input, target);
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
        std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
    }
}

void recursive_depth_test();
void recursive_count_test();

int main()
{
    recursive_count_test();
}

void recursive_depth_test()
{
    //  non-nested type `char`
    char test_char = 'A';
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_char)>() << '\n';
    
    //  non-nested type `int`
    int test_int = 100;
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_int)>() << '\n';
    
    //  std::vector<int>
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_vector)>() << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_vector2)>() << '\n';

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_deque)>() << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_deque2)>() << '\n';

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_list)>() << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    std::cout << recursive_depth<decltype(test_list2)>() << '\n';
}

void recursive_count_test()
{
    std::vector<int> test_vector{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_vector, 5) << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_vector)> test_vector2{ test_vector , test_vector , test_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_vector2, 5) << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::string>
    std::vector<std::string> test_string_vector{ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20" };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_string_vector, "0") << '\n';

    //  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
    std::vector<decltype(test_string_vector)> test_string_vector2{ test_string_vector , test_string_vector , test_string_vector };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_string_vector2, "0") << '\n';

    //  std::deque<int>
    std::deque<int> test_deque;
    test_deque.push_back(1);
    test_deque.push_back(2);
    test_deque.push_back(3);
    test_deque.push_back(4);
    test_deque.push_back(5);
    test_deque.push_back(6);
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_deque, 1) << '\n';

    //  std::deque<std::deque<int>>
    std::deque<decltype(test_deque)> test_deque2;
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    test_deque2.push_back(test_deque);
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_deque2, 1) << '\n';

    //  std::list<int>
    std::list<int> test_list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << recursive_count<1>(test_list, 1) << '\n';


    //  std::list<std::list<int>>
    std::list<std::list<int>> test_list2 = { test_list, test_list, test_list, test_list };
    std::cout << recursive_count<2>(test_list2, 1) << '\n';

    std::cout << recursive_count<11>(
        n_dim_container_generator<10, std::list>(test_list, 3),
        1
        ) << '\n';
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/3b96j5haM)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A recursive_depth function for calculating depth of nested types implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269376/231235) and

  [A recursive_count Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269309/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement another version of `recursive_count` function using `recursive_depth` for unwrap_level checking.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Missing test cases

I don't see any test cases being added for the version of `recursive_count()` that doesn't take an unwrap level. Also, add test cases for corner cases, most importantly trying to apply `recursive_count<0>()` on ranges and applying `recursive_count()` on non-ranges. For example, consider adding the following test cases:

```
assert(recursive_count<0>(1, 2) == 0);
assert(recursive_count<0>(0, 0) == 1);
```

This will compile and run correctly. However, the following does not:

```
assert(recursive_count(1, 2) == 0);
assert(recursive_count(0, 0) == 1);
```

This will fail to compile with your code because your `recursive_count()` without an unwrap level only works on ranges. The fix is to make it `template<typename T>` instead of `template<std::ranges::input_range Range>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
       if (input == target)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
```

Write this clearly as:
`return (input == target) ? 1 : 0;`

The cognitive overhead of what you wrote is quite high:  the reader sees an `if` statement so the code does two different things.  Then, each thing is a return statement.  Ah, it returns either way, you *always* want to return -- you just want to condition to specify *which value* is returned.

So write it directly, rather than making the reader reverse-engineer that meaning.

I want to impress that it's not just "terse" for its own sake.  The single statement is easier to read and understand, since it directly states the intent.  In general, don't duplicate more than necessary in your conditional branches.  If the condition is just to affect some values, don't repeat the function calls and unaffected values.