# std::array and std::vector Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for the previous questions about recursive functions, including [A Summation Function For Arbitrary Nested Vector Implementation In C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250743/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Specified value_type for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Automatic Type Deducing from Lambda for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252325/231235) and [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235). In order to test these functions for arbitrary nested iterables, I am trying to implement some arbitrary nested iterable generators to construct nested `std::vector`s and nested `std::array`s with the given parameters. The generator for `std::array` case is named `n_dim_array_generator` and another generator for `std::vector` is named `n_dim_vector_generator`. After trying to use `if constexpr` syntax in [the previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235), I found that it is possible to use the similar technique in `n_dim_array_generator` function and `n_dim_vector_generator` function.

**The usage description**

For example, `auto test_vector = n_dim_vector_generator<2, int>(1, 3);` is expected to create a "test_vector" object which type is `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. The content of this `test_vector` should as same as the following code.

```
std::vector<int> vector1;
vector1.push_back(1);
vector1.push_back(1);
vector1.push_back(1);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> test_vector;
test_vector.push_back(vector1);
test_vector.push_back(vector1);
test_vector.push_back(vector1);
```

There are four key part in the usage `n_dim_vector_generator<2, int>(1, 3)`. The first number `2` represents the nested layers, the second parameter `int` represents the type of base elements, the third parameter `1` represents the input element which would be filled in, and the fourth parameter `3` represents the element count in each layer.

In the `n_dim_array_generator` function, the first parameter also represents the nested layers, but the parameter which represents the element count in each layer has been moved into the second one. Then, the third parameter represents the type of base elements and the fourth parameter represents the input element which would be filled in.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `n_dim_vector_generator` function and `n_dim_array_generator` function:

```
template<std::size_t dim, class T>
auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if (dim < 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Dimension can not be set less than 0");
    }
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<decltype(n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times))> output;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            output.push_back(n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times));
        }
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if (dim < 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Dimension can not be set less than 0");
    }
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        std::array<decltype(n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input)), times> output;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            output[i] = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

The test cases of `n_dim_vector_generator` function and `n_dim_array_generator` function are as below.

```
//  n_dim_vector_generator function usage with recursive_reduce function and recursive_count_if function
auto test_vector1 = n_dim_vector_generator<3, int>(3, 2);
std::cout << "recursive_reduce output: " << recursive_reduce(test_vector1, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output: " << recursive_count_if<3>(test_vector1, [](auto& i) {return i == 3; }) << std::endl;

//  n_dim_array_generator function usage with recursive_reduce function and recursive_count_if function
auto test_array1 = n_dim_array_generator<3, 2, int>(3);
std::cout << "recursive_reduce output: " << recursive_reduce(test_array1, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output: " << recursive_count_if<3>(test_array1, [](auto& i) {return i == 3; }) << std::endl;
```

The output of this test is as follows.

```
recursive_reduce output: 24
recursive_count_if output: 8
recursive_reduce output: 24
recursive_count_if output: 8
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/n88s7z)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [A Summation Function For Arbitrary Nested Vector Implementation In C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250743/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Specified value_type for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235),

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Automatic Type Deducing from Lambda for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252325/231235) and

  [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The `n_dim_vector_generator` function and `n_dim_array_generator` function are the key part here.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am not sure if it is a good idea to throw `std::logic_error` in the situation of `Dimension is set less than 0`. If there is any further possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unnecessary check for `dim < 0`

Since `dim` is a `std::size_t`, it can never be negative, so this check is redundant.

## Reserve spaces in vectors

If you know what the size of a vector is going to be up front, `reserve()` space for the elements to avoid unnecessary memory operations.

## Prefer `emplace_back()` over `push_back()` where possible

In `n_dim_vector_generator()` you can use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`. It will probably not matter much with an optimizing compiler, but this way you avoid a move operation each time you add an item.

## Consider using `std::fill()`

At least in `n_dim_array_generator()`, you can use [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) to fill the array you created:

```
std::array<decltype(n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input)), times> output;
std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input));
return output;
```

You could also do this with `n_dim_vector_generator()` if you `resize()` the vector before filling it, but that causes unnecessary default construction of elements right before they are overwritten again, or you could combine it with [`std::back_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), like so:

```
std::vector<decltype(n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times))> output;
output.reserve(times);
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(output), times, n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times));
return output;
```

Although sadly there is no `std::back_emplacer()`.