# std::deque and std::list Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [std::array and std::vector Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252488/231235) and the previous questions about recursive functions, including [A Summation Function For Arbitrary Nested Vector Implementation In C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250743/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Specified value_type for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235), [A recursive_count_if Function with Automatic Type Deducing from Lambda for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252325/231235) and [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235). Besides the `std::array` and `std::vector` cases, I am trying to implement other functions `n_dim_deque_generator` and `n_dim_list_generator` which purpose are similar as `n_dim_array_generator` and `n_dim_vector_generator`. In other words, `n_dim_deque_generator` function can construct nested `std::deque`s with the given parameters and `n_dim_list_generator` function can construct nested `std::list`s with the given parameters.

**The usage description**

As similar to the usage of `n_dim_vector_generator`, there are four key parts in the usage `n_dim_deque_generator<2, int>(1, 3)`. The first number `2` represents the nested layers, the second parameter `int` represents the type of base elements, the third parameter `1` represents the input element which would be filled in, and the fourth parameter `3` represents the element count in each layer.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `n_dim_deque_generator` function and `n_dim_list_generator` function:

```
template<std::size_t dim, class T>
auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        std::deque<decltype(n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times))> output;
        output.resize(times);
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times));
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, class T>
auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        std::list<decltype(n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times))> output;
        output.resize(times);
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times));
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

The test cases of `n_dim_deque_generator` function and `n_dim_list_generator` function are as below. The test cases of `n_dim_vector_generator` function and `n_dim_array_generator` function are also listed, for comparison purposes.

```
constexpr std::size_t dims_setting = 8;
int input_element = 3;
constexpr std::size_t element_count = 2;

//  n_dim_vector_generator function usage with recursive_reduce function and recursive_count_if function
auto test_vector1 = n_dim_vector_generator<dims_setting, int>(input_element, element_count);
std::cout << "recursive_reduce output: " << recursive_reduce(test_vector1, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output: " << recursive_count_if<dims_setting>(test_vector1, [](auto& i) {return i == 3; }) << std::endl;

//  n_dim_array_generator function usage with recursive_reduce function and recursive_count_if function
auto test_array1 = n_dim_array_generator<dims_setting, element_count, int>(input_element);
std::cout << "recursive_reduce output: " << recursive_reduce(test_array1, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output: " << recursive_count_if<dims_setting>(test_array1, [](auto& i) {return i == 3; }) << std::endl;

//  n_dim_deque_generator function usage with recursive_reduce function and recursive_count_if function
auto test_deque1 = n_dim_deque_generator<dims_setting, int>(input_element, element_count);
std::cout << "recursive_reduce output: " << recursive_reduce(test_deque1, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output: " << recursive_count_if<dims_setting>(test_deque1, [](auto& i) {return i == 3; }) << std::endl;

//  n_dim_list_generator function usage with recursive_reduce function and recursive_count_if function
auto test_list1 = n_dim_list_generator<dims_setting, int>(input_element, element_count);
std::cout << "recursive_reduce output: " << recursive_reduce(test_list1, 0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "recursive_count_if output: " << recursive_count_if<dims_setting>(test_list1, [](auto& i) {return i == 3; }) << std::endl;
```

The output of this test is as follows.

```
recursive_reduce output: 768
recursive_count_if output: 256
recursive_reduce output: 768
recursive_count_if output: 256
recursive_reduce output: 768
recursive_count_if output: 256
recursive_reduce output: 768
recursive_count_if output: 256
```

**Notes**

The `n_dim_vector_generator` function and `n_dim_array_generator` function have been updated as follows. Thanks to G. Sliepen for [answering the previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252490/231235).

```
template<std::size_t dim, class T>
auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<decltype(n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times))> output;
        output.reserve(times);
        std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(output), times, n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times));
        return output;
    }
}

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
{
    if constexpr (dim == 0)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        std::array<decltype(n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input)), times> output;
        std::fill(std::begin(output), std::end(output), n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input));
        return output;
    }
}
```

[A Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/vczahq)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [std::array and std::vector Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Generator Functions Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252488/231235) and

  the previous questions about recursive functions, including

  - [A Summation Function For Arbitrary Nested Vector Implementation In C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250743/231235),
  - [A recursive_count_if Function For Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252053/231235),
  - [A recursive_count_if Function with Specified value_type for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252225/231235),
  - [A recursive_count_if Function with Automatic Type Deducing from Lambda for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252325/231235) and
  - [A recursive_count_if Function with Unwrap Level for Various Type Arbitrary Nested Iterable Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/252404/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  The `n_dim_deque_generator` function and `n_dim_list_generator` function have been added.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  I am not sure if it is a good idea to use `resize` function and `std::fill` function in both `n_dim_deque_generator` and `n_dim_list_generator` implementation. If there is any further possible improvement, please let me know.